# Change the shape of a fraction

Tags: symbols

Is it possible to change the bar in a fraction to a different symbol? ie.

```
\frac{x}{y}
```

But instead of a straight line, I'd like to choose the delimiter to say `\overbrace`. I know I can get rid of the delimiter completely using `\genfrac`

```
\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{x}{y}
```

And the closest I've come is:

```
\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{x}{\overbrace{y}}
```

While this extends if `y` is a large expression, it does not extend the delimiter if `x` is a large expression. Any thoughts?

**EDIT**: Changed to `\overbrace` from `\hat` as the hat does not compile. Question remains the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're doing to get `\hat` to extend—it doesn't for me—but the following sort of works. I'm not totally happy with the spacing. Note that I used `\overbrace` instead of `\hat` since it actually does extend.

```
\newcommand*\hatfrac[2]{
        \genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{#1}{\mathpalette\makehathelper{{#1}{#2}}}
}
\def\makehathelper#1#2{\makehat#1#2}
\def\makehat#1#2#3{
        \begingroup
        \setbox0\hbox{$\mathsurround0pt #1#2$}
        \setbox2\hbox{$\mathsurround0pt #1#3$}
        \ifdim\wd0<\wd2
                \overbrace{\box2}
        \else
                \overbrace{\hbox to\wd0{\hfil\box2\hfil}}
        \fi
        \endgroup
}
```

The braces don't seem to line up in the two cases. If you make the vinculum (the fraction bar) larger than 0pt, you get a line, of course, but then the braces line up. Try

```
\[
\hatfrac{abcdefghijkl}{x}
\hatfrac{x}{abcdefghijkl}
\hatfrac{x}{y}
\]
```

to see what I mean.

**Update**
I'm leaving my old solution because I suspect that with some modifications, someone can make it work. Here's my current solution.

```
\newcommand*\hatfrac[2]{
        \mathchoice{\makehat\textstyle{#1}{#2}}
                   {\makehat\scriptstyle{#1}{#2}}
                   {\makehat\scriptscriptstyle{#1}{#2}}
                   {\makehat\scriptscriptstyle{#1}{#2}}
}
\def\makehat#1#2#3{
        \mathinner{
        \hskip\nulldelimiterspace
        \setbox0\hbox{\strut$\mathsurround0pt#1#2$}
        \setbox2\hbox{\strut\cramped[#1]{#3}}
        \dimen0 \wd\ifdim\wd0<\wd2 2\else0\fi
        \setbox4\hbox{$\mathsurround0pt\overbrace{\hbox to\dimen0{\hfil}}$}
        \dimen0 \wd4
        \dimen2 \ht2
        \advance\dimen2 \dp2
        \advance\dimen2 \ht4
        \setbox6\vbox{\hbox to\dimen0{\hfil\unhbox0\hfil}
                      \nointerlineskip
                      \box4
                      \nointerlineskip
                      \hbox to\dimen0{\hfil\unhbox2\hfil}}
        \lower.5\dimen2\box6
        \hskip\nulldelimiterspace
        }
}
```

It has one problem, which I hope is minor enough that you can use it. The first is that the numerator and denominator are typeset with a `\strut` for spacing. What should happen instead is the numerator (resp. denominator) should be moved up (resp. down) some amount dependent on the font and its height+depth. In principle, this is doable, but I'd need to spend a lot more time reading Appendix G of the TeXbook.

**EDIT**: There was an additional problem regarding cramped math styles that has been resolved thanks to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2623/how-does-one-change-the-math-style-to-one-of-the-primed-styles/2655#2655). You need the `mathtools` package for the `\cramped` macro. Actually, a similar issue exists with the numerator. The denominator should always be cramped, so using `\cramped` we can solve it. The numerator should be cramped only when the entire fraction is cramped. I don't know how to test if the current style is cramped or not.

Answer (score 5):

I'm in a TikZ-mood.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\newcommand{\intfunnyfrac}[1]{%
\tikz[baseline]
\draw
node[anchor=mid] (frac) {\(#1\)}
[draw,decorate,decoration=brace]
(frac.west) -- (frac.east)
;%
}

\newcommand{\funnyfrac}[2]{%
\mathchoice{%
\intfunnyfrac{\displaystyle{ #1 \atop #2}}%
}{%
\intfunnyfrac{\textstyle{ #1 \atop #2}}%
}{%
\intfunnyfrac{\scriptstyle {#1 \atop #2}}%
}{%
\intfunnyfrac{\scriptscriptstyle {#1 \atop #2}}%
}%
}
\begin{document}
\[
X \frac{A}{B} \funnyfrac{A}{B} \frac{A}{B} Y
\]

\[
X \funnyfrac{A B C D}{B} \funnyfrac{A}{A B C D} \funnyfrac{A}{B} Y
\]

\end{document}
```

It could do with a bit of adjustment on spacing, and with bumpy replacements for the horizontal line then the numerator and denominator could do with a bit more separation, but it's intended more as a "proof of concept" than some code you could cut-and-paste.

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility is to build the "fractions" from scratch, from boxes.  Something like this seems to be working for me:

```
\newcommand*\hatfrac[2]{
        \mathchoice{\makehat\displaystyle{#1}{#2}}
                   {\makehat\textstyle{#1}{#2}} 
                   {\makehat\scriptstyle{#1}{#2}}
                   {\makehat\scriptscriptstyle{#1}{#2}} 
        }

\def\makehat#1#2#3{
        \begingroup
        \setbox0\hbox{$\mathsurround0pt #1#2$}
        \setbox2\hbox{$\mathsurround0pt #1#3$}
    \dimen0 = \ht0
    \advance\dimen0 by \dp0
    \dimen2 = \ht2
    \advance\dimen2 by \dp2
    \ifdim\dimen0<\dimen2
       \setbox4\vbox to\dimen2{\vfil\copy0\vskip0pt}
       \setbox6\vbox to\dimen2{\copy2\vskip0pt}
    \else
       \setbox4\vbox to\dimen0{\copy0\vskip0pt}
       \setbox6\vbox to\dimen0{\copy2\vfil\vskip0pt}
    \fi
        \ifdim\wd0<\wd2
       \dimen4=\wd2
        \else
       \dimen4=\wd0
        \fi
    \setbox8\hbox{\strut$\overbrace{\hbox to\dimen4{\hfil}}$}
    \dimen4=\wd8
    \;\vcenter{\hbox{\vbox{\hbox to\dimen4{\hfil\box4\hfil}%
    \box8\hbox to\dimen4{\hfil\box6\hfil}}}}\;
        \endgroup
}
```

Comment: Looks like we came up with pretty similar solutions!

Answer (score 3):

This is a slightly modified version of TH's solution that does not use `\genfrac`. Instead, I use the TeX primitive `\atop`.

```
\def\genbraced#1#2#3#4%accent style num den
  {\begingroup
   \setbox0\hbox{$\mathsurround0pt #2#3$}%
   \setbox2\hbox{$\mathsurround0pt #2#4$}%
   \dimen0\wd0
   \ifdim\dimen0<\wd2 \dimen0\wd2 \fi
   {\box0 \atop #1{\hbox to \dimen0{\hss\box2\hss}}}
   \endgroup}

\def\braced{\genbraced\overbrace\displaystyle}

%\showboxes %Really useful for visual debugging

\starttext

\startformula
\braced{abcdefghijkl}{x}
\braced{x}{abcdefghijkl}
\braced{x}{y}
\stopformula

\stoptext
```

Comment: This seems to have the same spacing problems my original solution has.