# How does one change the math style to one of the "primed" styles?

Tags: math-mode, tex-core

**Background**
TeX typesets each portion of a mathematical expression in one of 8 styles:

1. display,
2. display',
3. text,
4. text',
5. script,
6. script',
7. scriptscript, or
8. scriptscript'.

Knuth calls them, D, D', T, T', S, S', SS, and SS', respectively.

TeX transitions between styles for subscripts, superscripts, and for the numerators and denominators of fractions (`\above`, `\atop`, `\over` and their `\...withdelims` variants).

Four of these style are well known via `\displaystyle`, `\textstyle`, `\scriptstyle`, and `\scriptscriptstyle`. The other four are less known (in fact, I don't think I've seen any reference to them outside of the TeXbook). They are almost the same as the corresponding nonprimed style except that superscripts are typeset a bit farther down.

One simple way to see the difference is to look at the output of (the plain TeX document)

```
$${\atop x^y}{\atop\textstyle x^y}$$
\bye
```

The reason these differ is that TeX starts the math display in style D. It typesets the numerator in style T and the denominator in style T'. The `\textstyle` causes TeX to typeset the denominator in style T instead.

**Question**
How can one force TeX to go into one of the primed styles? As the example above illustrates, even when TeX is in one of the primed styles, it moves to the nonprime variant with `\textstyle` (similarly for the other three).

**Motivation**
This can be important when building vertical boxes in math mode. For example, see my [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2604/change-the-shape-of-a-fraction/2606#2606) to changing the shape of a fraction for a case where this is needed.

## Follow up question

Is there a way to check if the current style is cramped? I thought about putting `X^X` in a `\vcenter` and comparing its height to the current style as determined by `\mathchoice`, but this doesn't work because `\vcenter` doesn't give you a box.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [mathtools](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools/) package gives the `\cramped` command.

Answer (score 5):

A totally different answer: after some toying around, I managed to produce this plain TeX macro:

```
\newdimen\savedrulethickness
\def\docramped#1#2%
  {\savedrulethickness = \fontdimen8\textfont3
   \hbox{$\mathsurround0pt 
          \fontdimen8\textfont3=0pt 
           #1\overline{#2}$}%
    \fontdimen8\textfont3 \savedrulethickness}

\def\cramped{\mathpalette\docramped}

$f^b \overline{f^b} \cramped{f^b}$

\bye
```

If math family 3 has three different fonts instead of just 3 copies of cmex10, this needs extending a bit, and there are the general pitfalls with `\mathchoice`, but it seems to work.

In comparison, here is how the definition of `\cramped` would look in Luatex:

```
\def\cramped#1%
  {{\ifcase\mathstyle
    \crampeddisplaystyle      \or \or % 0 -> 1
    \crampedtextstyle         \or \or % 2 -> 3
    \crampedscriptstyle       \or \or % 4 -> 5
    \crampedscriptscriptstyle \fi     % 6 -> 7
   #1}}
```

Edit: used \mathpalette, and added the Luatex version

Comment: That's pretty good. You can simplify `\cramped` a bit by `\def\cramped{\mathpalette\docramped}`. Unfortunately, you can't use `\overline` inside the argument.

Comment: The LuaTeX definition is quite nice. It's too bad Knuth didn't include those primitives.

Comment: You can always switch to luatex and enjoy the new primitives.

Comment: Taco, you seem to have forgotten that you (and Hans) adapted  Knuth's cramped [macro](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/digests/tex-implementors/042)  to [ConTeXt](http://source.contextgarden.net/tex/context/base/supp-mat.tex) :-)

Comment: @aditya: I saw that one when looking up the luatex version, but I think the version here is nicer.

Answer (score 1):

`\mathaccent`'s accentee is typeset in cramped style. So, if the math font has a character available that does not actually print anything, you could use that to force the style.

(luatex defines 4 new primitives for this purpose)

Comment: You're absolutely right about `\mathaccent`. Unfortunately, this isn't the case if a font doesn't contain a character!. So while `\mathaccent"37F{x^y}` typesets in the cramped style (with a \Downarrow, it appears), `\mathaccent"380{x^y}` does not.

Answer (score 1):

`\radical0{...}`

`\radical` is a TeX primitive used to define `\sqrt` as `\def\sqrt{\radical"270370 }`
(The TeXbook, p. 157).

The number identifies the square root symbol and zero is no error and no symbol.
This leaves the wanted side effect of typesetting the argument in the primed style (cramped).

Comment: The `mathtools` macro `\cramped` uses the same idea.