# Problem with \mathpalette and \mathchoice

Tags: math-mode, tex-core, subscripts

When working on an additional answer to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3682/1235) question of mine, I stumbled across the following problem with `\mathpalette`. For simplicity I give an example where in practice it is ridiculous to use `\mathpalette`: `\mathpalette{}{B}_b` gives the output [image], whereas the straightforward `B_b` gives [image]. Note that in the latter version the subscript is closer to the "B", which is good. If instead of `\mathpalette` one uses the version `\mathchoice{B}{B}{B}{B}_b`, one (of course) has the same problem.

Is there a way around this problem? (I mean other than `\mathpalette{}{B_b}`, which is not an option for what I need.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: no. If you use `\mathchoice`, this is unavoidable.

Luatex offers a way to do `\mathstyle`-based typesetting without having to fall back on 
`\mathchoice`, see my answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1223/) for details.

Comment: You have the habit of posting negative answers to my questions ;-). I fear that again I'll have to accept your answer. Still this property of `\mathchoice` is a bit annoying, isn't it?

Comment: I really am sorry about those negative answers, but then, that is one reason for the existence of luatex. See my answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1223/ for a luatex-based solution to this problem.

Comment: OK, that question is indeed very much related to my question, and your LuaTeX-answer looks quite good indeed. I think the link should go into your answer here; then the answer would be a lot less negative!

Answer (score 4):

As I understand it the `\mathchoice` gives you choice item in the math list; the `_b` gives you an ord atom with no nucleus or superscript. In contrast, `B_b` gives you a single ord atom with a nucleus and subscript.

You can look at this by using `\showlists` in TeX.

```
$\mathchoice{B}{B}{B}{B}_b\showlists$
$B_b\showlists$
\bye
```

Then in the log, you see for the first math list,

```
\mathchoice
D\mathord
D.\fam1 B
T\mathord
T.\fam1 B
S\mathord
S.\fam1 B
s\mathord
s.\fam1 B
\mathord
_\fam1 b
```

and for the second, you get

```
\mathord
.\fam1 B
_\fam1 b
```

Note the `\mathord` in the penultimate line of the first list.

This is described in Chapters 17 and 26 of the TeXbook.

Comment: @TH: This doesn't really answer my question, but it nicely explains the behaviour I observed. Thank you! Now I'm a bit uncertain which answer to accept ...

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt: Taco answered your question. I just looked up _why_ the answer was no. :)