# Is there a way to dissect math lists?

Tags: tex-core

In the course of trying to answer this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3682/how-do-i-lower-the-widetilde-accent-i-e-move-it-closer-to-the-variable), I now realize that I need to be able to construct a math list and then check if it consists of a single character atom.

What I would like to be able to do is to deconstruct the math list similar to "Dissecting paragraphs with `\lastbox`" in *TeX by Topic*.

As described in this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3875/problem-with-mathpalette-and-mathchoice/3900#3900), one can use `\showlists` to write a representation of the partial lists to the log file. That doesn't seem to help me unless I want to parse the log file. (I don't.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am pretty sure you can do something that extends the *TeX by Topic* with `\lastbox` and
box unrolling after the paragraph has completed, but (besides being very tedious) that will not give you access to the actual math list, only to its converted format as a nested tree of `\hbox` and `\vbox`-es.

TeX82 does not offer access to the math list other than via `\showlists` (and for once I think a luatex answer would not really help).

Comment: I'm not sure how to deal with the `\mathon`/`\mathoff` itemsssssss that appear in the boxes. For example, `\hbox{$x$}` gives `\mathon`, `\teni x`, and `\mathoff` in plain TeX. I guess I haven't played with box unrolling much to know if there's anything that can be done to see that this is just a `\teni x`, for example. If I could do that, I think that'd be sufficient.

Comment: To follow up on that, `\hbox{$x$\setbox0\lastbox\showbox0}` tells me that `\box0` is void. This makes sense since `\mathoff` is not a box. I might just be out of luck here.

Comment: @TH Yes, I fear you are right. Parsing the log file it is, then

Comment: @TH: In Chapter 21 of the TeXbook it says that `\lastbox` is always void in math mode.

Comment: @TH: The following might be worth pointing out: It is not only that `\mathoff` is not a box, it is not even a TeX command.

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt: Yes, you're right on both counts.

Comment: @Taco Hoekwater: That's too bad. Parsing the log file is far, far more effort than I'm willing to go to here. If there were something similar to `\meaning` for `\showlists`, that'd be quite handy. Oh well.

Answer (score 6):

It is only possible to dissect math lists when using LuaTeX.  For instance, you can use the `mlist_to_hlist` callback.  The code below emulates `\showlists` for math lists, to some limited extent: for instance `\radical` is not taken care of.

Note that I am very much a LuaTeX newbie, so the code is probably very far from optimal, and doesn't follow standard best practices.

```
\begingroup
\catcode`~=12
\catcode`#=12
\escapechar=-1
\edef\\{\string\\}
\directlua
  {%
    local my = {}
    my.node = {}
    function my.node.tostring(t, newline)
        if t == nil then
            return ''
        end
        if my[node.type(t.id)] ~= nil then
            return my[node.type(t.id)].tostring(t, newline)
        else
            local result = newline .. node.type(t.id)
            for _, v in ipairs(node.fields(t.id)) do
                if v == 'id' or t[v] == nil then else
                    local value = t[v]
                    if type(value) == "userdata" then
                        value = node.type(value.id)
                    end
                    result = result .. ', ' .. v .. ': ' .. value
                end
            end
            return result
        end
    end
    %
    my.noad = {}
    my.noad.subtypes = {'op', nil, nil, 'bin', 'rel', 'open',
      'close', 'punct', 'inner', [0] = 'ord'}
    function my.noad.subtype(subtype)
        if my.noad.subtypes[subtype] == nil then
            return '\\\\math?'
        else
            return '\\\\math' .. my.noad.subtypes[subtype]
        end
    end
    function my.noad.tostring(t, newline)
        local result = newline .. my.noad.subtype(t.subtype)
        if t.attr ~= nil then
            result = result .. t.attr
        end
        result = result
                 .. my.node.tostring(t.nucleus, newline .. '.')
                 .. my.node.tostring(t.sup, newline .. '^')
                 .. my.node.tostring(t.sub, newline .. '_')
        return result
    end
    %
    my.math_char = {}
    function my.math_char.tostring(t, newline)
        return newline .. '\\\\fam' .. t.fam .. ' ' .. string.char(t.char)
    end
    %
    my.fence = {}
    function my.fence.tostring(t, newline)
        fencename = ({'\\\\left', '\\\\middle', '\\\\right'})[t.subtype]
        return newline .. fencename .. my.node.tostring(t.delim, ' ')
    end
    %
    my.delim = {}
    function my.delim.tostring(t, newline)
        return
            newline
            .. 'small: \\\\fam'
            .. t.small_fam
            .. ' '
            .. (t.small_char == 0 and '^'..'^@' or string.char(t.small_char))
            .. ', large: \\\\fam'
            .. t.large_fam
            .. ' '
            .. (t.large_char == 0 and '^'..'^@' or string.char(t.large_char))
    end
    %
    % subtype and attr ignored for sub_mlist?
    my.sub_mlist = {}
    function my.sub_mlist.tostring(mlist, newline)
        return my.mlist.tostring(mlist.head, newline)
    end
    %
    my.mlist = {}
    function my.mlist.tostring(h, newline)
        local result = ''
        for t in node.traverse(h) do
            result = result .. my.node.tostring(t, newline)
        end
        return result
    end
    %
    callback.register
      (
        "mlist_to_hlist",
        function (h, d, p)
            local tab = {}
            texio.write_nl('\\n')
            my.mlist.tostring(h, '\\n'):gsub('([^\\n]+)', texio.write_nl)
            texio.write_nl('\\n')
            return node.mlist_to_hlist(h, d, p)
        end
      )
  }
\endgroup

abc $ \mathord{\mathord{a}^b}^b \sum + = (),\left(2\middle|3\right)\sqrt{a}$ f

\bye
```