# Conflict between program and todonotes package

Tags: packages, incompatibility, todonotes, program

I want to add some pseudo-like code to my document using the `program` package, but when I add the package to my document, I get the following errors. I found out the problem being caused by a conflict between the package `todonotes` and `program`. Here is a minimum (non) working example, to reproduce my issue. My question: Is there any possibility to solve this issue (which means, I would like to keep both packages, as I currently use the `todonotes` heavily in my document).

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{program}
\usepackage[textsize=footnotesize]{todonotes}
\begin{document}
    Hello world!
\end{document}
```

The errors I get:

```
There were errors in your LaTeX source

/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex:673: Missing \endcsname inserted. [...eoperator{||}{or}        {2}{infix} {200}]
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex:673: Missing \endcsname inserted. [...eoperator{||}{or}        {2}{infix} {200}]
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex:673: Missing \endcsname inserted. [...eoperator{||}{or}        {2}{infix} {200}]
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex:673: Missing \endcsname inserted. [...eoperator{||}{or}        {2}{infix} {200}]
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex:673: Missing \endcsname inserted. [...eoperator{||}{or}        {2}{infix} {200}]
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.code.tex:15: No room for a new \dimen . [\newdimen\pgf@pt@x]
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.code.tex:16: No room for a new \dimen . [\newdimen\pgf@pt@y]
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.code.tex:18: No room for a new \dimen . [\newdimen\pgf@pt@temp]
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex:562: Missing \endcsname inserted. [}]
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex:562: Extra \endcsname. [}]
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex:562: Extra \else. [}]
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex:562: Missing \endcsname inserted. [}]
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex:562: Missing \endcsname inserted. [}]
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex:562: Missing \endcsname inserted. [}]
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex:562: Missing \endcsname inserted. [}]
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex:562: Package pgf Error: Arrow end type ``\relax \@dovar\hbox {}'' already defined. [}]
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex:15: No room for a new \dimen . [\newdimen\pgf@max]
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty:466: No room for a new \dimen . [\newdimen\pgf@nodesepstart]
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty:467: No room for a new \dimen . [\newdimen\pgf@nodesepend]
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex:13: No room for a new \dimen . [\newdimen\pgffor@iter]
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex:14: No room for a new \dimen . [\newdimen\pgffor@skip]
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex:872: No room for a new \dimen . [\newdimen\pgfplotmarksize]
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex:17: No room for a new \dimen . [\newdimen\tikz@lastx]
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex:18: No room for a new \dimen . [\newdimen\tikz@lasty]
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex:19: No room for a new \dimen . [\newdimen\tikz@lastxsaved]
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex:20: No room for a new \dimen . [\newdimen\tikz@lastysaved]
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex:22: No room for a new \dimen . [\newdimen\tikzleveldistance]
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex:23: No room for a new \dimen . [\newdimen\tikzsiblingdistance]
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex:885: Missing \endcsname inserted. [\tikz@set@pointed{\pgf@arrows@invertto}{to}]
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex:885: LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}. [\tikz@set@pointed{\pgf@arrows@invertto}{to}]
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex:885: Extra \endcsname. [\tikz@set@pointed{\pgf@arrows@invertto}{to}]
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex:885: Extra \else. [\tikz@set@pointed{\pgf@arrows@invertto}{to}]
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex:885: Missing \endcsname inserted. [\tikz@set@pointed{\pgf@arrows@invertto}{to}]
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex:885: Missing \endcsname inserted. [\tikz@set@pointed{\pgf@arrows@invertto}{to}]
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex:885: Missing \endcsname inserted. [\tikz@set@pointed{\pgf@arrows@invertto}{to}]
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex:885: Missing \endcsname inserted. [\tikz@set@pointed{\pgf@arrows@invertto}{to}]
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex:885: Missing \endcsname inserted. [\tikz@set@pointed{\pgf@arrows@invertto}{to}]
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex:885: Argument of \next has an extra }. [\tikz@set@pointed{\pgf@arrows@invertto}{to}]
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex:885: Paragraph ended before \next was complete. [\tikz@set@pointed{\pgf@arrows@invertto}{to}]
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex:885: Missing \endcsname inserted. [\tikz@set@pointed{\pgf@arrows@invertto}{to}]
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex:885: Argument of \next has an extra }. [\tikz@set@pointed{\pgf@arrows@invertto}{to}]
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex:885: Paragraph ended before \next was complete. [\tikz@set@pointed{\pgf@arrows@invertto}{to}]
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex:885: Missing \endcsname inserted. [\tikz@set@pointed{\pgf@arrows@invertto}{to}]
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex:885: Argument of \next has an extra }. [\tikz@set@pointed{\pgf@arrows@invertto}{to}]
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex:885: Use of \csname doesn't match its definition. [\tikz@set@pointed{\pgf@arrows@invertto}{to}]
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex:885: Missing control sequence inserted. [\tikz@set@pointed{\pgf@arrows@invertto}{to}]
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex:885: Argument of \next has an extra }. [\tikz@set@pointed{\pgf@arrows@invertto}{to}]
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex:885: Paragraph ended before \next was complete. [\tikz@set@pointed{\pgf@arrows@invertto}{to}]
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex:885: Package pgf Error: Arrow end type ``tikz@>\endgroup \let \par . [\tikz@set@pointed{\pgf@arrows@invertto}{to}]
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex:885: Missing \endcsname inserted. [\tikz@set@pointed{\pgf@arrows@invertto}{to}]
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex:885: Missing \endcsname inserted. [\tikz@set@pointed{\pgf@arrows@invertto}{to}]
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex:885: LaTeX Error: Variable name ended by end of line.. [\tikz@set@pointed{\pgf@arrows@invertto}{to}]
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty:54: No room for a new \dimen . [\newdimen\calc@Adimen]
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty:54: No room for a new \dimen . [\newdimen\calc@Adimen   \newdimen\calc@Bdimen]
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/subfigure/subfigure.sty:97: No room for a new \dimen . [\newdimen\subfigcaptopadj]
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/subfigure/subfigure.sty:99: No room for a new \dimen . [\newdimen\subfigcapmargin]
./Document.tex:1: Undefined control sequence. [\include{Header}]
./Document.tex:1: Undefined control sequence. [\include{Header}]
./Document.tex:1: Undefined control sequence. [\include{Header}]
./Document.tex:1: Undefined control sequence. [\include{Header}]
./Document.tex:1: Undefined control sequence. [\include{Header}]
./Document.tex:1: Extra \else. [\include{Header}]
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. When you have time, please have a look at our [page for starters](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Thank you, egreg and apologies for not having considered the starter page in advance. Using the MWE, I was able to track back the problem on a package conflict. I will edit my question accordingly.

Comment: The first measure should be changing the loading order: first `todonotes`, then `program`. The "No room for a new" errors can be cured by `\usepackage{etex}` just after the `\documentclass` line.

Comment: Yes; changing the package order solved the issue. Superb, thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A first measure when adding a package produces errors is to change the loading order; the present problem is due to some internal shuffling `program` does with “category codes” that confuse `todonotes` or, more properly, the TikZ engine it uses.

So

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[textsize=footnotesize]{todonotes}
\usepackage{program}

\begin{document}
    Hello world!
\end{document}
```

should be the solution.

From the error messages you report, there seems to be another problem; `program` makes intensive usage of internal registers and TikZ is quite hungry for them too, so other packages may cause overflowing the available number of registers. Just add `\usepackage{etex}` (see [No room for a new \dimen](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38607/no-room-for-a-new-dimen)); below I simulate a “real world” situation with `<other packages>` to remark that `etex` should be loaded as soon as possible.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{etex}

<other packages>

\usepackage[textsize=footnotesize]{todonotes}
\usepackage{program}

<other packages>

\begin{document}
    Hello world!
\end{document}
```