# How to use empheq with unicode-math?

Tags: xetex, unicode-math, empheq

I tried to change the engine from `pdfLaTeX` to `XeLaTeX`, but I can't compile a simple project:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage{english}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
    Ligatures=TeX,
    Extension=.otf,
    UprightFont= *-regular,
    BoldFont=*-bold,
    ItalicFont=*-italic,
    BoldItalicFont=*-bolditalic]{texgyrepagella}
\setmathfont[Extension=.otf]{texgyrepagella-math}

\usepackage{empheq}

\author{}
\title{}
\date{}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
\end{document}
```

But it produces error:

```
Command \dddot already defined. \hbox{\normalfont ...}\vss}}}}
Command \ddddot already defined. \hbox{\normalfont....}\vss}}}}
Extended mathchar used as mathchar (4203026) \mathchardef\std@minus\mathcode`\-\relax
Command \overleftrightarrow already defined. ...palette{\overarrow@\leftrightarrowfill@}}
Command \underrightarrow already defined. ...athpalette{\underarrow@\rightarrowfill@}}
Command \underleftarrow already defined. \mathpalette{\underarrow@\leftarrowfill@}}
Command \underleftrightarrow already defined. ...alette{\underarrow@\leftrightarrowfill@}}
```

Comment: load `empheq` first, just after `\documentclass` then let the xetex packages do their stuff

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: That's work, I haven't yet met the errors, that can be fixed by simply rearranging the `usepackage`'s...

Comment: Oh its very common see frequent answers telling to put hyperref last. Here both packages are defining several names of math commands, empheq is expecting them to be new so uses `\newcommand` so you get an error if they are already defined, unicode-math and friends are _expecting_ to redefine things to work in xetex so makes a gentle warning but redefines commands quite happily. So if you use empheq first it is happy and then unicode-math changes stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to load `empheq` before `unicode-math` so that it can define these commands and then unicode-math change them to work in xetex. Rather than the other way round where you get the error you show as `empheq` gives up as `unicode-math` has already defined things.