# Making a zip macro

Tags: tex-core

In functional languages, there often is a function called `zip`, which can be handy in many situations; for example in ruby, one can say:

```rb
%w(a b c).zip(%w(d e f))
```

to get an array of arrays `[["a", "d"], ["b", "e"], ["c", "f"]]`.

It seems that there are many ways to make a `zip` function, either with a [`map`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function)) ([another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4078910)), or [`foldr`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/235242). (The `map` might actually be done with `foldr`.)

But given that the `lambda.sty` lists do not seem to support nested lists, I'm not sure how would one go about making `zip` in TeX (with `lambda.sty`).

I tried something along the lines of which seemed the most simple;

```
\catcode`@=11
\input lambda.sty

\def\Zipwith#1#2#3{\Foldr#1{#3}{#2}}

\def\lista{\Listize[a,b,c]}
\def\listb{\Listize[d,e,f]}

\Unlistize{\Zipwith\Map\lista\listb}
\bye
```

but it results in `[abcd, abce, abcf]`. So, close but no cigar.

Would you have an idea?

I wouldn't actually need there to be nested lists as a result, just that for `lista` zipped with `listb`, some macro `\foo#1#2` would get run for (continuing with the example lists) three times, getting as its arguments on the first run `#1<-a, #2<-d`, on the second run `#1<-b, #2<-e`, and on the third `#1<-c, #2<-f`.

Comment: Are the lists always the same length?

Comment: @Werner: the lists can be any length, but the two lists need to always be of same length.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Great to see `expl3` in use in egreg's answer. Given the recent developments in the LaTeX3 interfaces I would like to "slightly" improve or change it as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

% package level definitions

\seq_new:N \l__morbusg_left_seq
\seq_new:N \l__morbusg_right_seq

% public package interface command

\cs_new:Npn \morbusg_zip:Nnnnn #1 #2 #3 #4 #5 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__morbusg_left_seq   { #2 } { #3 }
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__morbusg_right_seq { #4 } { #5 }
  \seq_mapthread_function:NNN \l__morbusg_left_seq \l__morbusg_right_seq #1
}

% xparse interface

\NewDocumentCommand{\zip}{ m O{,} m o m }
 { \IfNoValueTF {#4}
      { \morbusg_zip:Nnnnn #1 {#2} {#3} {#2} {#5} }
      { \morbusg_zip:Nnnnn #1 {#2} {#3} {#4} {#5} }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\foo}[2]{First is #1, second is #2\par}
\newcommand{\baz}[2]{Left is #1, right is #2\par}

\begin{document}
\zip{\foo}{a,b,c}{d,e,f}

\zip{\baz}[;]{A;B;C}{D;E;F}

\zip{\baz}{1,2,3}[!!]{X!!Y!Y!!Z}

\zip{\foo}[&]{9&8&7}[$]{5$4$3}
\end{document}
```

So what is different?

**Clear separation of functional interface `\morbusg_zip:Nnnnn` and document level interface `\zip`**.

As I outlined in [What can *I* do to help the LaTeX3 Project](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45838/what-can-i-do-to-help-the-latex3-project/46427#46427) the architecture of LaTeX3 separates out the two very clearly. `xparse`is a document level syntax package that implements LaTeX2e like syntax with optional arguments etc. But there might, and probably will, be alternatives, e.g., a key/value type of document level syntax, or an xml like syntax.

If properly separated the functional code, i.e., `\morbusg_zip:Nnnnn`would remain unchanged and you only switch the document level parsing routines. Maybe feels a bit like overkill in this particular example, but it helps to think in this way throughout and use the separation as best practice.

**Support for different separators on the two lists.**

The original solution used one and the same operator. I extended the functional definition to use one separator per list. So the functional definition offers more possibilities and it is up to the user interface to use or not use them, e.g., to get egreg's interface the definition for `\zip` would have been

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\zip}{ m O{,} m m }
    { \morbusg_zip:Nnnnn #1 {#2} {#3} {#2} {#4} }
```

i.e., reusing the same separator for both lists. Again that shows (imnsho) the advantage of decoupling the two levels.

**Clearly separating public interface and internal commands and variables**

Well, this time we only have one function and it is public, so only the two variables got marked as internal (which is they use `__` in their name). In a package one would/could have shortened that to `\l_@@_left_seq` where `@@` is a shorthand for the current "module" name with two `__`in front.

If the extended version is run through TeX you will get the following output (as you can see, stranger separators are possible too, e.g., `!!`, or `$` but that was already in the original solution):

[image]

Comment: Very nice lecture!

Comment: Maybe we should rename the 'mapthread' function to `\seq_zip:NNN` or something similar? (Perhaps `\seq_map_zip:NNN`, as we're trying to show what is a mapping.)

Answer (score 22):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_morbusg_left_seq
\seq_new:N \l_morbusg_right_seq

\NewDocumentCommand{\zip}{ m O{,} m m }
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_morbusg_left_seq  { #2 } { #3 }
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_morbusg_right_seq { #2 } { #4 }
  \seq_mapthread_function:NNN \l_morbusg_left_seq \l_morbusg_right_seq #1
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\foo}[2]{First is #1, second is #2\par}

\newcommand{\baz}[2]{Left is #1, right is #2\par}

\begin{document}
\zip{\foo}{a,b,c}{d,e,f}

\zip{\baz}[;]{A;B;C}{D;E;F}
\end{document}
```

The first argument to `\zip` is the two argument macro to apply; the optional argument is the list separator; then the two lists.

[image]

Comment: had some "stylistic" comments due to latest thinking in the LaTeX3 team, but that didn't fit a comment, so made it a separate answer.

Comment: egreg, @Frank: Thanks for an `expl3` answer, I'm sure it's very useful for its users. `:-)`

Answer (score 5):

The LaTeX3 solutions are probably how I'd tackle this (the sequence data structure is very well-designed), but if we assume that we can assume the lists use a comma separator as shown in the question then something like

```
\catcode`\@=11 %
\long\def\zip#1#2#3{%
  \zip@#3,#1,\q@recursion@tail,\q@mark,#2,\q@recursion@tail,\q@recursion@stop
}
\long\def\zip@#1,#2,#3\q@mark,#4,{%
  \stop@if@quark@recursion@tail{#2}
  \stop@if@quark@recursion@tail{#4}
  #1{#2}{#4}%
  \zip@#1,#3\q@mark,%
}
\long\def\stop@if@quark@recursion@tail#1{%
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\unexpanded{#1}}{\noexpand\q@recursion@tail}=\z@
    \expandafter\stop@if@quark@recursion@tail@aux
  \fi
}
\long\def\stop@if@quark@recursion@tail@aux#1\q@recursion@stop{}
\catcode`\@=12 %
\def\foo#1#2{[#1,#2]}
\zip{a,b,c}{1,2,3}\foo
\csname @@end\endcsname
\end
```

will work. (Note: this requires pdfTeX, but can also be worked with XeTeX and LuaTeX with the correct set up for `\pdfstrcmp`. Setting up without this primitive is doable but more awkward.)

The idea here is to grab one item from each list at a time. Each one is checked for the end marker `\q@recursion@tail`: I've assumed that the mapping simply stops when the shorter list ends.

Comment: It would of course be possible to set up `\zip` to generate the required auxiliary 'on the fly' with a variable list separator token.