# How to map optional arguments to functions?

Tags: latex3, xparse, mapping

What is the right way to map each optional argument to a function that applies a specific style to it?

In the example below, optional arguments are typeset in bold face preceded by a colon. But I want users to be able to define what style `#2` is to be typeset in, what style `#3` is to be typeset in, and so on:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand {\mystyle} { m } {:\textbf{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand {\mycs} { moooooooo }
 {
  #1
  \tl_set:Nn \l_my_tl { {#2} {#3} {#4} {#5} {#6} {#7} {#8} {#9} }
  \tl_map_inline:Nn \l_my_tl {\IfValueT{##1}{\mystyle{##1}}}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\mycs{1}[2][3][4][5][6][7][8][9]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following might be an option.  The `\setstyle` macro takes a comma separated list of commands names possibly preceded by characters.  By default the list is comma separated, but the optional argument can change the separator to whatever.  In the example below I used

`\setstyle{:\textbf,.\emph,\textsc}`

The `\usestyles` macro takes two mandatory arguments.  The first corresponds to your mandatory argument above, the second is a list of arguments.  By default the list is comma separated, but this can be changed with the optional argument.  The first `n` styles are then mapped to the first `n` arguments.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

% optional arg1 changes the separator for arg2
\NewDocumentCommand{\setstyle}{ O{,} m }{
    \ss_set_my_styles:nn {#1}{#2}
}

% optional arg1 changes the separator for arg3
\NewDocumentCommand{\usestyles}{ O{,} m m }{
    \ss_use_my_styles:nnn {#1}{#2}{#3}
}

% split style list at separator and store
\seq_new:N \g__ss_my_styles_seq
\cs_new:Npn \ss_set_my_styles:nn #1#2
    {
        \seq_set_split:Nnn \g__ss_my_styles_seq {#1}{#2}
    }

\cs_new:Npn \ss_use_my_styles:nnn #1#2#3
    {
        #2\par
        % split arg list at separator
        \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq {#1}{#3}
        % map styles to list items in order
        \seq_mapthread_function:NNN \g__ss_my_styles_seq \l_tmpa_seq \__ss_use:nn
    }

\cs_new:Npn \__ss_use:nn #1#2
    {
        % applies arg1 to arg2
        #1{#2}\par
    }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\setstyle{:\textbf,.\emph,\textsc}
\usestyles{first}{arg1,arg2,arg3}

\end{document}
```

---

---

Another option using `l3regex`.  With this you can add characters before and after the arguments.

- `\setstyle[<separator>][<string to replace>]{<style list>}`

The first optional sets the separator for the `<style list>` which defaults to a comma, the second sets the string to be replaced by the argument and defaults to `thearg`.

- `\usestyles[<separator>]{<1st mand>}{<list of args>}`

The optional again sets the separator for the third argument.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{l3regex}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \c__ss_repl_symb_tl
\seq_new:N \g__ss_my_styles_seq

% optional #1 sets separator
% optional #2 sets string to replace
\NewDocumentCommand{\setstyle}{ O{,} O{thearg} m }{
    \ss_set_my_styles:nn {#1}{#2}{#3}
}

% split style list at separator and store
\cs_new:Npn \ss_set_my_styles:nn #1#2#3 {
    \tl_gset:Nn \c__ss_repl_symb_tl {#2}
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \g__ss_my_styles_seq {#1}{#3}
}

% optional #1 sets separator to use when
% splitting #3
\NewDocumentCommand{\usestyles}{ O{,} m m }{
    \ss_use_my_styles:nnn {#1}{#2}{#3}
}

\cs_new:Npn \ss_use_my_styles:nnn #1#2#3 {
    #2\par
    % split arg list at separator
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq {#1}{#3}
    % map styles to list items in order
    \seq_mapthread_function:NNN \g__ss_my_styles_seq \l_tmpa_seq \__ss_use:nn
}

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_replace_all:nnN {VnN}    
\cs_new:Npn \__ss_use:nn #1#2 {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#1}
    \regex_replace_all:VnN {\c__ss_repl_symb_tl} {#2} \l_tmpa_tl
    \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl\par
}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\setstyle{before \textbf{thearg} after,before \emph{thearg} after,before \textsc{thearg} after}
\usestyles{first}{arg1,arg2,arg3}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you. But how can I allow users define complex styles as in the original example? For instance, one style inserts a colon before `arg1` and makes it bold face, while style 2 inserts a period before `arg2` and makes it italic. 1:**2**.__3__

Comment: With a small change you can put additional characters in front of the argument (but not after). I edited the answer to indicate how.

Comment: @nicolairostov Added an option that should allow additional formatting.

Comment: I'm just beginning to learn latex3.  So, I'm curious about your naming convention:  why `\c__ss_repl_symb_tl` instead of `\c_ss_repl_symb_tl`. ?  why `\g__ss_my_styles_seq` instead of `\g_ss_my_styles_seq`?  I'm also curious about the choice of `ss` in the command name.

Comment: @A.Ellett In an effort to be a good l3 citizen, I've been trying to follow the style conventions as laid out in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71459/14100)  (from a member of the l3 team).  The choice of `ss` was to reflect `s`et `s`tyle.  Looking now, it think that I failed with `\c__ss_repl_symb_tl` which I believe should have only 1 underscore: single underscore for macro's/tl's called by "document" commands, double underscores for anything not accessed directly by a "document" command as I understand it.

Comment: @ScottH. That's more-or-less right. In a 'quick hack' it's not so clear, but for a package we'd hope that 'code level interfaces' (one underscore) will be documented and that 'internal' (two underscore) stuff is not. The idea then is that you can access all the functionality the code offers without having to use or know any of those internals.

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks for chiming in, good to know that I'm pointed in the right direction.