# Where can I report typographical errors for LaTeX3 documentation?

Tags: latex3, contribute

Following up on [What can *I* do to help the LaTeX3 Project](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45838), there doesn't seem to be a definitive place to report a typo in any of the LaTeX3 documentation (e.g. `texdoc interface3`).

Where can I report such errors?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As with anything related to LaTeX3, you have a few routes:

- [Log an issue](https://github.com/latex3/svn-mirror/issues/new) on the [GitHub mirror](https://github.com/latex3/svn-mirror), which means you can link to the code (as the 'master' version is not Git, pull requests don't add much)
- Raise it on [LaTeX-L](http://www.lsoft.com/scripts/wl.exe?SL1=LATEX-L&H=LISTSERV.UNI-HEIDELBERG.DE)
- E-mail the team: latex-team@latex-project.org

Comment: The same applies to code issues, ideas, ...

Comment: Naturally. I did previously think though that the GitHub mirror was just that - a mirror. I didn't think it was actively looked at.

Comment: @SeanAllred The code is a mirror but the issue database is very handy: the LaTeX2e one (Gnats-based) is a nightmare.