# Good resources to understand how LaTeX is constructed layer after layer?

Tags: programming, documentation, tutorials

I have been a user of LaTeX for a couple of years now, and I would like to start to be involved in the writing packages. The problem is that currently, a lot of things appear to me as "black magic".

In `C` and `C++`, I have a good culture of how the languages work from the raw hardware to the compiler and the high-level part (the part that most people use), but for the moment, in LaTeX, I only know the "high-level" layer and I would like to understand the basics starting from "the bare metal".

What would be good resources to understand the whole logic behind TeX and LaTeX, how does it work "behind the scenes" and how it is constructed layer after layer ?

Comment: To understand TeX, read [The TeXbook](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/texbook)...

Comment: The contents of `TEXMFMAIN/tex/latex/base/`, the TeXbook (as Werner said), TeX by Topic...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Comment: I've been going through and cleaning the [tag:latex3] tag, but if this *is* asking partly about LaTeX3, Frank wrote a wonderful article about it: [What can *I* do to help the LaTeX3 Project?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46427/17423).