# Should expl3 code be used in packages intended to be compatible with multiple formats?

Tags: best-practices, package-writing, expl3

<sub>Maybe this question is just not a good idea in general, but, I'm curious. This could make package development simpler for some in the future. (Of course, this would not be forced on any package developer, but he/she could choose to use this approach or the traditional approach.) I guess the real key is that it could provide additional options for those who wished to use them.</sub>

---

Numerous packages<sup>1</sup>, including two I use quite frequently ([`pgf`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) and [`pgfplots`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots)) are implemented in a generic way that makes them usable with multiple formats. In the case of `pgf`/`pgfplots`, these "packages" work equally well in Plain TeX, LaTeX, and ConTeXt documents.

To accomplish this goal (ensuring compatibility with many formats), the code uses TeX primitives for implementation as a "common denominator". As a result, the code is full of `\expandafter`s, end-of-line `%`s, and all sorts of other TeX programming constructs that `expl3` syntax aims to abstract away from the programmer. (Not unlike LaTeX's original aim of abstracting these away from the typical document author.)

Along the lines of [`miniltx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/miniltx) and [`eplain`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/eplain), I imagine that all or some subset of `expl3` might be provided for use by format-agnostic package developers. When researching this question, I discovered that this possibility seems to be already available in the form of `expl3-generic.tex` that `\input`s the core `expl3` code (`expl3-code.tex`) in a format-neutral way.

- Was this design choice made with these types of uses in mind, or was there another reason to structure the code in this way? (Ease of low-level testing, for instance.)
- Do any current or in-development sets of format-neutral macros ("packages") use this approach?
- Finally, along the lines of the title: Is this a recommended practice? Should format-neutral packages (at the discretion of their authors, of course) use `expl3` syntax/conventions internally?

---

<sup>1</sup> Check your TDS tree at `texmf-dist/tex/generic` for some examples.

Comment: yes, no, perhaps:-)

Comment: See [this comment by Frank](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41?m=20892461#20892461). `expl3` is designed to be format-agnostic, but it does require e-TeX.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle There's `lt3graph`, for the most part

Comment: Off-topic: I am planning to learn `expl3` for updating my packages too, to be on the 'safe' side ;-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I was hoping for something with a bit of explanation behind the "perhaps". :-)

Comment: As you pointed out in chat, `termmenu` is such a package :) I chose expl3 because it made my job easier. I believe that's what David means – if expl3 makes your job easier, then by all means, use it. If it doesn't, what's the point?

Comment: @SeanAllred it's an *ex post facto* package. :-)

Comment: Well I didn't really make it for this post :-) actually just a small part of a larger project, to be announced ;)

Comment: @SeanAllred I believe you, it was just a (perhaps bad) joke. ;-)

Comment: @PaulGessler :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The core purpose of `expl3` is to form the programming layer for wider development of new LaTeX tools. At present, this work is carried out on top of the LaTeX2e format and so `expl3` was conceived as a LaTeX2e package. However, `expl3` is quite self-contained, putting all TeX primitives into a dedicated namespace and using them to build up the code environment. As a result, the idea of providing a version of `expl3` which can be loaded by formats other than LaTeX2e was first suggests some time ago, but only effected recently.

The implementation of `expl3` such that it can be loaded by different formats was done precisely to allow the code to be used with multiple formats. This followed a request from the user community. Thus the cross-format nature of `expl3` is intended to allow developers to use the code base to support their work. Importantly, only `expl3` is currently set up to load in this way: the same is *not* true for any additional `expl3`-based code (*e.g.* `l3regex`).

As to whether one wishes to use this ability, it will come down to the developers involved. For some developers of generic code, dependencies are to be avoided and indeed working at the 'bare metal' primitive level may be regarded as a positive factor. On the other hand, if you find `expl3` to be a useful development environment then this is your call and you are free to use it to support your work. For example, the team are using the generic loading ability of `expl3` to write scripts which execute in plain but with the richer set of tools available when using the coding environment.

It is important to remember that `expl3` only provides a code layer and thus anything 'higher level' will still have to be handled on a per-format basis.

---

If you want to use `expl3` in generic mode, the generic loader is called using

```
\input expl3-generic\relax
```

If used with LaTeX2e this will switch to the standard package, whilst for plain TeX and ConTeXt it will load as-is. At present, generic loading has not been tested with other formats.

Note that the graphics driver selection in generic mode always goes with the automatic driver selections. This means that (currently) working with `dvipdfmx` specials is not possible. If there is a significant need this may be re-examined.

Comment: How complicated would it actually be to add testing for the other formats? (At least Plain.) As I understand it, the project does use testing scripts.

Answer (score 8):

<sup>These are the recollections and opinions of a mere mortal.</sup>

> Was this design choice made with these types of uses in mind, or was there another reason to structure the code in this way? (Ease of low-level testing, for instance.)

As David notes in the comments and Frank noted in chat, this choice was made deliberately.  I suspect it was largely driven to separate further the ideas of logic, interface, presentation, and content.  That said, the language was also clearly designed to be very structured: a great deal of thought seems to have gone into its design and implementation to keep the good parts of TeX programming, abstract away the bad parts, and solve *real* modern typesetting problems while providing a relatively sane programming environment.

The rigid structure of expl3 helps *everyone*.

> Do any current or in-development sets of format-neutral macros ("packages") use this approach?

Well as a matter of fact, yes :-) [`termmenu`](http://ctan.org/pkg/termmenu) (currently in active development; I swear I didn't write it just for this question) uses solely expl3 to implement a terminal-driven menu system.

`lt3graph` could also *easily* be made format-agnostic, but alas: it is not.  Note that this too is primarily an extension of the expl3 programming language.

I think that this idea of extensions (in expl3-speak, 'modules') is what will drive expl3 development forward in the community.  LaTeX3, using expl3, will drive development for LaTeX.

> Finally, along the lines of the title: Is this a recommended practice? Should format-neutral packages (at the discretion of their authors, of course) use expl3 syntax/conventions internally?

I recommend it where it makes sense.  If you're creating something that is solely a programming problem, then *absolutely* implement it with expl3.  If it has a presentation element, however, [*keep the layers separate*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46427/17423).  Either make it completely a LaTeX package or peel away the pure logic into an expl3 module.

In any case, don't forget your prefix :)