# Underbrace and Subscripts

Tags: subscripts

How do I place a underbrace in a subscript?

```
I_{2,(\underbrace{3,3,3,3,3}_5)}
```

does not typeset correctly (the 3's are not subscript sized)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about a quick and simple `I_{2,(\underbrace{\scriptstyle3,3,3,3,3}_5)}`?

Answer (score 8):

Jan already gave a good answer. However, I'd say it's a real weakness of `\underbrace` that you have to do this manually. (One might even call it a bug.) Here's a surprisingly complicated redefinition of `\underbrace` that automatically inserts `\scriptstyle` if needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\let\saved@underbrace\underbrace
\renewcommand*\underbrace[1]{\@ifnextchar_{\ub@with{#1}}{\ub@without{#1}}}
\def\ub@with#1_#2{\mathpalette\underbrace@i{{#1}{_{#2}}}}
\newcommand*\ub@without[1]{\mathpalette\underbrace@i{{#1}{}}}
\newcommand*\underbrace@i[2]{\underbrace@ii#1#2}
\newcommand*\underbrace@ii[3]{\saved@underbrace{#1#2}#3}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
$I_{2,(\underbrace{3,3,3,3,3}_5)}$
\end{document}
```

One of the problems I had to overcome is very similar to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3875/1235) of mine: The underscore must go *inside* the mathpalette (if present).

Comment: I'll add something like this to unicode-math when I tackle the other under/over brace issues. Thanks!

Comment: @will: luatex seems not to have a problem here, the digits are in script style already with no other modifications (it seems an issue confined to the plain tex definition of underbrace)

Comment: @Khaled yeah, I was more referring to the terrible brokenness of these in xetex.