# How to avoid change of textsize when using underbrace?

Tags: math-mode, fontsize

I'd like to use `underbrace` in a formula:

```
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{r/C/l?s}
P_{a} \left( a | \gamma, \epsilon, \hat{K} \right)
 & = & \frac{1}{1 + \frac{\gamma}{\epsilon} \times
\underbrace{
 \frac{\alpha_{X} \left( p_{f} | \hat{K} \right)} {\alpha_{Y} \left( a | \hat{S} \right)}
}_{\Gamma \left( a | \hat{K} \right)}
}
 & \IEEEnonumber
\end{IEEEeqnarray}
```

Compared to the formula without underbrace, the the underbraced part is enlarged:

```
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{r/C/l?s}
P_{a} \left( a | \gamma, \epsilon, \hat{K} \right)
 & = & \frac{1}{1 + \frac{\gamma}{\epsilon} \times
% \underbrace{
 \frac{\alpha_{X} \left( p_{f} | \hat{K} \right)} {\alpha_{Y} \left( a | \hat{S} \right)}
% }_{\Gamma \left( a | \hat{K} \right)}
}
 & \IEEEnonumber
\end{IEEEeqnarray}
```

How can I avoid the change of the font-size when underbracing parts of a formula?

Comment: Exactly the same question, but with scriptstyle without textstyle as the desired target: [Underbrace and Subscripts - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5442/underbrace-and-subscripts)

Answer (score 8):

Add `\textstyle` inside `\underbrace`; better, define a new command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\newcommand{\tunderbrace}[1]{\underbrace{\textstyle#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{r/C/l?s}
P_{a} ( a | \gamma, \epsilon, \hat{K} )
 & = & \frac{1}{1 + \frac{\gamma}{\epsilon} \times
\tunderbrace{
 \frac{\alpha_{X} ( p_{f} | \hat{K} )} {\alpha_{Y} ( a | \hat{S} )}
}_{\Gamma ( a | \hat{K} )}
}
 & \IEEEnonumber
\end{IEEEeqnarray}
\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, you should have discovered why using indiscriminately `\left` and `\right` is wrong.

You probably also want to use `\mid` instead of `|`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\newcommand{\tunderbrace}[1]{\underbrace{\textstyle#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{r/C/l?s}
P_{a} ( a \mid \gamma, \epsilon, \hat{K} )
 & = & \frac{1}{1 + \frac{\gamma}{\epsilon} \times
\tunderbrace{
 \frac{\alpha_{X} ( p_{f} \mid \hat{K} )} {\alpha_{Y} ( a \mid \hat{S} )}
}_{\Gamma ( a \mid \hat{K} )}
}
 & \IEEEnonumber
\end{IEEEeqnarray}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would use a different name for `\mid`. This looks like conditional propability, i.e. `\let\mid\given` would make more sense as a first approx, i.e. `P_a(a \given y,\epsilon,\hat{K})` it makes a lot more sense when reading the than using `\mid`. And as a second approx I'd use a macro that allowed `\given` to grow along the outer fences.

Comment: @daleif OFFTOPIC! I usually prefer `\newcommand\given{\,|\,}` because in that context the large spacing around `\mid` doesn't look good, IMHO.

Comment: @Manuel, I do the same thing, but I tend to use `\:` not, `\,`, but that is a personal preference. Though, since `\given` can be used in many different contexts, I have a definition for each, such that the macro that gives the outer fences redefines `\given`, then e.g. a `\Set{a\in A \given a^2>0}` does not need to have the same *symbol* as used in a conditional propability.

Answer (score 6):

The following example is based on [egreg's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/155046/16967) (last example with `\mid`). It defines `\KeepStyleUnderBrace` that also works for the other math styles automatically:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}

\newcommand*{\KeepStyleUnderBrace}[1]{%
  \mathop{%
    \mathchoice
    {\underbrace{\displaystyle#1}}%
    {\underbrace{\textstyle#1}}%
    {\underbrace{\scriptstyle#1}}%
    {\underbrace{\scriptscriptstyle#1}}%
  }\limits
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{IEEEeqnarray}{r/C/l?s}
    P_{a} ( a \mid \gamma, \epsilon, \hat{K} )
    & = &
    \frac{1}{1 + \frac{\gamma}{\epsilon} \times
      \KeepStyleUnderBrace{
        \frac{\alpha_{X} ( p_{f} \mid \hat{K} )}
             {\alpha_{Y} ( a \mid \hat{S} )}
      }_{\Gamma ( a \mid \hat{K} )}
    }
    & \IEEEnonumber
  \end{IEEEeqnarray}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: This is a great kludge. IMHO this should be the default behaviour of `\underbrace`.