# underbrace in superscript exponentiation

Tags: superscripts, braces

So I have this latex code

```
\underbrace{
  a^{\frac{1}{n}} \cdot a^{\frac{1}{n}} \cdot \ldots \cdot a^{\frac{1}{n}}
}_{n\text{-times}}} = 
a^{
  \underbrace{
    \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n} + \ldots + \frac{1}{n}
  }_{n\text{-times}}
} =
a^{1} = a
```

that renders in this formula:
[image]

but as you can see the second summation in the exponent is rendered too big.

How to typeset it correctly?

Comment: I believe something very similar has already appeared: `\underbrace{\scriptstyle...}_{n\text{ times}}` (no hyphen, in my opinion).

Comment: Does Heiko's solution to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155043/how-to-avoid-change-of-textsize-when-using-underbrace satisfy you?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. It does it perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

So adding `\scriptstyle` does the trick (thanks to @egreg):

```
\underbrace{
  a^{\frac{1}{n}} \cdot a^{\frac{1}{n}} \cdot \ldots \cdot a^{\frac{1}{n}}
}_{n\text{-times}}} = 
a^{
  \underbrace{\scriptstyle{
    \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n} + \ldots + \frac{1}{n}}
  }_{n\text{-times}}
} =
a^{1} = a
```

[image]