# The mysteries of \mathpalette

Tags: math-mode, plain-tex

I would like to make a macro, `\vfrac`, which output would look like:

```
$$\displaylines{
  \displaystyle\raise.25ex\hbox{$\displaystyle1$}\!/\!\lower.5ex\hbox{$\displaystyle2$} \cr
  \textstyle\raise.25ex\hbox{$\textstyle1$}\!/\!\lower.5ex\hbox{$\textstyle2$}\cr
  \scriptstyle\raise.25ex\hbox{$\scriptstyle1$}\!/\!\lower.5ex\hbox{$\scriptstyle2$}\cr
  \scriptscriptstyle\raise.25ex\hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle1$}\!/\!\lower.5ex\hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle2$}\cr
}$$
```

[image]

I use the plain-format, so I tried to follow the TeXbook Appendix B:

```
\catcode`@=11
\def\vfrac#1#2{\mathpalette\vfr@c{#1}{#2}}
\def\vfr@c#1#2{\raise.5ex\hbox{$#1$}/\lower.25ex\hbox{$#2$}}
\catcode`@=12
$\vfrac{1}{2} \quad {}^{\vfrac12}$
```

which looks like

[image]

What is this I don't even...

Oh wait, it looks like it's taking the "1" as the second argument. A quick search through tex.sx gives me [Hendrik's question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3875/problem-with-mathpalette-and-mathchoice), where he just gives an empty first argument to `\mathpalette`. However, when I try that in my above macro, I get an error `! Argument of \vfr@c has an extra }.`

I'm at loss. How does `\mathpalette` work?

Comment: Does defining `\vfrac` using `\def\vfrac#1#2{\mathpalette\relax{\vfr@c{#1}{#2}}}` or `\def\vfrac#1#2{\mathpalette{\vfr@c{#1}{#2}}\relax}` solve your problem?

Comment: @Werner: it fixed the correct reading of arguments, but the `\hbox` contents do not get the correct size (now that I think about it, how could they). I should somehow be able to put the first argument to `\mathpalette` as an argument to `\vr@c` I think.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`\mathpalette` comes very handy in many situations where similar token lists must be passed to `\mathchoice`, that is, we want an expansion of the form

```
\mathchoice
  {<something in \displaystyle>}
  {<something in \textstyle>}
  {<something in \scriptstyle>}
  {<something in \scriptscriptstyle>}
```

However, to allow for maximum flexibility, the first argument to `\mathpalette` must be a two-argument macro, whose first argument is a math style declaration. Let's see an example, Plain TeX definition of `\in`:

```
\def\notin{\mathrel{\mathpalette\c@ncel\in}}
```

This is followed by

```
\def\c@ncel#1#2{\m@th\ooalign{$\hfil#1\mkern1mu/\hfil$\crcr$#1#2$}}
```

Don't look at the complications of `\c@ncel` but at the fact that the first argument must indeed be a style declaration. If TeX finds `\notin` it will do `\mathrel{\mathpalette\c@ncel\in}`, and the subformula inside `\mathrel` is expanded into

```
\mathchoice
  {\c@ncel\displaystyle{\in}}%
  {\c@ncel\textstyle{\in}}%
  {\c@ncel\scriptstyle{\in}}%
  {\c@ncel\scriptscriptstyle{\in}}
```

so, in text style the math list to typeset will be `\c@ncel\textstyle{\in}`, that is

```
\m@th\ooalign{$\hfil\textstyle\mkern1mu/\hfil$\crcr$\textstyle\in$}
```

Here `\ooalign` is the trick that allows for superimposing characters (it's a simple `\halign` but baseline skip is suppressed). The effect is of superimposing a slighly offset bar to `\in`.

The call of `\mathpalette` can also be of the form `\def\xyz{\mathpalette\XYZ}` and in this case the macro `\xyz` will appear to take an argument, which will actually be the second argument for \XYZ. And this is why the macro is defined this way.

Your `\vfrac` macro can be defined via `\mathpalette`, since the structure is the same; but the two arguments must be gathered before calling `\mathpalette` and stored in some macros:

```
\catcode`@=11
\def\vfrac#1#2{\def\vf@num{#1}\def\vf@den{#2}\mathpalette\vfr@c\relax}
\def\vfr@c#1#2{%
  \raise.5ex\hbox{$\m@th#1\vf@num$}\!/\!\lower.25ex\hbox{$\m@th#1\vf@den$}}
\catcode`@=12
```

(As Aditya observes, `\m@th` should always be called in these cases.) Here we don't need the second argument for `\vfr@c`, but it must be there anyway; one can use `\relax` or `{}`, it's the same: that second argument will never be used.

Comment: Ah, ofcourse! I was so stuck at thinking how to transport the parameters "as is" to the helper macro, it didn't even occur to me you could just `\def` them. Thanks!

Comment: The two arguments can also be packed in `{{#1}{#2}}` and retrieved using `\@car` `\@cdr` or `\@first/secondoftwo` if definitions are to be avoided.

Answer (score 27):

`\mathpalette` is defined as

```
\def\mathpalette#1#2{%
  \mathchoice
    {#1\displaystyle{#2}}%
    {#1\textstyle{#2}}%
    {#1\scriptstyle{#2}}%
    {#1\scriptscriptstyle{#2}}}
```

and therefore takes two arguments. The first argument is typeset as-is in the respective style as chosen by `\mathchoice`, while the second argument is typeset with a forced style.

The elementary nature of your `\vfrac` macro, it suffices to supply `\relax` as the first `#1` or second `#2` argument to `\mathpalette`.

---

A better choice might be to use `\mathchoice` directly in your definition of `\vfrac`:

```
$$\displaylines{
  \displaystyle\raise.25ex\hbox{$\displaystyle1$}\!/\!\lower.5ex\hbox{$\displaystyle2$} \cr
  \textstyle\raise.25ex\hbox{$\textstyle1$}\!/\!\lower.5ex\hbox{$\textstyle2$}\cr
  \scriptstyle\raise.25ex\hbox{$\scriptstyle1$}\!/\!\lower.5ex\hbox{$\scriptstyle2$}\cr
  \scriptscriptstyle\raise.25ex\hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle1$}\!/\!\lower.5ex\hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle2$}\cr
}$$

\def\vfrac#1#2{%
  \mathchoice%
    {\raise.5ex\hbox{$\displaystyle#1$}/\lower.25ex\hbox{$\displaystyle#2$}}% \displaystyle
    {\raise.5ex\hbox{$\textstyle#1$}/\lower.25ex\hbox{$\textstyle#2$}}% \textstyle
    {\raise.5ex\hbox{$\scriptstyle#1$}/\lower.25ex\hbox{$\scriptstyle#2$}}% \scriptstyle
    {\raise.5ex\hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle#1$}/\lower.25ex\hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle#2$}}% \scriptscriptstyle
}%

$\vfrac{1}{2} \quad {}^{\vfrac12}$
```

[image]

You may have to change the `\raise` and `\lower` quantities to match that in your `\displaylines` depending on your usage. Moreover, now you're down to one macro!

Comment: That's nice, thanks, but every time I find myself writing the exact same thing more than once, I get the feeling I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: You should set `\mathsurround` to `0` to avoid extra spacing around math. Usually this is done by using `\hbox{\m@th$...$}`

Comment: @morbusg: That's true. But it's better that such coding is hidden from view in a macro that it clutter the readability within the general document.

Comment: The explicit `\mathchoice` approach is definitely the way to go in case I need to make small adjustments to each style level. Thanks again!