# Command for fontsize-dependent code selection

Tags: math-mode, fontsize

I have heard of a LaTeX-command which provides font-dependent code selection in math mode, but I forgot the name of it and cannot find it – Here is what I mean:

```
\unknownCommand{display size code}{text size code}{script size code}{scriptscript size code}
```

so that one could write

```
$\unknownCommand{...}$ % => outputs "display size code"
$e^{\unknownCommand{...}}$ % => outputs "script size code"
```

Do you know what command it is?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34393/the-mysteries-of-mathpalette

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  \mathchoice{display}{text}{script}{scriptscript}
```

But beware `\mathchoice` is one of the most weird and hard to use parts of TeX, it always typesets all four branches and TeX makes a decision much later when converting the math list into a horizontal list as to which branch to use. (This is to support the unfortunate syntax of the `\over` primitive which means you don't know what style you are in at the point macros are expanded)