# Right superscript dot

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, accents

I would like to achieve the following: a dot right of an expression

with this minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{accents}

\newcommand{\dotr}[1]{%
#1\accentset{\mbox{\bfseries .}}{\vphantom{#1}}}

\begin{document}
$\dotr{(X+Y)}$
\end{document}
```

but the dot is too high. How can I lower the dot?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple solution using `\bullet` as superscript:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\dotr}[1]{#1^{\bullet}} 

\begin{document}
$\dotr{(X+Y)}$  
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

If the bullet is too large, it can be reduced using the `graphicx` package. The following example also measures the first term and puts the bullet as high as possible without exceeding the height of the term before:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\dotr}[1]{%
  \mathpalette\@dotr{#1}%
}
\newcommand*{\@dotr}[2]{%
  % #1: math style (\displaystyle, ..., \scriptscriptstyle)
  % #2: argument of \dotr
  \sbox0{$\m@th#1#2$}%
  \usebox{0}%
  % simulating a superscript
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\ht0-\height}{$\m@th#1\@smallbullet#1\bullet$}%
  \kern\scriptspace
}
\newcommand*{\@smallbullet}[2]{%
  \scalebox{.5}{$\m@th#1#2$}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$\dotr{(X+Y)}$
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Remarks:

- The size of the small bullet can be configured by the number for `\scalebox`.
- `\mathpalette` takes into account the current math style.
  It is further explained in the answers of question ["The mysteries of `\mathpalette`"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34393/the-mysteries-of-mathpalette). Therefore `\@dotr` has two arguments, the first argument is the math style.
- `\m@th` is just a shortcut (defined in the LaTeX kernel) for `\mathsurround=0pt` for the case someone the feature of having additional white space around math formulas.
- `\sbox` is the LaTeX version of setting a box register (first argument) with a horizontal box, whose contents is given in the second argument. It should be explained in a LaTeX manual. Even box numbers below 10 are free scratch registers for local assignments. The group is indirectly given by `\mathpalette`.

Comment: Couldy you explain what exactly `\sbox0{$\m@th#1#2$}` does and from where the definition of `\ht0` comes? Why has `\@dotr` 2 arguments? Thx alot!

Comment: @Gabriel I have extended the "Remarks".

Answer (score 6):

another approach:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\dotr}{\mbox{$\boldsymbol{\cdot}$}}

\begin{document}
$(X+Y)^{\dotr}$
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

Answer (score 3):

Your title says "Left" but your example code has a standard right superscript?

Assuming you want it on the right, I'd probably just do

```
(X+Y)^{\cdot}
```

Comment: good idea, but the dot is kind of puny.  see my answer.

Comment: true but `\bullet` is a bit big and `\scriptscriptstyle\bullet` too much to type. Oh I see you used a bold one, OK.

Answer (score 1):

The altitude of the dot is adjustable, currently 1ex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}    
\newcommand{\dotr}[1]{#1\mbox{\bfseries\addvbuffer[-1ex 1ex]{.}}}
\begin{document}
$\dotr{(X+Y)}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please compare:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{accents}

\newcommand{\dotr}[1]{%
#1\accentset{\mbox{\bfseries .}}{\vphantom{#1}}}

\begin{document}
$\dotr{(X+Y)}$ 

$(X+Y)^{\textstyle\textbf{.}}$
\end{document}
```

Of course, corrections of the heighth are possible.

[image]