# latex math symbol for pointer in object oriented context

Tags: symbols, arrows

I need to use the pointer symbol (like P->a) in math latex. If I use normal characters like hyphen and > it doesn't look good. I guess there should be a specific symbol for it in latex, but I didn't find it anywhere.

The hyphen should be connected to the edge of ">", like when you type --> in microsoft office and it changes it automatically.

Any idea?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own by joining two `-` and `>` in math mode:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\my@arrow}[1]{\ooalign{$#1-\mkern-5mu-$\cr\hidewidth$#1>$}}
\newcommand{\myarrow}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\my@arrow\relax}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
$A \rightarrow B$ \par
$A \longrightarrow B$ \par
$A -> B$ \par
$A \myarrow B_{A \myarrow B_{A \myarrow B}}$
\end{document}
```

The use of `\mathpalette` is explained in [The mysteries of `\mathpalette`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34393/5764). It's used as a helper function for `\mathchoice` to scale math content to the required style (size).