# Minus-like sign with stuff on top

Tags: symbols, stacking-symbols

I want to create an operator that works like a minus sign (including the spacing), but has the characters `res` on top (in `\textrm` mode). The length of the minus sign should be adjusted to look like underlining the `res` characters, and it needs to work in a subscript.  Currently I am using

```
\newcommand{\residue}[2]{#1\overset{\text{res}}{\relbar\mathrel{\mkern-3mu}\relbar\rule{0pt}{2pt}}#2}
```

which means in particular the operator I am using is

```
\relbar\mathrel{\mkern-3mu}\relbar\rule{0pt}{2pt}
```

but it leaves a bit of space between the two dashes (especially in subscripts), and in inline or display mode, there's too much line to the left of the letters `res`.

What is a better way to produce this symbol?

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following example defines macro `\res` with an optional argument for a different text than `res`:

- The size of the text is the size of a superscript (`\scriptsize` or `\scriptscriptsize`). Smaller sizes are not recommended to avoid the
  need for magnifying glasses.
- The vertical distance between the text and the minus sign is approximately the distance between the text and the underline by `\underline`.
- A longer minus sign is created by appending minus signs with some overlapping.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

% test for different fonts
%\usepackage{MnSymbol}
%\usepackage{mathabx}
%\usepackage{txfonts}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\res}[1][res]{%
  \mathbin{%
    \mathpalette\@res{\mathrm{#1}}%
  }%
}
\newmuskip\res@sidebearing
\setlength{\res@sidebearing}{1.5mu}% e.g. 1.5mu/CM, 1mu/MnSymbol
\newcommand*{\@res}[2]{%
  % #1: math style
  % #2: text
  \sbox0{$%
    \m@th
    \res@style#1%
    #2%
  $}%
  \sbox2{$\m@th#1\mkern-\res@sidebearing-\mkern-\res@sidebearing$}%
  \setbox4=\copy2 %
  \ifdim\wd4<\wd0 %
    \@whiledim\wd4<\wd0\do{%
      \dimen@=\dimexpr\wd4+.8\wd2\relax
      \ifdim\dimen@<\wd0 %
        \sbox4{\unhcopy4\hss\kern-.2\wd2\unhcopy2}%
      \else
        \setbox4=\hbox to \wd0{%
          \unhcopy4\hss\kern-.2\wd2\unhcopy2%
        }%
      \fi
    }%
  \fi
  \sbox6{$#1\vcenter{}$}%
  % \sbox8{$#1\mathop{}\limits^{}$}% alternative
  \sbox8{$\res@style#1\underline{}$}% ht8 + dp8 = 5 theta; sep = 3 theta
  \mkern1.5mu %
  \rlap{\copy4}%
  \hbox to \wd4{%
    \hfill
    % \raisebox{\dimexpr\dp0+\ht6+.5\ht8\relax}{\copy0}% alternative
    \raisebox{\dimexpr\dp0+\ht6+.7\dimexpr\ht8+\dp8\relax\relax}{\copy0}%
    \hfill
  }%
  \mkern1.5mu %
}
\newcommand*{\res@style}[1]{%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle
    \scriptstyle
  \else
    \ifx#1\textstyle
      \scriptstyle
    \else
      \scriptscriptstyle
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
% Test: "res" and long word "garbage" with descender
\begin{gather*}
  \displaystyle      A \res B \res[garbage] C \res[r] D \\
  \textstyle         A \res B \res[garbage] C \res[r] D \\
  \scriptstyle       A \res B \res[garbage] C \res[r] D \\
  \scriptscriptstyle A \res B \res[garbage] C \res[r] D
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Difficulties and properties of the minus sign:**

- The line thickness is not known. Thus the line thicknesses of `\underline` or `\frac` might be different.
- In many fonts, the line ends are rounded. The lines of `\underline` and `\frac` are not, because they are rules or rectangles.
- The side bearings, horizontal space at both ends, are not known.
  The implementation defines a math skip register `\res@sidebearing`
  for fine tuning.
- At least the vertical position is known, this should be the math axis.

**Remarks:**

- Box 0 contains the test in superscript size.
- Box 2 contains the minus sign minus side bearings.
- Box 4 is constructed with as many boxes 2 as needed to get a line that
  is long enough for the text.
- The height of box 6 is the math axis.
- Box 8: `\underline{...}` is similar to:

  ```
  \vtop{
    \hbox{...}
    \kern 3θ
    \hrule height θ
    \kern θ
  }
  ```

  Box 8 contains an empty `\underline{}` and allows the calculation of the separation space 3θ: `0.6\dimexpr\ht8+\dp8\relax`.

  Also the half height of the minus rule needs to be added and it is approximated by θ/2 (the part above the math axis).
- `\m@th` is short for `\mathsurround=0pt` to avoid additional horizontal spacing, if `\mathsurround` is set.
- `\mathpalette` helps to set the formula for the current math style.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps the following works for you; I changed the notation slightly from `\residue{A}{B}` to `A \residue B`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}*{3}{p{.3333\linewidth}@{}}}
  \texttt{Original} & \texttt{Choice 1} & \texttt{Choice 2} \\
  \newcommand{\residue}[2]{#1\overset{\text{res}}{\relbar\mathrel{\mkern-3mu}\relbar\rule{0pt}{2pt}}#2}

  $\residue{A}{B}$ \par
  $C^{\residue{A}{B}}$ \par
  $C^{D^{\residue{A}{B}}}$

  &

  \makeatletter
  \newcommand{\residue@}[1]{#1\overset{\text{\raisebox{.15em}{res}}}{\smash{-\mkern-5mu-}}}
  \newcommand{\residue}{\mathbin{\mathpalette\residue@\relax}}
  \makeatother

  $A \residue B$ \par
  $C^{A \residue B}$ \par
  $C^{D^{A \residue B}}$

  &

  \newcommand{\residue}{\mathbin{\mathchoice
    {\overset{\text{\raisebox{.15em}{res}}}{\smash{-\mkern-5mu-}}}% \displaystyle
    {\overset{\text{\raisebox{.15em}{res}}}{\smash{-\mkern-5mu-}}}% \textstyle
    {\overset{\text{\raisebox{.15em}{res}}}{\smash{-\mkern-5mu-}}}% \scriptstyle
    {\overset{\text{\raisebox{.1em}{\scalebox{.8}{res}}}}{\smash{-\mkern-5mu-}}}% \scriptscriptstyle
  }}

  $A \residue B$ \par
  $C^{A \residue B}$ \par
  $C^{D^{A \residue B}}$

\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

- *Choice 1* uses `\mathpalette` to provide the switching between math styles (see [The mysteries of `\mathpalette`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34393/5764)).
- *Choice 2* employs `\mathchoice` directly to allow for a better scaling of `res` at the `\scriptscriptstyle` level since there is no `\scriptscriptscriptstyle` (as an `\overset` of a `\scriptscriptstyle` argument - in a super-super/sub-sub script technically needs that).

Comment: The OP mentioned that the spacing around the new composite symbol should be like that of a minus sign, i.e., of type mathbin. You may want to mention that if that's what the OP really wants, he/she should use `\mathbin` rather than `\mathrel in the definition of the `\residue` macro.

Comment: @Mico: Absolutely correct. Imma gonna stick with Charles' original request of type `\mathbin`.

Comment: I'm accepting Heiko Oberdiek's answer, but let it be known that Werner's answer would have been entirely adequate for my needs and should be upvoted.

Comment: @Mico: Thanks for pointing that out; you are entirely correct.