# Using \mathpalette with macros that take more arguments

Tags: math-mode, macros

As I understand it, `\mathpalette` takes two arguments; the first must be a macro A that itself takes two arguments. A will be passed as `#1` commands to reproduce the math enviroment at the location where `\mathpalette` was invoked; and A will be passed as `#2` the second argument passed to the invocation of `\mathpalette`. For instance:

```
\newcommand\A[2]{\hbox{$\m@th#1(#2)$}}
...
$$\mathpalette\A2$$
```

Will display a `(2)` in the same math environment as `2` inhabited on the last line. (Here, that is a displaystyle environment.)

So far, so good. My problem is that I want to work with a macro like A that needs additional parameters. My strategy for solving this was to keep A as a 2-argument macro (making `\mathpalette` happy) but to have A invoke a further macro, but only partially supplying the arguments it wants. The rest of the arguments should be read from the position in the stream following the invocation of `\mathpalette`. For example:

```
\newcommand\A[2]{\B#1#2}
\newcommand\B[3]{\hbox{$\m@th#1(#2,#3)$}}
...
$$\mathpalette\A23$$
```

`\mathpalette` will invoke `A` with the current math environment settings in `#1` and with `2` in `#2`. `A` should then pass those arguments on to `B`, and `B` should read `3` as its third argument, yielding the output `(2,3)`.

But this doesn't compile. It gives the error:

> `! Argument of \B has an extra }.`

I can get it to compile but sticking `\expandafter` or `\relax` at the end of the definition of `\A`, but I don't fully understand what I'm doing, and none of my monkeying around is getting this to deliver the desired output of `(2,3)`.

Comment: Probably a duplicate? See [the-mysteries-of-mathpalette](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34393/the-mysteries-of-mathpalette).

Comment: I reviewed that question before posting. It's a tutorial on the basic use of `\mathpalette`, but doesn't address what I'm trying to do: find a workaround to using it with macros that take more than 2 arguments.

Comment: I guess the easiest way to define your macro is to use `\mathchoice` directly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that, `\mathchoice` (which is used to define `\mathpalette`) takes four subformula arguments that will be typeset immediately.

In your example,

```
\newcommand\A[2]{\B#1#2}
\newcommand\B[3]{\hbox{$\m@th#1(#2,#3)$}}
$$\mathpalette\A23$$
```

We know that
`\mathpalette\A23` expands to
`\mathchoice{\A\displaystyle{2}}{\A\textstyle{2}}{\A\scriptstyle{2}}{\A\scriptscriptstyle{2}}3`
but `\A\displaystyle{2}` cannot be typeset because you cannot expand it.

To fix the problem, you should use `\mathchoice` directly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\A[2]{%
  \mathchoice
    {\B\displaystyle{#1}{#2}}
    {\B\textstyle{#1}{#2}}
    {\B\scriptstyle{#1}{#2}}
    {\B\scriptscriptstyle{#1}{#2}}}
\newcommand\B[3]{\hbox{$\m@th#1(#2,#3)$}}

\begin{document}

$ \A23 $

\end{document}
```

Or, you can define your own variant of `\mathpalette`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\mathpalettetwo[3]{%
  \mathchoice
    {#1\displaystyle{#2}{#3}}
    {#1\textstyle{#2}{#3}}
    {#1\scriptstyle{#2}{#3}}
    {#1\scriptscriptstyle{#2}{#3}}}
\newcommand\B[3]{\hbox{$\m@th#1(#2,#3)$}}

\begin{document}

$ \mathpalettetwo\B23 $

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

Use another level:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\jim}[2]{\mathpalette\jiminner{{#1}{#2}}}
\newcommand{\jiminner}[2]{\mbox{$\m@th#1\jimsolve#2$}}
\newcommand{\jimsolve}[2]{(#1,#2)}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\jim{1}{2}\scriptstyle\jim{3}{4}\scriptscriptstyle\jim{5}{6}$

\end{document}
```

The two arguments to `\jim` are packed into a single argument to `\mathpalette`; then `\jiminner` passes control to `\jimsolve`.

[image]