# how to raise superscript inside overline?

Tags: formatting, superscripts

I want to N squared inside overline.
The superscript in `$\overline{N^2}$` is too low. How to raise superscript higher?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Answer (score 7):

This is done on purpose, in order to avoid excessive height when not really needed. Inside `\overline`, the current math style changes into the “cramped” variant. You can revert to the uncramped one by explicitly selecting it or using a command that does it for you.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\roverline}[1]{\mathpalette\doroverline{#1}}
\newcommand{\doroverline}[2]{\overline{#1#2}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
display:      & $\displaystyle\overline{N^2}N^2$      & $\displaystyle\roverline{N^2}N^2$\\
text:         & $\textstyle\overline{N^2}N^2$         & $\textstyle\roverline{N^2}N^2$ \\
script:       & $\scriptstyle\overline{N^2}N^2$       & $\scriptstyle\roverline{N^2}N^2$ \\
scriptscript: & $\scriptscriptstyle\overline{N^2}N^2$ & $\scriptscriptstyle\roverline{N^2}N^2$\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The center column has `\overline`, the right column has `\roverline`.

[image]

Comment: Can you explain why you define `\doroverline` and why it gets two arguments?

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek It's described in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34412/4427

Answer (score 2):

## Is this what you are looking for?

[image]

The example you gave does what it says, it puts a line over `N^2`. If you tell it to square `\overline{N}`, you get the result I think you want.

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}
$\overline{N}^2$
\end{document}
```

---

If you actually want the `2` to appear above the line, you'd want to use a custom command:

[image]

*This goes beyond my skill level* so this is just a mockup, I used TikZ for it only because I don't know the proper way to do this using LaTeX/TeX, *it's not the best tool for this.*

Purely for illustrative purposes, no warranty expressed or implied, probably guaranteed to mess up spacing and alignment:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\supersuperscript}{
    \hspace{-6.6pt}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) (0,11.8pt) node {\scriptsize 2};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }

\begin{document}
$\overline{N\ }\supersuperscript$
\end{document}
```

(It would be cool if someone came along and actually showed how the custom superscript should be done...)

Comment: I want "2" under the overline but higher than the normal position from `$\overline{N^2}$`. thanks