# Oriented harpoon equality

Tags: arrows, relation-symbols

I would like to use a symbol that looks like an equality symbol, but with one arrow on one of the sides of the lines that indicates an orientation.

(for instance when manipulating possibly undefined expression and indicate that definiteness of one side implies that of the other)

The closest thing I found are the `$\rightbarharpoon$` and `$\leftbarharpoon$` from the `mathabx` package. But the symbol does not really evoke an equality to me: too long, the two lines too close to each other.

Any suggestions?

Comment: would something like unicode U+296C or U+296A suit?  or do they also appear too long?  (those would be in the xits or stix fonts.) if they are too long, then i think what you want hasn't been implemented; i've never seen them in the proportions you describe.

Comment: Could do, but you need xetex or something like this load these fonts, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution which can be used with `(pdf)latex`. Igive a ‘long’ version and a short version of harpoon equality (not perfect, as it uses `\resizebox` to adjust the length of the symbol):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\rightharpoonupeq}{\mathrel{%
\raise.22ex\hbox{$\rightharpoonup $}%
\setbox0=\hbox{$\relbar\mkern-9.1mu\relbar$}%
\kern -.98\wd0 \lower.22ex\box0}}%
%
\newcommand{\leftharpoonupeq}{\mathrel{%
\raise.22ex\hbox{$\leftharpoonup $}%
\setbox0=\hbox{$\relbar\mkern-9.1mu\relbar$}%
\kern -.98\wd0 \lower.22ex\box0}}%

\newcommand{\rightharpoondowneq}{\mathrel{%
\lower.22ex\hbox{$\rightharpoondown$}%
\setbox0=\hbox{$\relbar\mkern-9.1mu\relbar$}%
\kern -.98\wd0 \raise.22ex\box0}}%

\newcommand{\leftharpoondowneq}{\mathrel{%
\lower.22ex\hbox{$\leftharpoondown$}%
\setbox0=\hbox{$\relbar\mkern-9.1mu\relbar$}%
\kern -.98\wd0 \raise.22ex\box0}}%


\newcommand{\shortrightharpoonupeq}{\mathrel{%
\resizebox{\widthof{$=$}}{\height}{%
\raise.22ex\hbox{$\rightharpoonup $}%
\setbox0=\hbox{$\relbar\mkern-9.1mu\relbar$}%
\kern -.98\wd0 \lower.22ex\box0}}}%
%%
\newcommand{\shortleftharpoonupeq}{\mathrel{%
\resizebox{\widthof{$=$}}{\height}{%
\raise.22ex\hbox{$\leftharpoonup $}%
\setbox0=\hbox{$\relbar\mkern-9.1mu\relbar$}%
\kern -.98\wd0 \lower.22ex\box0}}}%

\newcommand{\shortrightharpoondowneq}{\mathrel{%
\resizebox{\widthof{$=$}}{\height}{%
\lower.22ex\hbox{$\rightharpoondown$}%
\setbox0=\hbox{$\relbar\mkern-9.1mu\relbar$}%
\kern -.98\wd0 \raise.22ex\box0}}}%

\newcommand{\shortleftharpoondowneq}{\mathrel{%
\resizebox{\widthof{$=$}}{\height}{%
\lower.22ex\hbox{$\leftharpoondown$}%
\setbox0=\hbox{$\relbar\mkern-9.1mu\relbar$}%
\kern -.98\wd0 \raise.22ex\box0}}}%



\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}%
  \texttt{`Long' version} & :\qquad & A & = B \\
                                & & A & \rightleftharpoons B \\
                                & & A & \rightharpoonupeq B\leftharpoonupeq C \\
                                & & A & \rightharpoondowneq B \leftharpoondowneq C \\[4ex]
  \texttt{`Short' version} & :\qquad & A & = B \\
                                & & A & \shortrightharpoonupeq B\shortleftharpoonupeq C \\
                                & & A & \shortrightharpoondowneq B \shortleftharpoondowneq C
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\textttt` was faulty, and I forgot to change the quotes also for `short`… It's corrected now.

Comment: Works well, thanks. One thing though: the $\relbar\mkern-9.1mu\relbar$ doesn't display very well on my pdf reader, superposing to relbars seems to create an artifact.

Comment: Could you describe precisely what you see? I checked it was OK with SumatraPDF and Adobe Reader, at a magnification of 6400 %.  Did you try to zoom, to see whaat happens?

Comment: When I zoom in, it disappears. So this is probably the pdf reader (evince on ubuntu) trying to be smarter than everyone. Basically on the area where the two relbars overlap, there is a slight dark blur that makes the lower bar look a bit thicker. Nevermind, that was more to let you know, I think I'll be using your solution as is.

Comment: Actually if you look close carefully enough, it is discernible on the images you posted to illustrate your commands.

Comment: It's not the first time I see Evince mentioned for display problems. Did you try to see what happens with Ghostscript?

Comment: I've tried various readers, all exhibit a similar behavior. I guess this has to do with anti-aliasing, and the only way I see to avoid that would be to use \rule instead of \relbar, but this is a mess to get right (interaction with \kern... but I basically know nothing about plain TeX)

Comment: I'll try when I have a moment — although I'm no expert either.

Answer (score 3):

With help of Lua- or XeLaTeX you may want to take one of the following unicodes and fonts. If you think the symbols are too long, you may want to trim them like shown in the end. The last approach can be done with the symbols of `mathabx` as well and therefore may be compiled with pdfLaTeX.

[image]

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{trimclip}

\newcommand*{\rightequal}{\mathrel{\clipbox{1.95999pt 0pt .45pt 0pt}{$\rightharpoonupdash$}}}
\newcommand*{\leftequal}{\mathrel{\clipbox{.45pt 0pt 1.95999pt 0pt}{$\leftharpoonupdash$}}}

\begin{document}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}
$A= A \equalrightarrow B = B \equalleftarrow A = A$ % U+2971 and U+2972

$A= A \rightharpoonupdash B = B \leftharpoonupdash A = A$ % U+296C and U+296A

\setmathfont{STIX Math}
$A= A \equalrightarrow B = B \equalleftarrow A = A$

$A= A \rightharpoonupdash B = B \leftharpoonupdash A = A$

\begin{align*}
A&\rightequal B\\
A &= B\\
A&\leftequal B
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a good option.
Indeed I should have mentioned that something working with pdflatex would be preferable.

Could you explain what is happening in the definition \mathrel{\mathpalette\laux\relax}}?

(what are the relax, mathpalette, mathrel for?

Comment: @Marc Sorry, the [mathpalette](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34393) was used falsely. I removed that. The `\mathrel` is needed to make the clipped symbol a relation symbol again (which it has been before.)