# How can I vertically align boxes in math-mode?

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment, boxes

I want to make a box for my daughter in order to fill in the blank. But it is not nice. How can I repair the boxes?
[image]

Comment: The sourcecode for this MWE would help us. What could help, and I will post an answer using this, if you give us your code, is the `\vcenter` option. There are other ways, but I think this suffices.

Comment: I tried `\[\vcenter{\hbox{\rule{0.35cm}{0.35cm}}} + 2016 = 2017 \]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is *a* suggestion:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\pbox}[1]{\boxed{\phantom{#1}}}

\begin{document}

$ \pbox{2015} + 2016 = 4031 $

\medskip

$ \pbox{1} + \pbox{2} + \pbox{3} = 6 $

\medskip

$ \pbox{f(x)} = ax^2 + bx + c $

\medskip

$ \dfrac{6}{10} = \dfrac{\pbox{3}}{5} $

\end{document}
```

The contents is set as a `\phantom` inside a `\boxed` (from [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)).

Comment: Nice work, even though the OP has not provided the MWE.

Comment: @Werner HOw can I simplify this line`$  12\,\, \pbox{>} \,\,5 + 6.$`?

Comment: @toandhsp: You could probably use `$ 12 \mathbin{\pbox{>}} 5 + 6 $`.

Comment: @Werner Can I get a square box? If I use `$ 12 \mathbin{\pbox{>}} 5 + 6 $` not nice.

Comment: @toandhsp: Try with `$ 12 \mathbin{\pbox{\vphantom{>}\rule{1ex}{0pt}}} 5 + 6 $`.

Comment: And how about $ 12 \mathbin{\pbox{\vphantom{=}\rule{1ex}{0pt}}} 5 + 6 $?

Comment: `=` does not have the same height as `<` or `>`, so stick to the latter for a square relation. Alternatively, just use `$ 12 \mathbin{\boxed{\phantom{\rule{1ex}{1.3ex}}}} 5 + 6 $`.

Comment: I really like this approach. The phantom inside the box doesn't seem to respond to sizing cues; for example, the box still appears at full size when it's in an exponent. Do you know of any way to make the phantom resize like usual?

Comment: @Vectornaut: Try [this version](https://pastebin.com/raw/MACM8Pfd). It uses [`\mathpalette`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34393/5764) to bring over the math style, since `\boxed` doesn't do that by itself; [example output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hp3Ym.png).

Comment: @Werner, this looks great! I'd never heard of `\mathpalette` before.