# Make \scalebox work in subscript mode accordingly

Tags: math-mode, macros, graphics

I created a simple macro to type a kind of a range notation (`a:b`) with a larger colon do distinguish if from normal text.

This is the macro with a MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\range}[3][]{%
\def\rangedbldot{\scalebox{1.4}{:}}%
\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax%
  \ensuremath{#2\rangedbldot#3}%
\else%
  \ensuremath{#2\rangedbldot#1\rangedbldot#3}%
\fi%
}

\begin{document}
\(1{:}2\)

\(\range{1}{2}\)

\(a_{\range{1}{2}}\)
\end{document}
```

This is the result:

[image]

What I would expect is that since I'm using a `\scalebox`, not a `\resizebox`, the scaled colon would be proportional to the current font size, that in subscripts is a little bit smaller than in normal text. But apparently that's not the case.

What have I got wrong here? And how do I fix the macro to make the colon proportional on both cases?

Comment: `\scalebox` and `\resizebox` are essentially the same thing, just a different syntax for the scale factor what you are scaling in either case is `\mbox{$:$}` which does not get smaller in subscripts

Comment: also it's best not to use `minimal` class for tests as it does not set up the fonts fully so you can often get artifacts there that will not be a problem in real classes. It'd avoid scaling and use something like `\bm{:}` to get a bold : or if you want to scale use `amsmath` then `\text{\scalebox{...}}` the `\text` macro will take care of setting the size in subscripts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\mathpalette`, see [The mysteries of \mathpalette](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34393/)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\range}[3][]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \ensuremath{#2\rangedbldot#3}%
  \else
    \ensuremath{#2\rangedbldot#1\rangedbldot#3}%
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\rangedbldot}{\mathpalette\dorangedbldot\relax}
\newcommand{\dorangedbldot}[2]{%
  \scalebox{1.4}{$#1:$}%
}

\begin{document}
\(1{:}2\)

\(\range{1}{2}\)

\(a_{\range{1}{2}}\)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly. It'll take me a while to understand the mysteries of \mathpalette :P

Answer (score 1):

Here I use `\ThisStyle{...\SavedStyle...}` of the `scalerel` package to carry the appropriate math-size into the `\scalebox`.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{graphicx,scalerel}

\newcommand{\range}[3][]{%
\def\rangedbldot{\ThisStyle{\scalebox{1.4}{$\SavedStyle:$}}}%
\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax%
  \ensuremath{#2\rangedbldot#3}%
\else%
  \ensuremath{#2\rangedbldot#1\rangedbldot#3}%
\fi%
}

\begin{document}
\(1{:}2\)

\(\range{1}{2}\)

\(a_{\range{1}{2}}\)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would use  a font change, but if you want to scale it is easier to use `\text` than use mathpalette directly.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath,bm}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\range}[3][\@gobble]{%
  \ensuremath{#2\rangedbldot#1\rangedbldot#3}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{.2\textwidth}
\def\rangedbldot{\scalebox{1.4}{:}}

\(1{:}2\)

\(\range{1}{2}\)

\(a_{\range{1}{2}}\)
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.2\textwidth}
\def\rangedbldot{{\bm{:}}}

\(1{:}2\)

\(\range{1}{2}\)

\(a_{\range{1}{2}}\)
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.2\textwidth}
\def\rangedbldot{\text{\scalebox{1.4}{:}}}

\(1{:}2\)

\(\range{1}{2}\)

\(a_{\range{1}{2}}\)
\end{minipage}




\end{document}
```

Comment: Indeed using `\text` is far less complicated than using `\mathpalette`. But as a matter of choice I prefer avoiding the dependence on other packages (even though I don't know if I have ever NOT used `amsmath`). But thanks a lot anyways!

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik `amsmath` and `bm` the two packages I used there are part of the required core latex distribution, so using them offers no more dependencies than using `minimal` class or `article` class.