# How to align equation's symbol explanation/meanings?

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, equations

[image]

Firstly, I don't know what is the good way to display/represent symbol's meaning used in the equation?

Secondly, if I display those like the above slide how can I align the equal signs?

My working code is -

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\logo{%
  %\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1.5cm,keepaspectratio]{DUlogo}%
  \includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1.5cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}
  \hspace{\dimexpr\paperwidth-2cm-5pt}%
  %\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm,keepaspectratio]{GNR.png}%
  \includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Delay equation}
  \begin{exampleblock}{}
    \[
      d_{i} = \frac{1}{\mu_{i}- \lambda_{i}} + \frac{1}{c_{i} - \lambda_{i}}
    \]
  \end{exampleblock}
  \centering
  $d = \text{total delay}$\\
  $\mu_{i} = \text{service rate}$\\
  $\lambda_{i} = \text{arival rate}$\\
  $c_{i} = \text{transmission rate}$\\
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Update**
What is for this one when symbols have different length?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\logo{%
  \includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1.5cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}%
  \hspace{\dimexpr\paperwidth-2cm-5pt}%
  \includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Equation}
  \begin{exampleblock}{}
   \[
     \hat{x_{i}} = \sum_{j\in{\mathcal{A}}}^{}h_{ij}^{H}w_{ij}x_{i} + \sum_{k\neq i}^{N}\sum_{j\in{A}}^{}h_{ij}^{H}w_{kj}x_{k} + \delta_{i}
   \]
  \end{exampleblock}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item $\mathcal{A}$\qquad set of active RRHs
    \item $x_{i}$\qquad data symbol for $i$th user
    \item $w_{ij}\in\mathbb{C}^{k}$\quad Complex number set
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why not simply using a bulleted list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Call me old-fashioned, but I don't think there should be centering at all for the explanatory notes (and no `=` either, because the symbol would be mathematically wrong).

The equation should have prominence, the explanatory notes shouldn't.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\logo{%
  \makebox[\dimexpr\textwidth+0.57cm]{%
    \includegraphics[width=1cm]{../duck}%
    \hfill
    \includegraphics[width=1cm]{../duck}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Delay equation}
\begin{exampleblock}{}
\centering
$\displaystyle
  d_{i} = \frac{1}{\mu_{i}- \lambda_{i}} + \frac{1}{c_{i} - \lambda_{i}}
$
\end{exampleblock}

\begin{itemize}
\item $d_{i}$\quad total delay
\item $\lambda_{i}$\quad arrival rate
\item $\mu_{i}$\quad service rate
\item $c_{i}$\quad transmission rate
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

(There should be a better way to know where the theme places the logo, so that the box width can be set without trial and error.)

[image]

Comment: You can also solution for centering the item.

Comment: But, if the symbols have different length your solution doesn't work. see this https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Wz5ZBpNW5x/

Comment: I edited my question. Don't need to see the linked code.

Answer (score 9):

You can achieve alignment if you set the content in boxes that are of the same width; something that is easy to achieve using [`eqparbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox):

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}

\usepackage{eqparbox,amsmath,xparse}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34412/5764
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\eqmathbox}{o O{c} m}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}
    {\def\eqmathbox@##1##2{\eqmakebox[#1][#2]{$##1##2$}}}
    {\def\eqmathbox@##1##2{\eqmakebox{$##1##2$}}}
  \mathpalette\eqmathbox@{#3}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Delay equation}
  \begin{exampleblock}{}
    \[
      \eqmathbox[LHS][r]{d_i} = 
        \eqmathbox[RHS][l]{\frac{1}{\mu_i - \lambda_i} + \frac{1}{c_i - \lambda_i}}
    \]
  \end{exampleblock}
  \centering
  $\eqmathbox[LHS][r]{d} = \eqmakebox[RHS][l]{total delay}$ \\
  $\eqmathbox[LHS][r]{\mu_i} = \eqmakebox[RHS][l]{service rate}$ \\
  $\eqmathbox[LHS][r]{\lambda_i} = \eqmakebox[RHS][l]{arrival rate}$ \\
  $\eqmathbox[LHS][r]{c_i} = \eqmakebox[RHS][l]{transmission rate}$
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

You'll have to compile twice at the first go (or with any change of the `LHS` or `RHS` components.

---

If you're not concerned about alignment across the `exampleblock`, you can just set the item descriptions inside an `align*`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Delay equation}
  \begin{exampleblock}{}
    \[
      d_i = \frac{1}{\mu_i - \lambda_i} + \frac{1}{c_i - \lambda_i}
    \]
  \end{exampleblock}

  \vspace{-\baselineskip}

  \begin{align*}
            d &= \text{total delay} \\
        \mu_i &= \text{service rate} \\
    \lambda_i &= \text{arrival rate} \\
          c_i &= \text{transmission rate}
  \end{align*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This approach is far more convenient with more space for visual appeal. One doesn't gain much from the alignment across the `exampleblock`.

Comment: Thank you. I tried the 2nd approach, but without the `*`, so I didn't get the expected output.

Answer (score 5):

I also suggest this variant, with `alignat*`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\logo{%
  %\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1.5cm,keepaspectratio]{DUlogo}%
  \includegraphics[width=1.1cm,height=1.8cm,keepaspectratio]{bugs-bunny}
  \hspace{\dimexpr\paperwidth-2cm-5pt}%
  %\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm,keepaspectratio]{GNR.png}%
  \includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm,keepaspectratio]{hare-blazon}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Delay equation}
  \begin{exampleblock}{}
    \[
      d_{i} = \frac{1}{\mu_{i}- \lambda_{i}} + \frac{1}{c_{i} - \lambda_{i}}
    \]
  \end{exampleblock}
\useshortskip
\begin{alignat*}{2}
 d_{i} & = \text{total delay} & \qquad \lambda_{i} & = \text{arrival rate} \\
 \mu_{i} & = \text{service rate} & c_{i} & = \text{transmission rate}
\end{alignat*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]