# Hyphenation and words breaking not working

Tags: hyphenation

I have problem with words breaking. It's not working. I tried use `\hyphenation{}` but it's now working. There is no any errors. I tried use also `\-` in word that I want to break but it's not working too. Any ideas how to solve this?

[image: breaking words problem]

My preambule before `\begin{document}` below:

```
\documentclass[polish]{article}

%\newcommand{\DoNotLoadEpstopdf}{}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xparse,eqparbox,amsmath}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{subfig}


%-------Definition of \signature--
 \def\signature#1#2#3{{\hskip#1in{\hbox to #2in%
{\leaders\hbox to .00625in{\hfil.\hfil}\hfill}}%
 \par\hskip#1in#3\vskip1cm}}
%------------------------------
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34412/5764
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\eqmathbox}{o O{c} m}{%
    \IfValueTF{#1}
    {\def\eqmathbox@##1##2{\eqmakebox[#1][#2]{$##1##2$}}}
    {\def\eqmathbox@##1##2{\eqmakebox{$##1##2$}}}
    \mathpalette\eqmathbox@{#3}
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\ts}{\quad}

%-------Big chapter letters--
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\huge\headingfont}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
%------------------------------

\frenchspacing

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because you are suppressing the hyphenation with the `hyphenat` package.

From the `hyphenat` manual:

> The `none` option disables all hyphenation.  If you use this option you should also consider using `\sloppy` (to reduce TeX’s moans about bad line breaks) or `\raggedright` (to reduce moans about overfull boxes).

So remove the `hyphenat` package, or the `[none]` option.