# align block not properly aligning

Tags: align, amsmath

I'm using amsmath and want to display a state-space representation where all equal-signs are alligned, and the elements in-between are centered. Just like `align` should do, to my understanding. But I get this, where all blocks are aligned right. Not to mention weird blank spaces inserted after each `=`:
[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\renewcommand{\vec}{\textbf}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
    \dot{\vec{x}} &=& \begin{bmatrix}
    \dot{n}\\\dot{x}\\\dot{x_c}\\\dot{V_v}\\\dot{V_m}\\\dot{H}
    \end{bmatrix} &=& \begin{bmatrix}
    f_2(f_1(I),n)\\
    f_4(x, x_c, f_3(f_1(I),n,x,x_c))\\
    f_5(x, x_c, f_3(f_1(I),n,x,x_c))\\
    f_8(f_7(f_6(x, x_c),H), V_v, f_9(V_m))\\
    f_{10}(V_m, f_{11}(V_v))\\
    f_{12}(H, f_9(V_m))
    \end{bmatrix} &=& \vec{f}(\vec{x}, \vec{u}; \theta)
    \label{eq:state}\text{, and}\\
    \vec{z} &=& \begin{bmatrix}
    S_w
    \end{bmatrix} &=& \begin{bmatrix}
    h_1(f_9(V_m))
    \end{bmatrix} &=& \vec{h}(\vec{x}; \theta)
    \label{eq:output}\text{.}
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic: Use `\mathbf`, not `\textbf`, for math-mode material.

Comment: just one comment.  placing `&` signs after `=` signs is `eqnarray` notation, not any of the `amsmath` alignment structures.  that's the reason for the extra space.

Answer (score 3):

That is the standard behaviour for `align`, since it inserts gaps (horizontally) depending on the use of `&`. There is an assumption that multiple equations are to be spread out. And your current use of `&=&` around the relations resembles what was required when using `eqnarray`. This is not the case with [`amsmath`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s `align`-and-friends.

To force centre alignment, you can store the content in a box and use measurements to push smaller boxes into the right position. [`eqparbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox) provides this out of the box with `\eqmakebox[<tag>][<align>]{<stuff>}`, `<align>`ing (`l`eft, `c`entre/default, `r`ight) all `<stuff>` with the same `<tag>` as required.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\usepackage{eqparbox,xparse}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34412/5764
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\eqmathbox}{o O{c} m}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}
    {\def\eqmathbox@##1##2{\eqmakebox[#1][#2]{$##1##2$}}}
    {\def\eqmathbox@##1##2{\eqmakebox{$##1##2$}}}
  \mathpalette\eqmathbox@{#3}
}
\renewcommand{\vec}{\bm}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  \dot{\vec{x}} &= \eqmathbox[left]{\begin{bmatrix}
    \dot{n} \\ \dot{x} \\ \dot{x_c} \\ \dot{V_v} \\ \dot{V_m} \\ \dot{H}
  \end{bmatrix}} = \eqmathbox[middle]{\begin{bmatrix}
    f_2( f_1( I ), n) \\
    f_4( x, x_c, f_3( f_1( I ), n, x, x_c ) ) \\
    f_5( x, x_c, f_3( f_1( I ), n, x, x_c ) ) \\
    f_8( f_7( f_6( x, x_c ), H ), V_v, f_9( V_m ) ) \\
    f_{10}( V_m, f_{11}( V_v ) ) \\
    f_{12}( H, f_9( V_m ) )
  \end{bmatrix}} = \eqmathbox[right]{\vec{f}( \vec{x}, \vec{u}; \theta ),}
  \label{eq:state} \text{ and} \\
  \vec{z} &= \eqmathbox[left]{\begin{bmatrix}
    S_w
  \end{bmatrix}} = \eqmathbox[middle]{\begin{bmatrix}
    h_1( f_9( V_m ) )
  \end{bmatrix}} = \eqmathbox[right]{\vec{h}( \vec{x}; \theta ).}
  \label{eq:output}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

This requires at least two compilations with every change in content within an `\eqmathbox`.

Comment: This looks like what I want. But it seems quite a hassle, especially the two compilations... No easier way?

Comment: @JHBonarius: Two compilations are only required when there is a change in `<stuff>` fot the same `<tag>`. Once `<stuff>` is settled/finalized, you only have to compile once. There are alternatives, like placing the largest content in a box that you can use for measurement in the placing of the smaller components. It would require less compilation, but clutter your code. [`eqparbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox) automates this approach with the addition of compilation (again, only when `<stuff>` changes for the same `<tag>`). If you're not interested in equation numbering, an `array` would work.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that providing multipled alignment points across the two equations really helps elucidate what the two equations "mean". Why not use a `gather` environment, to create two individually-centered equations.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\shortintertext' macro
\renewcommand{\vec}{\mathbf} % use '\mathbf', not '\textbf' 
\begin{document}
    \begin{gather}
    \dot{\vec{x}} =
    \begin{bmatrix}
      \dot{n}\\ \dot{x}\\ \dot{x_c}\\ \dot{V_v}\\ \dot{V_m}\\ \dot{H}
    \end{bmatrix} =
    \begin{bmatrix}
      f_2(f_1(I),n)\\
      f_4(x, x_c, f_3(f_1(I),n,x,x_c))\\
      f_5(x, x_c, f_3(f_1(I),n,x,x_c))\\
      f_8(f_7(f_6(x, x_c),H), V_v, f_9(V_m))\\
      f_{10}(V_m, f_{11}(V_v))\\
      f_{12}(H, f_9(V_m))
    \end{bmatrix} =
    \vec{f}(\vec{x}, \vec{u}; \theta)
    \label{eq:state}\\
    \shortintertext{and}
    \vec{z} =
    \begin{bmatrix}
      S_w
    \end{bmatrix} =
    \begin{bmatrix}
      h_1(f_9(V_m))
    \end{bmatrix} =
    \vec{h}(\vec{x}; \theta).
    \label{eq:output}
    \end{gather}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I had it like this (somewhat). But I need to shrink my 8 page article to a 4-page limit, so want to save all the space I have. The state-space representation equations are usually written below each other.

Comment: @JHBonarius - I suppose a tiny bit of vertical space could be saved by moving the word "and" to the end of the preceding line, rather than placing it on a  line by itself.