# Trouble using flalign for left aligned math equations

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, equations, align

I tried to left align some equations, but always get the wrong result

[image]

Code below

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\section*{Test}

\begin{flalign}
&&U_{i}&&= U_{\mathrm{h}i} + U_{\mathrm{r}i} \ ,  &&I_{i} &&= \frac{1}{Z_{\mathrm{L}i}}(U_{\mathrm{h}i} - U_{\mathrm{r}i})\\
&&U_{\mathrm{h}i}&&= \frac{U_i + Z_{\mathrm{L}i}I_{i}}{2} \ , &&U_{\mathrm{r}i} &&= \frac{U_i - Z_{\mathrm{L}i}I_{i}}{2}
\end{flalign}

\end{document}
```

What I would like to have:

[image]

Thank you all

Comment: Why `flalign`? Any reason?

Comment: @Werner I seached some method before. `flalign` `align` `alignat`  I have all tried

Comment: why do you want to left align the left hand side of the =??? so making the space around the `=` asymmetrical? that looks very odd and quite unlike a normal left aligned equation setting in amsmath.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle May be not good for Quality. But it is true a trouble for me. In my opinion, `&` split the equation and each part should be left aligned

Comment: it makes it harder to read (and distracts the reader with an unusual layout) but it's your document and a free world, if that's what you what I see egreg  and Werner have provided solutions:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `flalign` with `&` around the alignment relations and between each of the equations as well as a final `&` on each row:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,eqparbox,xparse}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34412/5764
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\eqmathbox}{o O{c} m}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}
    {\def\eqmathbox@##1##2{\eqmakebox[#1][#2]{$##1##2$}}}
    {\def\eqmathbox@##1##2{\eqmakebox{$##1##2$}}}
  \mathpalette\eqmathbox@{#3}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign}
              \eqmathbox[L1][l]{U_i} &= U_{\mathrm{h}i} + U_{\mathrm{r}i},  & 
              \eqmathbox[L2][l]{I_i} &= \frac{1}{Z_{\mathrm{L}i}}(U_{\mathrm{h}i} - U_{\mathrm{r}i}) & \\
  \eqmathbox[L1][l]{U_{\mathrm{h}i}} &= \frac{U_i + Z_{\mathrm{L}i}I_{i}}{2}, & 
  \eqmathbox[L2][l]{U_{\mathrm{r}i}} &= \frac{U_i - Z_{\mathrm{L}i}I_{i}}{2} &
\end{flalign}

\end{document}
```

The use of [`eqparbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox) supports alignment choices for elements within `\eqmathbox[<tag>][<align>]{<stuff>}`. All elements with the same `<tag>` will have the same maximum width where you can specify the individual `<align>`ment as needed (`l`eft in the above example).

An alternative without `eqparbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign}
  \mathrlap{U_i}\phantom{U_{\mathrm{h}i}} &= U_{\mathrm{h}i} + U_{\mathrm{r}i},  & 
  \mathrlap{I_i}\phantom{U_{\mathrm{r}i}} &= \frac{1}{Z_{\mathrm{L}i}}(U_{\mathrm{h}i} - U_{\mathrm{r}i}) & \\
                          U_{\mathrm{h}i} &= \frac{U_i + Z_{\mathrm{L}i}I_{i}}{2}, & 
                          U_{\mathrm{r}i} &= \frac{U_i - Z_{\mathrm{L}i}I_{i}}{2} &
\end{flalign}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I also need the equation begin from left, not centered

Comment: @sun0727: Like which of the following two setups: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/um3tn.png) Equations (1) & (2) or equations (3) & (4)?

Comment: like the second one, but `Ui` shoule also at the line begin, so the space betwenn `Ui` and `=` can be more.

Comment: thanks, I have uploaded a figure for what I want to have.

Comment: @sun0727: See the update.

Comment: very nice, but can you explain, why it is not so easy to approach, in my opinion, `&` split the equation, and each part just should be left aligned

Comment: @sun0727: The default behaviour is the have the LHS of the equation right-aligned and the RHS of the equation left-aligned. If you want to change that, you have to play around a bit.

Answer (score 2):

I can see no reason for the equation to start at the left margin. Anyway, here's the code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\section*{Test}

\begin{flalign}
U_{i}           &= U_{\mathrm{h}i} + U_{\mathrm{r}i} ,  
  & I_{i} &= \frac{1}{Z_{\mathrm{L}i}}(U_{\mathrm{h}i} - U_{\mathrm{r}i}) && \\
U_{\mathrm{h}i} &= \frac{U_i + Z_{\mathrm{L}i}I_{i}}{2} ,
  & U_{\mathrm{r}i} &= \frac{U_i - Z_{\mathrm{L}i}I_{i}}{2} &&
\end{flalign}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With the standard `align`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\section*{Test}

\begin{align}
U_{i}           &= U_{\mathrm{h}i} + U_{\mathrm{r}i} ,  
  & I_{i} &= \frac{1}{Z_{\mathrm{L}i}}(U_{\mathrm{h}i} - U_{\mathrm{r}i}) \\
U_{\mathrm{h}i} &= \frac{U_i + Z_{\mathrm{L}i}I_{i}}{2} ,
  & U_{\mathrm{r}i} &= \frac{U_i - Z_{\mathrm{L}i}I_{i}}{2}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

You get

[image]

which agrees with *all* other equations, since you're using `fleqn`.

If your aim is to align to the left U and I, then use a phantom. I took the occasion for simplifying your input by defining `\rh`, `\rr` and `\rL`. The macro `\prh` stands for “a phantom `\rh`”.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newcommand{\rh}{\mathrm{h}}
\newcommand{\prh}{\hphantom{\rh}}
\newcommand{\rL}{\mathrm{L}}
\newcommand{\rr}{\mathrm{r}}

\begin{document}

\section*{Test}

\begin{align}
U_{i\prh}           &= U_{\rh i} + U_{\rr i} ,  
  & I_{i\prh} &= \frac{1}{Z_{\rL i}}(U_{\rh i} - U_{\rr i}) \\
U_{\rh i} &= \frac{U_i + Z_{\rL i}I_{i}}{2} ,
  & U_{\rh i} &= \frac{U_i - Z_{\rL i}I_{i}}{2}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Adapt to the `flalign` shown above, if you prefer.

[image]

Comment: thanks, I have uploaded a figure for what I want to have.

Comment: @sun0727 I don't think it improves the quality. But I added it.

Answer (score 2):

The `flalign`  environment requires only 5 = 2×3 – 1 ampersands since it has 3 groups of alignment.

Another possibility, to left align only some equations in your document; consists in nesting your equations in a `fleqn` environment, defined by `nccmath`. Furthermore, it can take an optional argument for the distance from the left margin at which the equation body begins (by default, it is 0pt). Demo:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.3pt}

\begin{document}
\section*{Test}

\begin{flalign}
U_{i}&= U_{\mathrm{h}i} + U_{\mathrm{r}i} &I_{i} &= \frac{1}{Z_{\mathrm{L}i}}(U_{\mathrm{h}i} - U_{\mathrm{r}i}) & \\
U_{\mathrm{h}i}&= \frac{U_i + Z_{\mathrm{L}i}I_{i}}{2}&U_{\mathrm{r}i}&= \frac{U_i - Z_{\mathrm{L}i}I_{i}}{2}
\end{flalign}
\vspace{\baselineskip}
\begin{fleqn}[1em]
\begin{align}
U_{i}&= U_{\mathrm{h}i} + U_{\mathrm{r}i} &I_{i} &= \frac{1}{Z_{\mathrm{L}i}}(U_{\mathrm{h}i} - U_{\mathrm{r}i}) & \\
U_{\mathrm{h}i}&= \frac{U_i + Z_{\mathrm{L}i}I_{i}}{2}&U_{\mathrm{r}i}&= \frac{U_i - Z_{\mathrm{L}i}I_{i}}{2}
\end{align}
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]