# get width and height of character in the power

Tags: math-mode, superscripts, lengths

I want to create a "minus-sign" in a superscript of a letter in math mode using `\rule{width}{height}` to get control over the look of it. In principle, I get something to my liking, but I fail to make the width and height adjust to when I use it in the power of an expression.

I tried:

```
\newlength{\charheight}
\newlength{\charwidth}
\newcommand{\supmin}[1]{%
\settoheight{\charheight}{#1}
\settowidth{\charwidth}{#1}
#1^{\rule{\charwidth}{\charheight}}
}
```

and

```
\newcommand{\supmin}[1]{%
#1^{\rule{1ex}{1em}}
}
```

both failed to adjust the box in the superscript when used in the power:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
k \binom{N}{k} - \supmin{k} p^{\supmin{k}} > 0
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

To my eye, these boxes have the same size.
[image]

Comment: They have the same size because `\settoheight{...}{k}` and `\settowidth{...}{k}` effectively measure how large a `k` would be in the main text. They do not take into account the fact that you are using them in math mode (or in a superscript). You could measure e.g. the height of a script style `k` with `\settoheight{...}{$\scriptstyle k$}`.

Comment: (_In egreg's answer, `\mathpalette` is used to automatically insert `\displaystyle`, `\textstyle`, `\scriptstyle` or `\scriptscriptstyle` (whichever is appropriate) as `#1` to `\sup@min` (and the original argument as `#2`)._)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a job for [`\mathpalette`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34393/):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\supmin}[1]{{\mathpalette\sup@min{#1}}}
\newcommand{\sup@min}[2]{%
  \begingroup % <- important
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1#2$}%
  #2^{\rule{\wd\z@}{\ht\z@}}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
k \binom{N}{k} - \supmin{k} p^{\supmin{k}} > 0
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, doing a bit of scaling and using offset gave me the desired result: ``\rule[0.3\ht\z@]{0.8\wd\z@}{0.03\ht\z@}``