# Multiple choice questions with proposed answers in random order — addition of automatic correction (cross mark)

Tags: align, boxes, expl3, mark

Considering my two previous questions:

[Squares for answer choice options and perfect alignment to mathematical answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/461730/squares-for-answer-choice-options-and-perfect-alignment-to-mathematical-answers)

### First @egreg's code

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\squarecap}[1]{\fbox{\makebox[\height]{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\squarecap{A}\par
\squarecap{B}\par
\squarecap{C}\par
\squarecap{D}\par
\squarecap{E}\par
\squarecap{M}\par

\end{document}
```

### Second @egreg's code

[Automatically shake questions and answers for a test created with LaTeX after the compilation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/519826/automatically-shake-questions-and-answers-for-a-test-created-with-latex-after-th)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper,margin=1cm]{geometry} % just to make smaller images
\usepackage{multicol,mathtools}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\pagestyle{empty}

\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\question}{mm}
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l__sebastiano_question_body_seq
  \tl_map_inline:nn { #2 } { \seq_put_right:Nn \l__sebastiano_question_body_seq { ##1 } }
  \seq_shuffle:N \l__sebastiano_question_body_seq

  \item #1 \\[2ex]

  \seq_indexed_map_inline:Nn \l__sebastiano_question_body_seq
   {
    \fbox { \int_to_Alph:n { ##1 } } ~ ##2 \\[0.5ex]
   }

  \fbox { \int_to_Alph:n { \seq_count:N \l__sebastiano_question_body_seq + 1 } } ~
  \makebox[9em]{\hrulefill}
 }

\NewDocumentEnvironment{test}{m+b}
 {
  \prg_replicate:nn { #1 } { #2 \clearpage }
 }
 {}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{test}{4}

\begin{enumerate}
\question{La velocità di \SI{1,00e2}{m/s} espressa in \si{km/h} è:}{
  {\SI{36}{km/h}.}
  {\SI{360}{km/h}.}
  {\SI{27,8}{km/h}.}
  {\SI{3,60e8}{km/h}.}
}

\question{In fisica nucleare si usa l'angstrom (simbolo: $\SI{1}{\angstrom}=\SI{1e-10}{m}$) 
e il fermi o femtometro ($\SI{1}{fm}=\SI{1e-15}{m}$). Qual è la relazione tra queste due 
unità di misura?}{
  {$\SI{1}{\angstrom}=\SI{1e5}{fm}$.}
  {$\SI{1}{\angstrom}=\SI{1e-5}{fm}$.}
  {$\SI{1}{\angstrom}=\SI{1e-15}{fm}$.}
  {$\SI{1}{\angstrom}=\SI{1e3}{fm}$.}
}

\end{enumerate}

\end{test}

\end{document}
```

how can I combine the codes to have perfect squares, (do not use `siunitx` package) and to have a mark cross that I need as a corrector that I will can eliminate in the prints of the tests that I will give to my students?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the following should do more or less what you want. I assume there is always exactly one correct answer per question (otherwise, we'll probably have to change the input syntax because of the freeform answer, which is currently not part of the input). The correct answer must be indicated with a preceding `[x]` or `[X]` as follows:

```
\question{La velocità di \SI{1,00e2}{m/s} espressa in \si{km/h} è:}{
     {\SI{36}{km/h}.}
  [X]{\SI{360}{km/h}.}
     {\SI{27,8}{km/h}.}
     {\SI{3,60e8}{km/h}.}
}
```

Spaces are ignored before and after the `[x]` or `[X]`, therefore this kind of input is also legal:

```
\question{La velocità di \SI{1,00e2}{m/s} espressa in \si{km/h} è:}{
      {\SI{36}{km/h}.}
  [X] {\SI{360}{km/h}.}
      {\SI{27,8}{km/h}.}
      {\SI{3,60e8}{km/h}.}
}
```

If none of the proposed answers has such a mark for a given question, the freeform answer (with no corresponding line in the above input) is assumed to be the correct one.

Whether a check mark next to the correct answer for each question is printed depends on the use of `\ShowCorrectAnswers` and `\HideCorrectAnswers` (see the screenshots below). These commands respect TeX grouping rules (i.e., they act locally). Alternatively, you can:

- load the `sebmcq` package with `show-correct-answers=true` or `show-correct-answers=false`, or
- use `\sebmcqSetup{show-correct-answers=true}` or `\sebmcqSetup{show-correct-answers=false}`.

The `\sebmcqSetup` command respects grouping and accepts the following options. They can also be passed in the `\usepackage{sebmcq}` call and in the optional argument of the `questionnaire` environment.

- `questionnaire-env` (initially: `enumerate`). This is the environment used by `questionnaire` in order to print all questions. It has to accept an `\item` command that works the same way as in `enumerate`.
- `shuffle-questions` (initially: `false`); the value can be `true` or `false`. If you use the option with no value, it means `true`.
- `shuffle-answers` (initially: `false`). The value is interpreted in the same way as for `shuffle-questions`.
- `show-correct-answers` (initially: `false`). Ditto regarding the value.
- `after-answer-num-skip=〈skip〉` determines the horizontal space between each answer number/letter and the corresponding answer.
- `answer-number-format=〈code〉` allows one to completely change the formatting of answer numbers (alph, Alph, roman, Roman, arabic; custom Ti*k*Z code to draw a circle or rectangle around it, etc). Any occurrence of `#1` in the 〈code〉 argument will be replaced by the proposed answer number (an integer).

The examples below show how to use these options.

## The `sebmcq.sty` style file

```latex
% sebmcq.sty --- Multiple choice questions. Can print questions and proposed
%                answers in a random order. Optionally show the correct
%                answers.
%
% See <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/529060/73317> for more information.
%
% Copyright (C) 2020  Florent Rougon, Enrico Gregorio
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3
% of this license or (at your option) any later version.
% The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3 can be found in the LICENSE file present in this
% distribution.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status `maintained'.
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work is Florent Rougon.
%
% This work consists of only one file: sebmcq.sty.
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]
\RequirePackage{expl3}
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\RequirePackage{l3keys2e}
\RequirePackage{amssymb}        % for the \checkmark
\ProvidesExplPackage{sebmcq}{2020-03-14}{0.6}
  {Multiple choice questions}

\str_new:N \l_questionnaire_env_str
\seq_new:N \l__sebmcq_questions_seq
\tl_new:N \l__sebmcq_answers_tl
\tl_new:N \l__sebmcq_correctness_code_tl
\tl_new:N \l__sebmcq_answer_tl
\bool_new:N \l_sebmcq_shuffle_questions_bool
\bool_new:N \l_sebmcq_shuffle_answers_bool
\bool_new:N \l_sebmcq_show_correct_answers_bool
\bool_new:N \l__sebmcq_has_correct_answer_bool    % parsing stage
\bool_new:N \l__sebmcq_correct_answer_marked_bool % rendering stage
\skip_new:N \l_sebmcq_after_answer_num_skip        % horizontal skip

\msg_new:nnn { sebmcq } { invalid-answer-opt-arg }
  { Invalid~input~inside~brackets~before~answer:~'#1'. }

\msg_new:nnn { sebmcq } { empty-answer-opt-arg }
  { Empty~input~inside~brackets~before~answer. }

\msg_new:nnn { sebmcq } { question-cmd-used-outside-of-questionnaire-env }
  { \question command~used~outside~of~questionnaire~environment. }

% This is assumed to be illegal
\msg_new:nnn { sebmcq } { several-correct-answers }
  { Several~answers~have~been~marked~as~correct~for~a~question. }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__sebmcq_read_answer_with_optarg:wn [#1]#2
  {
    \tl_if_empty:nTF {#1}
      { \msg_error:nn { sebmcq } { empty-answer-opt-arg } }
      {
        \str_if_in:nnTF { xX } {#1}
          {
            \bool_if:NTF \l__sebmcq_has_correct_answer_bool
              { \msg_error:nn { sebmcq } { several-correct-answers } }
              {
                \bool_set_true:N \l__sebmcq_has_correct_answer_bool
                \tl_put_right:Nn \l__sebmcq_answers_tl
                  { { { \correct } {#2} } }
              }
          }
          { \msg_error:nnn { sebmcq } { invalid-answer-opt-arg } {#1} }
      }
    \__sebmcq_read_answers:w % recurse
  }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__sebmcq_read_answer_without_optarg:n #1
  {
    % Incorrect answer
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__sebmcq_answers_tl { { { } {#1} } }
    \__sebmcq_read_answers:w % recurse
  }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__sebmcq_read_answers:w
  {
    \peek_meaning_ignore_spaces:NTF \q_stop
      { \use_none:n }
      {
        \peek_meaning_ignore_spaces:NTF [
          { \__sebmcq_read_answer_with_optarg:wn }
          { \__sebmcq_read_answer_without_optarg:n }
      }
  }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__sebmcq_maybe_mark_correct_answer:
  {
    % Little trick in the boolean expression: this allows us to automatically
    % mark the freeform answer as correct if none of the explicitly given
    % answers was declared as correct.
    \bool_if:nT
      {
          \bool_if_p:N \l_sebmcq_show_correct_answers_bool &&
        ! \bool_if_p:N \l__sebmcq_correct_answer_marked_bool
      }
      {
        \makebox[0pt][r] { \checkmark \skip_horizontal:n { 0.7em } }
        % No other answer will be marked as correct for this question.
        \bool_set_true:N \l__sebmcq_correct_answer_marked_bool
      }
  }

% Default function for formatting the question number
\cs_new_protected:Npn \sebmcq_format_question_number_default:n #1
  {
    \fbox { \makebox[\height]{ \int_to_Alph:n {#1} } }
  }

% #1: empty means the answer is incorrect
% #2: answer number
% #3: answer text
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__sebmcq_print_proposed_answer:nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \tl_if_empty:nF {#1} { \__sebmcq_maybe_mark_correct_answer: }
    \__sebmcq_format_question_number:n {#2}
    \skip_horizontal:n { \l_sebmcq_after_answer_num_skip } {#3} \\[0.5ex]
  }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__sebmcq_print_proposed_answer:nnn { VnV }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__sebmcq_format_question_number:n { x }

% Based on egreg's code: <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/519972/73317>
% #1: question text; #2: proposed answers
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__sebmcq_read_question:nn #1#2
  {
    \tl_clear:N \l__sebmcq_answers_tl
    \bool_set_false:N \l__sebmcq_has_correct_answer_bool
    \__sebmcq_read_answers:w #2 \q_stop
    \seq_put_right:Nx \l__sebmcq_questions_seq
      {
        { \exp_not:n {#1} }                                    % { question }
        { \exp_not:n \exp_after:wN { \l__sebmcq_answers_tl } } % { answers }
      }
  }

\seq_new:N \l__sebmcq_oq_answers_seq

% #1: question
% #2: answers, each of which being of the form
% { { \correct or empty } { answer text } }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__sebmcq_output_question:nn #1#2
  {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__sebmcq_oq_answers_seq { } {#2}
    \bool_if:NT \l_sebmcq_shuffle_answers_bool
      { \seq_shuffle:N \l__sebmcq_oq_answers_seq }

    \item {#1} \\[2ex]          % question text

    \bool_set_false:N \l__sebmcq_correct_answer_marked_bool
    \seq_indexed_map_inline:Nn \l__sebmcq_oq_answers_seq
      {
        \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { } {##2}
        \seq_pop_left:NN \l_tmpa_seq \l__sebmcq_correctness_code_tl
        \seq_pop_left:NN \l_tmpa_seq \l__sebmcq_answer_tl
        \__sebmcq_print_proposed_answer:VnV
          \l__sebmcq_correctness_code_tl {##1}
          \l__sebmcq_answer_tl
      }

    \__sebmcq_maybe_mark_correct_answer:
    \__sebmcq_format_question_number:x
      { \int_eval:n { \seq_count:N \l__sebmcq_oq_answers_seq + 1 } }
    \skip_horizontal:n { \l_sebmcq_after_answer_num_skip }
    \hbox_to_wd:nn { 9em } { \hrulefill }
  }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__sebmcq_output_question:n #1
  { \__sebmcq_output_question:nn #1 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__sebmcq_output_questionnaire:
  {
    \bool_if:NT \l_sebmcq_shuffle_questions_bool
      { \seq_shuffle:N \l__sebmcq_questions_seq }
    % I didn't use \seq_map_inline:Nn here because it would fail with l3kernel
    % older than 2020-03-14 (this is due to a bug in \seq_shuffle:N
    % <https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/687>, fixed in this commit:
    % <https://github.com/latex3/latex3/commit/42c70c63fd83324c5792dd14538a39dd7e388a55>).
    \seq_map_function:NN \l__sebmcq_questions_seq \__sebmcq_output_question:n
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \question { }
  {
    \msg_error:nn { sebmcq } { question-cmd-used-outside-of-questionnaire-env }
  }

\NewDocumentEnvironment { questionnaire } { O{} }
  {
    \keys_set:nn { sebmcq } {#1}
    \cs_set_eq:NN \question \__sebmcq_read_question:nn
    \tl_clear:N \l__sebmcq_questions_seq
    \use:c { \str_use:N \l_questionnaire_env_str }
  }
  {
    \__sebmcq_output_questionnaire:
    \use:c { end \str_use:N \l_questionnaire_env_str }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \ShowCorrectAnswers { }
 {
   \bool_set_true:N \l_sebmcq_show_correct_answers_bool
 }

\NewDocumentCommand \HideCorrectAnswers { }
 {
   \bool_set_false:N \l_sebmcq_show_correct_answers_bool
 }

% Set the default question number formatter
\cs_new_eq:NN \__sebmcq_format_question_number:n
              \sebmcq_format_question_number_default:n

\keys_define:nn { sebmcq }
  {
    after-answer-num-skip .skip_set:N = \l_sebmcq_after_answer_num_skip ,
    after-answer-num-skip .value_required:n = true,
    after-answer-num-skip .initial:n = { 0.9em },
    %
    answer-number-format  .code:n = {
      \cs_set_protected:Npn \__sebmcq_format_question_number:n ##1 {#1} },
    answer-number-format  .value_required:n = true,
    %
    questionnaire-env     .code:n = {
      \str_set:Nn \l_questionnaire_env_str {#1} },
    questionnaire-env     .value_required:n = true,
    questionnaire-env     .initial:n = { enumerate },
    %
    show-correct-answers  .bool_set:N = \l_sebmcq_show_correct_answers_bool,
    show-correct-answers  .initial:n = { false },
    show-correct-answers  .default:n = { true },
    %
    shuffle-questions     .bool_set:N = \l_sebmcq_shuffle_questions_bool,
    shuffle-questions     .initial:n = { false },
    shuffle-questions     .default:n = { true },
    %
    shuffle-answers       .bool_set:N = \l_sebmcq_shuffle_answers_bool,
    shuffle-answers       .initial:n = { false },
    shuffle-answers       .default:n = { true },
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \sebmcqSetup { m }
  {
    \keys_set:nn { sebmcq } {#1}
  }

% Process LaTeX2e-style package options. This uses l3keys2e, see
% <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/371754/73317> for explanations.
\ProcessKeysPackageOptions { sebmcq }

\endinput
```

## First example

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}                      % or whatever you want
% To make small pages for the screenshots:
\usepackage[paperwidth=15cm, paperheight=11cm,
            hmargin=2cm, vmargin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx}                      % only for the examples
\usepackage{xparse}                       % only for the 'test' environment
\usepackage[shuffle-questions, shuffle-answers]{sebmcq} % your new package :-)

\pagestyle{empty}

\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment { test } { m +b }
  { \prg_replicate:nn { #1 } { #2 \clearpage } }
  { }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\ShowCorrectAnswers

\begin{document}

\begin{test}{4}
\begin{questionnaire}
% Mark the correct answer with either [x] or [X]. If no mark is present, the
% correct answer is assumed to be the freeform one.
\question{La velocità di \SI{1,00e2}{m/s} espressa in \si{km/h} è:}{
     {\SI{36}{km/h}.}
  [X]{\SI{360}{km/h}.}
     {\SI{27,8}{km/h}.}
     {\SI{3,60e8}{km/h}.}
}

\question{In fisica nucleare si usa l'angstrom
  (simbolo: $\SI{1}{\angstrom} = \SI{1e-10}{m}$) e il fermi o femtometro
  ($\SI{1}{fm} = \SI{1e-15}{m}$). Qual è la relazione tra queste due
  unità di misura?}{
  [x]{$\SI{1}{\angstrom}=\SI{1e5}{fm}$.}
     {$\SI{1}{\angstrom}=\SI{1e-5}{fm}$.}
     {$\SI{1}{\angstrom}=\SI{1e-15}{fm}$.}
     {$\SI{1}{\angstrom}=\SI{1e3}{fm}$.}
}
\end{questionnaire}
\end{test}

\end{document}
```

Sample output:

[image: correct answers shown]

Sample output with `\ShowCorrectAnswers` commented out, or with `\HideCorrectAnswers`:

[image: correct answers not shown]

## Second example

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}                      % or whatever you want
% To make small pages for the screenshots:
\usepackage[paperwidth=15cm, paperheight=12cm,
            hmargin=2cm, vmargin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx}                      % for the examples
\usepackage{tikz}                         % for \myCircled
\usepackage{sebmcq}
\sebmcqSetup{
  shuffle-questions, shuffle-answers, show-correct-answers=true,
  answer-number-format={\myCircled{#1}}, after-answer-num-skip=1.5em,
}

\pagestyle{empty}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}

\newcommand*{\myCircled}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(number.base)]
    \node[circle, draw=green!10!gray, fill=blue!30!green!10] (number) {#1};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{questionnaire}
\question{La velocità di \SI{1,00e2}{m/s} espressa in \si{km/h} è:}{
      {\SI{36}{km/h}.}
  [X] {\SI{360}{km/h}.}
      {\SI{27,8}{km/h}.}
      {\SI{3,60e8}{km/h}.}
}

\question{In fisica nucleare si usa l'angstrom (simbolo:
   $\SI{1}{\angstrom} = \SI{1e-10}{m}$) e il fermi o femtometro
   ($\SI{1}{fm} = \SI{1e-15}{m}$). Qual è la relazione tra queste due unità di
   misura?}{
  [X] {$\SI{1}{\angstrom}=\SI{1e5}{fm}$.}
      {$\SI{1}{\angstrom}=\SI{1e-5}{fm}$.}
      {$\SI{1}{\angstrom}=\SI{1e-15}{fm}$.}
      {$\SI{1}{\angstrom}=\SI{1e3}{fm}$.}
}
\end{questionnaire}

\end{document}
```

Sample output (the value `1.5em` passed to option `after-answer-num-skip` is probably too large; this is only to demonstrate its effect):

[image: second example]

## Third example

This is a small variant of the previous example. This time, the `answer-number-format` key isn't set with `\sebmcqSetup`, but in the optional argument of the `questionnaire` environment.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}                      % or whatever you want
% To make small pages for the screenshots:
\usepackage[paperwidth=15cm, paperheight=11cm,
            hmargin=2cm, vmargin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx}                      % for the examples
\usepackage{tikz}                         % for \myCircled
\usepackage{sebmcq}
\sebmcqSetup{shuffle-questions, shuffle-answers, show-correct-answers}

\pagestyle{empty}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}

\begin{document}

% Use a specific answer number format for this questionnaire
\begin{questionnaire}[answer-number-format={%
  \tikz[baseline=(number.base)]
    \node[rectangle, rounded corners=1pt, draw=none, fill=gray!40] (number)
      {#1};%
  }]

\question{La velocità di \SI{1,00e2}{m/s} espressa in \si{km/h} è:}{
      {\SI{36}{km/h}.}
  [X] {\SI{360}{km/h}.}
      {\SI{27,8}{km/h}.}
      {\SI{3,60e8}{km/h}.}
}

\question{In fisica nucleare si usa l'angstrom (simbolo:
   $\SI{1}{\angstrom} = \SI{1e-10}{m}$) e il fermi o femtometro
   ($\SI{1}{fm} = \SI{1e-15}{m}$). Qual è la relazione tra queste due unità di
   misura?}{
  [X] {$\SI{1}{\angstrom}=\SI{1e5}{fm}$.}
      {$\SI{1}{\angstrom}=\SI{1e-5}{fm}$.}
      {$\SI{1}{\angstrom}=\SI{1e-15}{fm}$.}
      {$\SI{1}{\angstrom}=\SI{1e3}{fm}$.}
}
\end{questionnaire}

\end{document}
```

[image: third example]

## Fourth example

This is a small variant of the previous examples with `\alph`-style numbering for the proposed answers (LaTeX2e's `\alph` command can't be used here, because the proposed answer number is not a counter when represented by `#1` in the argument of `answer-number-format`).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}                      % or whatever you want
% To make small pages for the screenshots:
\usepackage[paperwidth=15cm, paperheight=11cm,
            hmargin=2cm, vmargin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx}                      % for the examples
\usepackage{tikz}                         % for \mySquared
\usepackage{expl3}                        % for \int_to_alph:n
\usepackage{sebmcq}
\sebmcqSetup{
  shuffle-questions, shuffle-answers, show-correct-answers,
  answer-number-format={\mySquared{#1}},
}

\pagestyle{empty}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% Borrow \int_to_alph:n from expl3
\cs_new_eq:NN \inttoalph \int_to_alph:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand*{\mySquared}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(number.base)]
    \node[rectangle, rounded corners=1pt, draw=none, fill=gray!40] (number)
      {\inttoalph{#1}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{questionnaire}
\question{In fisica nucleare si usa l'angstrom (simbolo:
   $\SI{1}{\angstrom} = \SI{1e-10}{m}$) e il fermi o femtometro
   ($\SI{1}{fm} = \SI{1e-15}{m}$). Qual è la relazione tra queste due unità di
   misura?}{
  [X] {$\SI{1}{\angstrom}=\SI{1e5}{fm}$.}
      {$\SI{1}{\angstrom}=\SI{1e-5}{fm}$.}
      {$\SI{1}{\angstrom}=\SI{1e-15}{fm}$.}
      {$\SI{1}{\angstrom}=\SI{1e3}{fm}$.}
}
\end{questionnaire}

\end{document}
```

[image: fourth example]

Comment: A billion thanks. Not even a century would have taken me to build your code. Thank you very much.

Comment: My pleasure, @Sebastiano, glad to see you like the outcome.

Comment: Thank you once again so cordially and thank you for everything.

Comment: @Sebastiano I wrapped the code in a .sty (namely, `sebmcq.sty`) for your convenience.

Comment: @egreg I listed you among the copyright holders of the `sebmcq.sty` file provided in this answer (respecting [your statement](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3333/73317), TTBOMK). Should you be unhappy about that, feel free to edit the answer. :-)

Comment: I thank you, egreg and you from the bottom of my heart. During this time I only relax with LaTeX and music. I'm on tilt almost always .

Comment: I had to google “to be on tilt”... it doesn't sound very positive, I hope it will ge better soon! I improved the default layout and added options in key=value format that allow one to easily change some aspects of the layout. I believe the question title should be changed to something like “Multiple choice questions with proposed answers in random order”. Otherwise, I fear that people finding this via a search engine will flee as soon as they read “Mixer of two previous codes”. :-)

Comment: I always thank you with all my heart and correct, simple and good people are always welcome. You can easily change anything you want in my questions or answers. Don't worry about a change of the title.

Comment: For the numbering of the answers, please, type A, B, C, D, and E, otherwise I have to change the title page that I gave to my students. :-((((

Comment: The defaults didn't change (except the horizontal space after answer letter-or-number which was too small IMHO; I changed it last night). This is just an *option*. The second example uses option `answer-number-format` to modify the numbering style. If you don't use this option, you still have  A, B, C, D, etc. numbering inside squares.

Comment: Very kind frougon I have tried your excellent code and thank you very much always also for your excellent answers. But I have a doubt: why have I not a random questions for the test? The random answers for the possibile options A, B, C, D, E work correctly. Have you the possiblity to add a random questions? Thank you again.

Comment: Hi Sebastiano, I had not understood you wanted the questions in random order too. Unfortunately, I don't have the time now, but will look at it when I can.

Comment: Hi, again. Yes, if it is possible. Don't worry, you can do my request when you will hava a bit of time. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi, please check the updated answer and tell me if you find a problem. You now need to use the `questionnaire` environment. With this update, neither questions nor answers are shuffled by default anymore, but the new options `shuffle-questions` and `shuffle-answers` allow you to choose what you want.

Comment: Hi :-), very kindest frougon everything OK and I thank you immediately as I can. You were very kind like so many others users I have appreciated.

Comment: Glad to hear it works fine. I made a small update to `sebmcq.sty` to explain a technical choice I made yesterday and avoid some problems in the future (the question and answer texts are now wrapped in braces to prevent `\bfseries` and friends from leaking to the following text; this also prevents `\item` from picking up an unwanted optional argument from an opening bracket that might start the question text). You don't need to change your `.tex` files, just update the `.sty`.

Comment: Very kindest Frougon....thank you ...very much. I hope that you have seen....:-)..Ok, now I will modificate the `.sty` file. But just a curiosity? :-) Where can I put the code to generate image with `\begin{figure}` using `graphicx`? Into or out the `questionnaire` I have mistakes.

Comment: @Sebastiano I know you've received a good education, contrary to so many users on this site... Regarding your question, you can't use `figure` or `table` inside the questionnaire because they create a *float*, but you can use `\includegraphics` which merely creates a box, like any text character. TeX doesn't make any difference! Ditto for a `tikzpicture`, by the way (a `tikzpicture` is also a box, but in some cases with a `\raise` or `\lower` command in front of it, which in rare circumstances can cause little problems—this is when options like `baseline` and `overlay` are used, IIRC).

Comment: I'd be glad to... For people wondering, the rare problems I mentioned that can occur with Ti*k*Z options `baseline` and `overlay` are explained in [PGF bug 345](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/345/).

Comment: Gasp, another tiny update to `sebmcq.sty`: `\l_sebmcq_after_answer_num_skip` was declared with `dim` type instead of `skip`, which would have prevented one from effectively using stretchable glue for the `after-answer-num-skip` option (so, probably no change for what you've written so far). No need to thank me, I've just been stupid forgetting to update the type after doing a search & replace on the variable name!

Comment: The +1 for the comment is only for the....virus. :-)

Comment: Hi very kind, please, when you have a bit of your time can you see my recent question related to this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/611635/multiple-choice-questions-with-proposed-answers-in-random-order-a3paper-not-wor. Thank you very much.