# Create fancy multiple choice exam with circled options

Tags: exam

I haven't been able to find any source where I can get a template for creating an exam with multiple choice. But the choices must be circled so student fill them....does anyone know any source?.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX!  The `circledsteps` package might help.

Comment: Hello Christian, welcome to TeX.SX. There is an example with circled question numbers in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/529060/73317) (the way the question number is printed is customizable).

Comment: the problem with that post is that it is not working in overflow... it shows errors, even at copy paste...

Comment: The answer I mentioned contains a package. Obviously, documents using that package won't work if the package is not installed.

Comment: I don't know how to do that

Comment: If you have a TeX distribution (such as TeX Live or MiKTeX) installed on your computer, you can simply copy the `.sty` file in the same directory as the `.tex` file that uses it, and it will work. If documents are in multiple directories, it is best to put the `.sty` file in a “local texmf tree”. The latter place is distribution-dependent, but every TeX distribution offers this possibility.

Comment: I use overflow, because every time I install latex in my computer it doesn't work..it doesn't even show a blank page.

Comment: Sorry, in this case, I can't help.

Comment: You can use tikz with [baseline=A.base] where A is the node name.  It would help if you provided an overlook compatible MWE.