# Strange alphanumeric symbols using URW-classico

Tags: packages, expl3, xparse, fontfamily

I was trying to create a retrieval test for some students, and while I didn't change anything for this code with the `sebmeq.sty` located in this response from very nice user **@frougon**:

[Multiple choice questions with proposed answers in random order — addition of automatic correction (cross mark)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/529034/multiple-choice-questions-with-proposed-answers-in-random-order-addition-of-au)

I have tried this MWE and it works perfectly (note that `a3paper` work correctly - To seem be `a3paper`):

```
 \documentclass[leqno,10pt]{extarticle}
    \usepackage[italian]{babel}
    \usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
    \usepackage{multicol,xcolor,array}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{landscape,a3paper,
              tmargin=0.6in,bmargin=0.35in,hmargin=0.35in}
    \usepackage{expl3}             % for \int_to_alph:n
    \usepackage{xparse}           % only for the 'test' environment
    \usepackage[shuffle-questions, shuffle-answers]{sebmcq}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    
    \ExplSyntaxOn
    \NewDocumentEnvironment { test } { m +b }
      { \prg_replicate:nn { #1 } { #2 \clearpage } }
      { }
    \ExplSyntaxOff
    \ShowCorrectAnswers
    
    
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \setlength{\headheight}{16pt}
    \lhead{\sffamily\bfseries Classe  \textit{Liceo Scient. S.A.}}
    \chead{\sffamily\bfseries a.s. 2020--2021}
    \rhead{\sffamily\bfseries Test 30 domande --- FISICA ---}
    
    \usepackage{siunitx}  
    \sisetup{output-decimal-marker={\text{,}},
             exponent-product=\cdot}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    
    \begin{document}
    \large
    \begin{multicols}{5}
    \begin{questionnaire}
    
    \question{Quale delle seguenti affermazioni è corretta?}
    {    {Un corpo esteso o rigido è in equilibrio se la risultante delle forze agenti sul corpo è nulla.}
        {Un corpo rigido o esteso è in equilibrio se la risultante dei momenti agenti sul corpo è nulla.}
       [X]{Un corpo esteso è in equilibrio se la risultante delle forze e la risultante dei momenti che agiscono sul corpo sono entrambe nulle.}
        {Un corpo esteso è in equilibrio se la forza  che agisce sul baricentro è nulla.}
    }
    
    \question{100 DVD impilati formano un cilindro; possiamo inclinare tale cilindro in modo che rimanga in equilibrio?}
    {     {No, perché un cilindro non retto non rimane in equilibrio.}
        {Si, sempre perché i DVD sono molto leggeri.}
      [X]{Sì, se la verticale passante per il baricentro (punto compreso tra il centro del 50-esimo e 51-esimo DVD), cade nel piano di appoggio della colonna.}
        {No, perché tra un DVD e l'altro c'è poco attrito.}
    }
    
    \question{Quale delle seguenti affermazioni è corretta?}
    {    {Un corpo esteso o rigido è in equilibrio se la risultante delle forze agenti sul corpo è nulla.}
        {Un corpo rigido o esteso è in equilibrio se la risultante dei momenti agenti sul corpo è nulla.}
       [X]{Un corpo esteso è in equilibrio se la risultante delle forze e la risultante dei momenti che agiscono sul corpo sono entrambe nulle.}
        {Un corpo esteso è in equilibrio se la forza  che agisce sul baricentro è nulla.}
    }
    \question{Quale delle seguenti affermazioni è corretta?}
    {    {Un corpo esteso o rigido è in equilibrio se la risultante delle forze agenti sul corpo è nulla.}
        {Un corpo rigido o esteso è in equilibrio se la risultante dei momenti agenti sul corpo è nulla.}
       [X]{Un corpo esteso è in equilibrio se la risultante delle forze e la risultante dei momenti che agiscono sul corpo sono entrambe nulle.}
        {Un corpo esteso è in equilibrio se la forza  che agisce sul baricentro è nulla.}
    }
    \question{Quale delle seguenti affermazioni è corretta?}
    {    {Un corpo esteso o rigido è in equilibrio se la risultante delle forze agenti sul corpo è nulla.}
        {Un corpo rigido o esteso è in equilibrio se la risultante dei momenti agenti sul corpo è nulla.}
       [X]{Un corpo esteso è in equilibrio se la risultante delle forze e la risultante dei momenti che agiscono sul corpo sono entrambe nulle.}
        {Un corpo esteso è in equilibrio se la forza  che agisce sul baricentro è nulla.}
    }
    \question{Quale delle seguenti affermazioni è corretta?}
    {    {Un corpo esteso o rigido è in equilibrio se la risultante delle forze agenti sul corpo è nulla.}
        {Un corpo rigido o esteso è in equilibrio se la risultante dei momenti agenti sul corpo è nulla.}
       [X]{Un corpo esteso è in equilibrio se la risultante delle forze e la risultante dei momenti che agiscono sul corpo sono entrambe nulle.}
        {Un corpo esteso è in equilibrio se la forza  che agisce sul baricentro è nulla.}
    }
    \question{Quale delle seguenti affermazioni è corretta?}
    {    {Un corpo esteso o rigido è in equilibrio se la risultante delle forze agenti sul corpo è nulla.}
        {Un corpo rigido o esteso è in equilibrio se la risultante dei momenti agenti sul corpo è nulla.}
       [X]{Un corpo esteso è in equilibrio se la risultante delle forze e la risultante dei momenti che agiscono sul corpo sono entrambe nulle.}
        {Un corpo esteso è in equilibrio se la forza  che agisce sul baricentro è nulla.}
    }
    \question{Quale delle seguenti affermazioni è corretta?}
    {    {Un corpo esteso o rigido è in equilibrio se la risultante delle forze agenti sul corpo è nulla.}
        {Un corpo rigido o esteso è in equilibrio se la risultante dei momenti agenti sul corpo è nulla.}
       [X]{Un corpo esteso è in equilibrio se la risultante delle forze e la risultante dei momenti che agiscono sul corpo sono entrambe nulle.}
        {Un corpo esteso è in equilibrio se la forza  che agisce sul baricentro è nulla.}
    }
    \question{Quale delle seguenti affermazioni è corretta?}
    {    {Un corpo esteso o rigido è in equilibrio se la risultante delle forze agenti sul corpo è nulla.}
        {Un corpo rigido o esteso è in equilibrio se la risultante dei momenti agenti sul corpo è nulla.}
       [X]{Un corpo esteso è in equilibrio se la risultante delle forze e la risultante dei momenti che agiscono sul corpo sono entrambe nulle.}
        {Un corpo esteso è in equilibrio se la forza  che agisce sul baricentro è nulla.}
    }
    \question{Quale delle seguenti affermazioni è corretta?}
    {    {Un corpo esteso o rigido è in equilibrio se la risultante delle forze agenti sul corpo è nulla.}
        {Un corpo rigido o esteso è in equilibrio se la risultante dei momenti agenti sul corpo è nulla.}
       [X]{Un corpo esteso è in equilibrio se la risultante delle forze e la risultante dei momenti che agiscono sul corpo sono entrambe nulle.}
        {Un corpo esteso è in equilibrio se la forza  che agisce sul baricentro è nulla.}
    }
    \question{Quale delle seguenti affermazioni è corretta?}
    {    {Un corpo esteso o rigido è in equilibrio se la risultante delle forze agenti sul corpo è nulla.}
        {Un corpo rigido o esteso è in equilibrio se la risultante dei momenti agenti sul corpo è nulla.}
       [X]{Un corpo esteso è in equilibrio se la risultante delle forze e la risultante dei momenti che agiscono sul corpo sono entrambe nulle.}
        {Un corpo esteso è in equilibrio se la forza  che agisce sul baricentro è nulla.}
    }
    \question{Quale delle seguenti affermazioni è corretta?}
    {    {Un corpo esteso o rigido è in equilibrio se la risultante delle forze agenti sul corpo è nulla.}
        {Un corpo rigido o esteso è in equilibrio se la risultante dei momenti agenti sul corpo è nulla.}
       [X]{Un corpo esteso è in equilibrio se la risultante delle forze e la risultante dei momenti che agiscono sul corpo sono entrambe nulle.}
        {Un corpo esteso è in equilibrio se la forza  che agisce sul baricentro è nulla.}
    }
    \question{Quale delle seguenti affermazioni è corretta?}
    {    {Un corpo esteso o rigido è in equilibrio se la risultante delle forze agenti sul corpo è nulla.}
        {Un corpo rigido o esteso è in equilibrio se la risultante dei momenti agenti sul corpo è nulla.}
       [X]{Un corpo esteso è in equilibrio se la risultante delle forze e la risultante dei momenti che agiscono sul corpo sono entrambe nulle.}
        {Un corpo esteso è in equilibrio se la forza  che agisce sul baricentro è nulla.}
    }
    \question{Quale delle seguenti affermazioni è corretta?}
    {    {Un corpo esteso o rigido è in equilibrio se la risultante delle forze agenti sul corpo è nulla.}
        {Un corpo rigido o esteso è in equilibrio se la risultante dei momenti agenti sul corpo è nulla.}
       [X]{Un corpo esteso è in equilibrio se la risultante delle forze e la risultante dei momenti che agiscono sul corpo sono entrambe nulle.}
        {Un corpo esteso è in equilibrio se la forza  che agisce sul baricentro è nulla.}
    }
    
    \end{questionnaire}
    \end{multicols}
    \end{document}
```

But when I use this code using `URW-Classico` font here [classico.tds.zip](http://mirrors.ctan.org/install/fonts/urw/classico.tds.zip):

```
\documentclass[leqno,12pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
% Qui ridefinisco il font sans-serif di default, così che rimanga sempre
% URW-Classico.
\renewcommand*\sfdefault{uop}
% E poi considero la famiglia di default per tutto il documento sans-serif
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{graphicx,multicol,xcolor,array}
\graphicspath{ {img/} }

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{landscape,a3paper,
          tmargin=0.6in,bmargin=0.35in,hmargin=0.35in}

% (JFB: con mathastext e lo stesso opzione "basic"
%  lettere e numeri in modo matematico utilizzano anche URW-Classico)
\usepackage[italic,basic, default mathsizes]{mathastext}
\MTlettershape{sl}\Mathastext
% (JFB: provo con piccoli extra spazi dopo le lettere)
\makeatletter
\@for\@tempa:=a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z\do{%
\MTsetmathskips{\@tempa}{0mu}{0.5mu}}%
\@for\@tempa:=A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z\do{%
\MTsetmathskips{\@tempa}{0mu}{0.5mu}}%
\makeatother
   
\usepackage{expl3}             % for \int_to_alph:n
\usepackage{xparse}           % only for the 'test' environment
\usepackage[shuffle-questions, shuffle-answers]{sebmcq}
 

\pagestyle{empty}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment { test } { m +b }
  { \prg_replicate:nn { #1 } { #2 \clearpage } }
  { }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\ShowCorrectAnswers


\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
% i=intervallo, a=aperto, c=chiuso
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\IAA{]}{[}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\IAC{]}{]}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ICA{[}{[}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ICC{[}{]}
% esempi di uso: 
% \IAA{0,1} -> ]0,1[ con gli spazi adeguati
% \IAA*{0,1} -> \left]0,1\right[
% \IAA[\bigg]{0,1} -> \biggl]0,1\biggr[

% Nuovo \mathbb{R}
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{futm}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{futm}{m}{n}{
  <-> s * [.95] fourier-bb
  }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{Ufutm}{U}{futm}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathbb}{Ufutm}
\usepackage[cal=boondoxo,calscaled=.97,bb=boondox]{mathalfa}

% Taking f from fouriernc font
  \DeclareFontEncoding{FML}{}{}
  \DeclareFontSubstitution{FML}{fncmi}{m}{it}
  \DeclareSymbolFont{fourierletters}{FML}{fncmi}{m}{it}
  \SetSymbolFont{fourierletters}{bold}{FML}{fncmi}{b}{it}
%
  \DeclareMathSymbol {f}{\mathalpha}{fourierletters}{`f}

% si deve fare qualcosa di più per ragione di mathastext
\makeatletter
  \DeclareMathSymbol {\mst@f}{\mathalpha}{fourierletters}{`f}
\makeatother

% Taking g from fouriernc font
  \DeclareFontEncoding{FML}{}{}
  \DeclareFontSubstitution{FML}{fncmi}{m}{it}
  \DeclareSymbolFont{fourierletters}{FML}{fncmi}{m}{it}
  \SetSymbolFont{fourierletters}{bold}{FML}{fncmi}{b}{it}
%
  \DeclareMathSymbol {g}{\mathalpha}{fourierletters}{`g}
% si deve fare qualcosa di più per ragione di mathastext
\makeatletter
  \DeclareMathSymbol {\mst@g}{\mathalpha}{fourierletters}{`g}
\makeatother

% Taking k from fouriernc font
  \DeclareFontEncoding{FML}{}{}
  \DeclareFontSubstitution{FML}{fncmi}{m}{it}
  \DeclareSymbolFont{fourierletters}{FML}{fncmi}{m}{it}
  \SetSymbolFont{fourierletters}{bold}{FML}{fncmi}{b}{it}
%
  \DeclareMathSymbol {k}{\mathalpha}{fourierletters}{`k}
% si deve fare qualcosa di più per ragione di mathastext
\makeatletter
\DeclareMathSymbol {\mst@k}{\mathalpha}{fourierletters}{`k}
\makeatother

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\headheight}{16pt}
\lhead{\sffamily\bfseries Classe  \textit{Liceo Scient. S.A.}}
\chead{\sffamily\bfseries a.s. 2020--2021}
\rhead{\sffamily\bfseries Test 30 domande --- FISICA ---}

\usepackage{siunitx}  
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={\text{,}},
         exponent-product=\cdot}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\large
\begin{multicols}{5}
\begin{questionnaire}

\question{Quale delle seguenti affermazioni è corretta?}
{    {Un corpo esteso o rigido è in equilibrio se la risultante delle forze agenti sul corpo è nulla.}
    {Un corpo rigido o esteso è in equilibrio se la risultante dei momenti agenti sul corpo è nulla.}
   [X]{Un corpo esteso è in equilibrio se la risultante delle forze e la risultante dei momenti che agiscono sul corpo sono entrambe nulle.}
    {Un corpo esteso è in equilibrio se la forza  che agisce sul baricentro è nulla.}
}

\question{100 DVD impilati formano un cilindro; possiamo inclinare tale cilindro in modo che rimanga in equilibrio?}
{     {No, perché un cilindro non retto non rimane in equilibrio.}
    {Si, sempre perché i DVD sono molto leggeri.}
  [X]{Sì, se la verticale passante per il baricentro (punto compreso tra il centro del 50-esimo e 51-esimo DVD), cade nel piano di appoggio della colonna.}
    {No, perché tra un DVD e l'altro c'è poco attrito.}
}

\end{questionnaire}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

I get this with a strange string **T@TS1**:

[image]

Last year I have never had this problem although I have always used URW-classico.

> How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Hello Sebastiano. I'm sorry, but I can't reproduce the problem. I tried with `pdflatex` on TeX Live 2020 and 2021 (updated a minute ago). I commented out the part about `uop`. In both cases, the output file is in landscape A3 format and there is no `T@TS1` that I can see. Besides, you should have reduced your problem to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/73317). As far as I'm concerned, there is no need to modify the `sebmcq.sty` file, but if the problem is reproducible on your side, I'm sure that doesn't require such a lengthy .tex file.

Comment: @frougon Hi again very kind frougon. I have restrict the code, but I think that the problem is `uop`. I am not very able to improve my question. Any helpful suggestions you have for writing my issue well are appreciated - you can do whatever you think is helpful. Thank you very much.

Comment: The T@TS1 string came up already it's a bug in siunitx which will be fixed in the next release, it is unrelated to the fonts here

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you very much for your precious help. I have removed `\usepackage{siunitx}  
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={\text{,}},
         exponent-product=\cdot}` and all work perfectly. I will thank you further.