Create exam with random chosen questions
These days I'm trying to write code to create quizzes. For example, I have a bank of 10 questions. This file is tex.
I want to write the second tex file in a way that two questions are randomly selected from this bank. Let it give answers to the selected questions at the end of the PDF.
Could you help me?
ps: All questions are multiple-choice

If you can use Linux, try AMC (auto-multiple-choice): Is not (only)  a LaTeX package. There are a few questions about if is this site.

I suggest this link https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/529034/multiple-choice-questions-with-proposed-answers-in-random-order-addition-of-au I think that is  your question.

There is the exam-radomizechoices package.  Not sure if it can handle using only some of the questions each time.
