# Improving mathabx's long arrows

Tags: symbols, relation-symbols, mathabx

In my opinion, `mathabx` has the nicest arrows. However, it doesn't include long arrows as single glyphs, so they are built in the same way `amsmath` builds their arrows, with the code `\def\longleftarrow{\relbar\protect\joinrel\leftarrow}`.

The problem is that mathabx's `relbar` has roundend corners, the same as the endings of mathbax`s arrows. Hence, long arrows present an imperfection in the middle. It is shown in the following picture, with zoom=98526.1%.

[image]

A partial solution is to redefine the `relbar` as the `-` sign. This fix one ''hill'' but it still remains another one:

[image]

In this case zoom= 98526.1% too.

Thus, **My question**: does anybody know how to fix this problem?

Thanks
Here I write my `mwe`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathabx}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{matha}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{matha}{m}{n}{
      <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10> gen * matha
      <10.95> matha10 <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88> matha12
      }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{matha}{U}{matha}{m}{n}
%\let\rightarrow\abc
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varrelbar}{\mathrel}{matha}{1}
\def\varlongrightarrow{\varrelbar\protect\joinrel\rightarrow}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
&\longrightarrow \\
&\varlongrightarrow
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

EDIT

I add a figure showing the arrowhead of one arrow (zoom=147789%)

[image]

Comment: Please help us out and provide a minimum working example of code.

Comment: Oh, yes. Sorry. I'll edit the question. Thanks.

Comment: I do not get your behavior...I get a highly pixelated arrowhead, but a straight arrow shank without anomaly (when using Adobe reader).  When using TeXworks viewer, I do get a shaft anomaly, but in the form of a single stair step.

Comment: Did you compile with pdfLaTeX?

Comment: Yes I did compile with `pdflatex`.

Comment: I don't know. May it be a problem in my `mathabx`package? Anyway, despite of the different behabviour, you still have an anomaly with long arrows.

Comment: Is your arrowhead pixelated?  Your included images would suggest not.

Comment: No, the arrowheads look fine. Let me include the pictures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `\clipbox` to cut off the ends of `\relbar` and `\rightarrow` instead of having them overlap.
This command is defined in the `trimclip` package, which is part of [`adjustbox`](https://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) and is documented separately [here](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/adjustbox/trimclip.pdf).

It feels a little bit like overkill, but it works and I'm not really sure how else you could accomplish this.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathabx}

\usepackage{trimclip}
\makeatletter %% <- make @ usable in command names
\newcommand*\clipjoin[2]{\mathrel{\mathpalette\clipjoin@{{#1}{#2}}}}
\def\clipjoin@#1#2{\clipjoin@@{#1}#2}
\def\clipjoin@@#1#2#3{%
  \begingroup
    \settowidth\@tempdima{$\m@th#1\mkern3mu$}%
      \trimbox{0pt 128pt {.01\@tempdima} 128pt}{\clipbox{0pt -128pt {.49\@tempdima} -128pt}{$\m@th#1#2$}}%
      \trimbox{{.01\@tempdima} 128pt 0pt 128pt}{\clipbox{{.49\@tempdima} -128pt 0pt -128pt}{$\m@th#1#3$}}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother  %% <- revert @

\newcommand*\cliprightarrow{\clipjoin{\relbar}{\rightarrow}}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
    \longrightarrow
    \\[\glueexpr1ex-\baselineskip]
    \cliprightarrow
    \\
    \scriptstyle
    \longrightarrow
    \\[\glueexpr1ex-\baselineskip]
    \scriptstyle
    \cliprightarrow
    \\
    \scriptscriptstyle
    \cliprightarrow
    \\[\glueexpr1ex-\baselineskip]
    \scriptscriptstyle
    \longrightarrow
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

Here's the result at 600dpi:

[image: output]

*(From top to bottom, these are pairs of arrows in `\displaystyle`, `\scriptstyle` and `\scriptscriptstyle`, and of each pair the top one is a `\longrightarrow` and the bottom one is a `\cliprightarrow`)*

---

To illustrate what this looks like from really close by, I've loaded `xcolor` and defined.

```
\newcommand*\cliprightarrow{\clipjoin{\relbar}{\color{red}\rightarrow}}
```

Here is the part where the arrows meet at 300 000 dpi (~100 000%?):

[image: GOOD]

And here is, for comparison, what the original `\longrightarrow` looks like at the same resolution:

[image: BAD]

### Notes:

- I'm using [`\mathpalette`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34393/156366) to get the size of the arrow right at every math style.
- I'm measuring how wide `3mu` is at the current math style because this is how much will need to be cut off from `\relbar` and `\rightarrow` (together) to get the same length as with `\joinrel`.
- `\clipbox{<left> <bottom> <right> <top>}{<stuff>}` clips `<left>`/`<bottom>`/`<right>`/`<top>` from the left/bottom/right/top of `<stuff>`. The part that is clipped off won't be printed
- `\trimbox{<left> <bottom> <right> <top>}{<stuff>}` just changes the bounding box of `<stuff>` in the same way.
- I've used large negative numbers (`-128pt`) for the vertical lengths in the argument of `\clipbox` because `\rightarrow` is larger than its bounding box and the top of the arrowhead would otherwise be cut off. I then correct this by putting the result in a `\trimbox` that shrinks the bounding box by the same amount.
- I'm clipping off only `1.47mu` from `\relbar` and `\rightarrow` rather than `1.5mu` and trimming each by `0.03` to ensure that there is still a (really tiny) overlap between the arrow shaft and the arrowhead, just in case.

Comment: I know that comments conggratulating the answers should be avoided. But this answer so fantastic that I have to do it. Just amazing. Thanks.