# Automatically use long arrows in display mode

Tags: math-mode, displaystyle

I'd like to have the command `\to` produce the arrow from `\longrightarrow`, but *only* when in a display mode, making use of the available space.
More precisely, the output of

```
So we have a map $A \to B$.
```

should be left unchanged, but

```
So we have a map
\[
    A \to B.
\]
```

should produce the same as

```
So we have a map
\[
    A \longrightarrow B.
\]
```

If possible, I'd like the same to happen to `\mapsto` getting replaced by `\longmapsto` when in display mode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if it is wise to do this (perhaps something breaks?), but you certainly can do this by redefining `\to` using `\mathchoice`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand\to{\mathchoice{\longrightarrow}{\rightarrow}{\rightarrow}{\rightarrow}}
\begin{document}

  So we have a map $A \to B$ and we have a map
  \[ C \to D.  \]

\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

I have made it so that `\to` expands to `\longrightarrow` in display mode and otherwise to `\rightarrow` for text, script and scriptscript styles - in `fontmath.ltx` the `\to` command is defined as `\let\to\rightarrow`.

Have a look at [The mysteries of \mathpalette](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34393/the-mysteries-of-mathpalette) for a description of the `\mathchoice` and `\mathpalette` commands.

Comment: I'd use `\rightarrow` instead of `\realto`, no need for the `\let`.

Comment: Although doing the same for `\mapsto` would require a `\let`-construction, would it not?

Comment: @SvanN You could either do something like `\let\realmapsto\mapsto` and then `\renewcommand\mapsto{\mathchoice{\longmapsto}{\realmapsto}{\realmapsto}{\realmapsto}}` or instead use `\renewcommand\mapsto{\mathchoice{\longmapsto}{\mapstochar\rightarrow}{\mapstochar\rightarrow}{\mapstochar\rightarrow}}`. [If you look in `fontmath.ltx` you will find `\def\mapsto{\mapstochar\rightarrow}`.]