# How to realise curved slash in mathmode?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

[image]

As in the picture, there is a X//H with the double slash curved. It seems `\wr` is similar to this symbol, but not oblique enough and \big does not work for `\wr`.

How can I type this double curved slash?

Comment: Hi, welcome! You can always scale symbols using \scalebox, which ships with the graphicx package. And you will benefit from posting a minimal example that shows what you have tried.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can rotate the `\approx` symbol and set it as a `rel`ation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@curveslash}[2]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{70}{$#1#2$}}
\newcommand{\curveslash}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\@curveslash\approx}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\ldots enveloping quotient $H \curveslash H$.
\[
  H \curveslash H_{H \curveslash H_{H \curveslash H}}
\]

\end{document}
```

The use of `\mathpalette` results in a `\mathchoice` with access to the different math styles (see [The mysteries of `\mathpalette`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34393/5764)).