# Double equal sign - Problem with \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

Tags: font-encodings

I have made a macro to type a double equal sign but the signs are thinner when I use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` (see the picture and the code below). How can I fix this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % <--- This is the guilty package
\usepackage{ucs}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand\shorteq{\resizebox{.5em}{\heightof{=}}{=}}

\newcommand\eqtest{\mathop{\shorteq\mkern1mu\shorteq}}

\begin{document}

$A \eqtest B$

$A = B$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the text mode `=` instead of the math mode one.

Here's a different implementation that also scales automatically in subscripts and superscripts. You don't need `calc`, because in the context of `\resizebox` you can use `\width` and `\height` to refer to the dimensions of the box being resized.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\shorteq{\mathrel{\mathpalette\shorteq@{.75}}}
\newcommand{\shorteq@}[2]{%
  \resizebox{#2\width}{\height}{$\m@th#1=$}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A \shorteq B$

$A = B$

$X_{a\shorteq b}$

$X_{a=b}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notes.

1. `ucs` is obsolete and does nothing useful
2. `inputenc` is not necessary if `utf8` input is used.
3. A relative width has been used (adjust it to suit) rather than `0.5em` that makes little sense.

Comment: Thanks for the code and the comments. What is the 1st argument of `\shorteq@`?

Comment: @projetmbc It is the current math style, provided by `\mathpalette`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34393/4427

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link!