# How to use \only or similar to align content inside `align` environment?

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, align

Please consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Copenhagen}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{}
Text.
\begin{align*}
    A&=B\\
    \only<2>{
    &\color{red}{C=D+1-5M\implies E=1}\\
    }
    \uncover<3->{&=C\\}
    \uncover<4->{&=B}
\end{align*}
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The problem is on slide 2, where `A=B` is not in the same position as in slides 1, 3 and 5:

[image: MWE output]

I want the red because is a note for a property that I will use in the next step, however it is the only slide that is not aligned with respect to the others.

I would like to have the following output (see slide 2.):

[image: What I want]

How can we achieve the last image not using commands like `\hspace`?

Comment: just put it in `\[...\]` after the alignment? (since you don't want it aligned)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle hi! Sorry if I have not explained well, I want `A=B` of slide 2 aligned with the rest of lines (`=C` and `=B`). Also, the red part should be aligned to the middle.

Comment: yes isn't that what you would get?

Comment: You said I don't want it aligned, what do you mean by that? I want to align the slide 2 properly.

Comment: the red part has no alignment with the black so no need to put it in the `align` just make it a `\[..\[`

Comment: Do you mean break the `align` into two like this?: https://imgur.com/a/WVsYj3C It creates a lot of space around and the black lines are not aligned w.r.t. `=`.

Comment: actually what I meant doesn't work as well as I intended, so forget it:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for the elements to stop flickering between slides, they need to have the same width. One can assure they have the same width by using components from [`eqparbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox) (with a modification to allow for math content via `\eqmathbox[<tag>][<align>]{<stuff>}`). Additionally, I use `\alt<os>{<default>}{<other>}` which puts `<default>` on the provided `o`verlay `s`pecification and `<other>` otherwise.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
%\usepackage{xparse}% If you have LaTeX2e < 2020-10-01

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34412/5764
\makeatletter
% \eqmathbox[<tag>][<align>]{<math>}
\NewDocumentCommand{\eqmathbox}{o O{c} m}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}
    {\def\eqmathbox@##1##2{\eqmakebox[#1][#2]{$##1##2$}}}
    {\def\eqmathbox@##1##2{\eqmakebox{$##1##2$}}}
  \mathpalette\eqmathbox@{#3}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{block}{}
  Text.
  \begin{align*}
    \eqmathbox[LHS][r]{A} &\eqmathbox[RHS][l]{{} = B} \\
    \alt<2>{\eqmathbox[LHS][r]{\color{red}C = D + 1}}{} &
      \alt<2>{\eqmathbox[RHS][l]{\color{red}{} - 5M \implies E = 1}}{\uncover<3->{= C}} \\
    \uncover<4->{&= D}
  \end{align*}
\end{block}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It seems that my LaTeX distribution is having some issues with respect to `eqparbox`. I use pdfLaTeX. In Overleaf it throws me a lot of errors, and in TeXworks says: "! Undefined control sequence. l.29 \NewDocumentCommand                        {\eqmathbox}{o O{c} m}{%"

Comment: @manooooh add `\usepackage{xparse}` for older releases. (as Werner has already put in a comment in the code)