# Pad text with space to a certain width

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment

I've made the equations align here using `\hphantom{}`:

```
\begin{theorem}[Möbius inversion]
    Let $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, and let $g$ and $h$ be complex-valued functions defined on $\mathbb{Z}^+$ or on the set of divisors of $n$.
    \renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\roman{enumi})}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item If\hphantom{then} $\displaystyle h(k) = \sum\limits_{d \mid k} g(d) \hphantom{\mu(k/d)}$ \quad for all $k$, \\\\
        then\hphantom{If} $\displaystyle g(k) = \sum\limits_{d \mid k} \mu(k/d) h(d)$ \quad for all $k$. \\
        \item If\hphantom{then} $\displaystyle h(k) = \sum\limits_{k \mid d \mid n} g(d) \hphantom{\mu(d/k)}$ \quad for all $k$, \\\\
        then\hphantom{If} $\displaystyle g(k) = \sum\limits_{k \mid d \mid n} \mu(d/k) h(d)$ \quad for all $k$.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}
```

[image]

However, it's a bit of a hassle and it's not a very flexible method. I'd like something like `\paddedtext{2em}{If}` which takes the text `If` and adds horizontal space so that its width is `2em`. Or some way to say "insert 2em minus the length of If".

Comment: Off-topic: Do change `\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\roman{enumi})}` to `\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\upshape(\roman{enumi})}`. That way, `(i)`, `(ii)` etc will be rendered in the upright font shape, making them look more "structural" and less like part of the running text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While there may be a little overhead in guessing proper values for `\tabA` and `\tabB`, it remains efficient from a typing point of view.  This uses the `tabto` package for tabbing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{tabto}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}[M\"obius inversion]
  Let $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, and let~$g$ and~$h$ be complex-valued functions defined on $\mathbb{Z}^+$ or on the set of divisors of~$n$.
  \renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\roman{enumi})}
  \newcommand\tabA{\tabto{.35in}}
  \newcommand\tabB{\tabto{1.8in}}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item If\tabA $\displaystyle h(k) = 
      \sum\limits_{d \mid k} g(d)$\tabB for all $k$,
      
      then\tabA $\displaystyle g(k) = 
      \sum\limits_{d \mid k} \mu(k/d) h(d)$\tabB for all $k$.
      
    \item If\tabA $\displaystyle h(k) = 
      \sum\limits_{k \mid d \mid n} g(d)$\tabB for all $k$,
      
      then\tabA $\displaystyle g(k) = 
      \sum\limits_{k \mid d \mid n} \mu(d/k) h(d)$\tabB for all $k$.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This seems like an ideal job for [`eqparbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox), since it's flexible for variable content: `\eqmakebox[<tag>][<align>]{<stuff>}` sets `<stuff>` in a box that is widest across the same `<tag>` with a specific `<align>`ment (`l`eft, `r`ight or `c`entre).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{eqparbox}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34412/5764
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\eqmathbox}{o O{c} m}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}
    {\def\eqmathbox@##1##2{\eqmakebox[#1][#2]{$##1##2$}}}
    {\def\eqmathbox@##1##2{\eqmakebox{$##1##2$}}}
  \mathpalette\eqmathbox@{#3}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[M\"obius inversion]
  Let $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, and let~$g$ and~$h$ be complex-valued functions defined on $\mathbb{Z}^+$ or on the set of divisors of~$n$.
  \renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\roman{enumi})}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item \eqmakebox[ifthen][l]{If} $\displaystyle \eqmathbox[hg][r]{h(k)} = 
      \eqmathbox[mobsum][l]{\sum\limits_{d \mid k} g(d)}$ for all $k$,
      
      \eqmakebox[ifthen][l]{then}   $\displaystyle \eqmathbox[hg][r]{g(k)} = 
      \eqmathbox[mobsum][l]{\sum\limits_{d \mid k} \mu(k/d) h(d)}$ for all~$k$.
      
    \item \eqmakebox[ifthen][l]{If} $\displaystyle \eqmathbox[hg][r]{h(k)} = 
      \eqmathbox[mobsum][l]{\sum\limits_{k \mid d \mid n} g(d)}$ for all~$k$,
      
      \eqmakebox[ifthen][l]{then}   $\displaystyle \eqmathbox[hg][r]{g(k)} = 
      \eqmathbox[mobsum][l]{\sum\limits_{k \mid d \mid n} \mu(d/k) h(d)}$ for all~$k$.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

`eqparbox` uses a `\label`-`\ref`-like system to capture the widths and therefore require multiple compilations with any change of the widest element by `<tag>`.

Comment: It doesn't compile for me. The preamble generates errors: "You can't use `macro parameter character #' in math mode. \mathpalette\eqmathbox@{#3}", "Undefined control sequence. \NewDocumentCommand", "Parameters must be numbered consecutively. {\def\eqmathbox@##" etc

Comment: @Blrp: This is because you don't have an up-to-date LaTeX. So you need to add `\usepackage{xparse}` to your preamble before the definition of `\eqmathbox`.

Answer (score 3):

Your `\paddedtext{2em}{If}` should be defined using TeX primitives like this:

```
\def\paddedtext#1#2{\leavevmode\hbox to#1{#2\hss}\ignorespaces}
```