# Overbrace on Powers

Tags: syntax, overbrace

How can I make an overbrace on powers without it being buggy. Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{yhmath}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\begin{document}
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
    (x^{m+1})^n &=& \underbrace{x^{m+1} \cdots x^{m+1}}_{n} \\[.8cm]
    &=& x^{\overbrace{(m+1)+\cdots+(m+1)}^{n}} \\[.8cm]
    &=& x^{\overbrace{(m+\cdots+m)}^{n}+\overbrace{(1+\cdots+1)}^{n}}
\end{array}
$$
\end{document}
```

The image below ilustrate the code above.

[image: Output for the code above]

Anyone knows how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I've included all the packages used in my document as well as made it "ctrl+c ctrl+v"-able.

Comment: Please, make a complete example from `\documentclass` up to `\end{document}` that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Ok, I've made the corrections, thanks.

Comment: What PDF viewer are you using? Does the vertical alignment change when you zoom in/out? I'm of the opinion that this is browser/viewer based, not (La)TeX based. The two answers provided suggested that as well as the problem can't be replicated.

Comment: Oh, the problem is certainly with `\usepackage{MnSymbol}` Don't use it.

Comment: Werner, I'm using overleaf, it does not change with zooming. egreg, it was!!!! Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your issue, but the commands `\underbrace` and `\overbrace` cannot really be used in subscripts or superscripts, because they force the material to be in display style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ubrace}[2]{{\mathpalette\ubrace@{{#1}{#2}}}}
\newcommand{\ubrace@}[2]{\ubrace@@{#1}#2}
\newcommand{\ubrace@@}[3]{\underbrace{#1#2}_{#3}}
\newcommand{\obrace}[2]{{\mathpalette\obrace@{{#1}{#2}}}}
\newcommand{\obrace@}[2]{\obrace@@{#1}#2}
\newcommand{\obrace@@}[3]{\overbrace{#1#2}^{#3}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{aligned}
  (x^{m+1})^n
  &=\ubrace{x^{m+1} \cdots x^{m+1}}{n} \\
  &= x^{\obrace{(m+1)+\cdots+(m+1)}{n}} \\
  &= x^{\obrace{(m+\cdots+m)}{n}+\obrace{(1+\cdots+1)}{n}}
\end{aligned}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello egreg. Can you explain a little your code? Why do two extra macros have to be used?

Comment: @projetmbc I need to pass three arguments to `\mathpalette`, but it only accepts two: `\mathpalette` wants as arguments a two-argument macro and the material to be processed. The first argument to the two-argument macro is automatically supplied and is `\displaystyle` and so on. So I delegate the job to a three-argument macro. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34412/4427

Comment: I'll try this solution here and I'll give you the feedback.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. I'll leave it like that because it is just a solutions file I'm making for myself. Thank you very much for the time spent trying to help me, the effort is greatly apreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I cannot reproduce your picture. Below is my picture generated from your example:
[image]

Comment: To be fair, on close examination, I do see a discontinuity between the linear portion and the curved part of the brace also in your example (although consistent in all three cases). But that may just be dependent on the pdf-reader.

Comment: But the output is *very* wrong, don't you agree?

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback! I don't know why it is so broken in my compilation.

Comment: @MatthiasArras, Sharp eyes!! The discontinuity is probably caused by my pdf-reader. It disappeared when I further magnified the picture.

Comment: @egreg, Indeed. Your answer is much better.