# How to put two matrices on top of each other?

Tags: matrices

This code

```
\begin{bmatrix} 
        a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14} \\
        a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24} \\
        a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34} 
    \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
        4 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
        6 & 7 & 8 & 9 
    
    \end{bmatrix}
```

generates two matrices side by side.
How can I make them on top of each other?

Comment: Is mere stacking required, or do columns need to align?  If the former, `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\[
\stackon{
\begin{bmatrix} 
        a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14} \\
        a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24} \\
        a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34} 
    \end{bmatrix}
}{
    \begin{bmatrix}
        5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
        4 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
        6 & 7 & 8 & 9 
    \end{bmatrix}
}
\]
\end{document}`

Comment: Or this:  `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{matrix} 
  {\begin{bmatrix} 
        a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14} \\
        a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24} \\
        a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34} 
    \end{bmatrix}}\\
    {\begin{bmatrix}
        5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
        4 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
        6 & 7 & 8 & 9 
    \end{bmatrix}}
    \end{matrix}
\]
\end{document}` ...but only if columns need not align

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest you place both `bmatrix` environments inside a `gather*` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'bmatrix' and 'gather*' environments

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
\begin{bmatrix} 
        a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14} \\
        a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24} \\
        a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34} 
\end{bmatrix} \\ % <-- force a line break
\begin{bmatrix}
        5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
        4 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
        6 & 7 & 8 & 9  
\end{bmatrix}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here are some options; in principle, wrap the two matrices inside an `array` and separate them using a regular line break `\\`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,eqparbox}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34412/5764
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\eqmathbox}{o O{c} m}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}
    {\def\eqmathbox@##1##2{\eqmakebox[#1][#2]{$##1##2$}}}
    {\def\eqmathbox@##1##2{\eqmakebox{$##1##2$}}}
  \mathpalette\eqmathbox@{#3}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{bmatrix} 
    a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14} \\
    a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24} \\
    a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34} 
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
    4 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
    6 & 7 & 8 & 9 
  \end{bmatrix}
\]

\[
  \begin{array}{@{} c @{}}
    \begin{bmatrix} 
      a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14} \\
      a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24} \\
      a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34} 
    \end{bmatrix} \\
    \begin{bmatrix}
      5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
      4 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
      6 & 7 & 8 & 9 
    \end{bmatrix}
  \end{array} \qquad
  \begin{array}{@{} c @{}}
    \begin{bmatrix} 
      \eqmathbox[aa]{a_{11}} & \eqmathbox[aa]{a_{12}} & \eqmathbox[aa]{a_{13}} & \eqmathbox[aa]{a_{14}} \\
      a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24} \\
      a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34} 
    \end{bmatrix} \\
    \\[\dimexpr-\normalbaselineskip+\jot]
    \begin{bmatrix}
      \eqmathbox[aa]{5} & \eqmathbox[aa]{6} & \eqmathbox[aa]{7} & \eqmathbox[aa]{8} \\
      4 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
      6 & 7 & 8 & 9 
    \end{bmatrix}
  \end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

The addition of [`eqparbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox) (and `\eqmathbox`) depends on whether you want the entries to be aligned across the `bmatrix`-es. You can also consider [`blkarray`](//ctan.org/pkg/blkarray).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the OP wants the columns of the first matrix aligned with the columns of the second. It's possible with `{NiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[\begin{NiceMatrix} 
   a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14} \\
   a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24} \\
   a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34} \\[1mm]
   5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
   4 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
   6 & 7 & 8 & 9  
\CodeAfter
  \SubMatrix[{1-1}{3-4}]
  \SubMatrix[{4-1}{6-4}]
\end{NiceMatrix}\]

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]