# \underbracket in custom command

Tags: mathtools

I am looking to define the custom command `\distr` as follows:

```
\newcommand{\distr}[1]{\underbracket[0.3pt][1pt]{#1}}
```

The command `\underbracket` is the one appearing in `mathtools`. However, I see (at least) two issues upon compiling: (1) when e.g. `distr{f}` appears in a subscript/superscript, the character *f* retains its usual size instead of being shrinked to `\small`; (2) sometimes there is unwanted spacing around `\distr{ }`, for example when script letters appear before it (like `\mathscr{L}\distr{\psi}`). How do I implement `\distr` in such a way to avoid these issues? Apart from `mathtools`, I am using standard mathematics symbol packages such as `amsmath`, `physics`, and `amssymb`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[cal=euler]{mathalfa}

\newcommand{\distr}[1]{\underbracket[0.3pt][1pt]{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation*}
        a_f\ a_{\distr{f}} \qquad \mathcal{L}\psi\ \mathcal{L}\distr{\psi}
    \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\mathpalette` to distinguish between the different math styles:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@distr}[2]{\underbracket[0.3pt][1pt]{#1#2}}
\newcommand{\distr}[1]{\mathpalette{\@distr}{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
  a_f\ a_{\distr{f}} \qquad \mathcal{L}\psi\ \mathcal{L}\distr{\psi}
\]

\end{document}
```

See [The mysteries of `\mathpalette`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34393/5764) for a discussion on how `\mathpalette` works.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Any suggestions for the spacing issue?

Comment: @giobrach: Perhaps use `\mathcal{L}\!\distr{\psi}`.

Comment: I had thought of that, but I wonder whether there is a way to include `\!` in the definition of `\distr` in such a way that it shows up only when needed (i.e. when a character such as `\mathcal{L}` precedes it).

Comment: @giobrach: Try [this code](https://pastebin.com/raw/B8rvQyRU). It redefines `\mathcal` to check if it's followed by `\distr` (rather than defining `\distr` to look back; it's easy peeking ahead). If so, it inserts `\!`.

Comment: Thank you! Actually, I've determined that the issue appears for all characters appearing before `\distr`, not just those of the calligraphic variety. Is there a way to redefine `\distr` in the same fashion (maybe with something like `\@ifprevchar`, if it exists)? If you care to include it in the answer, I would be glad to accept it.

Comment: Ok, solved! I just needed to surround the definition of `\distr` with `{ }`. Thanks for everything!

Comment: @giobrach: You can also try [this option](https://pastebin.com/raw/kCZSbvtE), which removes the horizontal spacing that could be introduced by `\underbracket`...

Comment: Even better! Thanks!