# How to "resume" alignat

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, vertical-alignment, alignment, alignat

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
    A \hspace{12.5pt} & \hspace{12.5pt} && A \\[10pt]
    B \\[10pt]
    C \hspace{12.5pt} & \hspace{12.5pt} && C \\[10pt]
    D \hspace{12.5pt} & \hspace{12.5pt} && D
\end{alignat*}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
    A \hspace{12.5pt} & \hspace{12.5pt} && A \\
\end{alignat*}
\begin{equation*}
    B 
\end{equation*}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
    C \hspace{12.5pt} & \hspace{12.5pt} && C \\[10pt]
    D \hspace{12.5pt} & \hspace{12.5pt} && D
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

I'd like the B to be centered with equal vertical space between the lines.

**Edit.**

My original question was not sufficiently precise.
I do not want the horizontal spacing between the aligned columns to change.
In practice the entries will be quite wide.
Please see the new example.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
    A \hspace{12.5pt} & \hspace{12.5pt} && A \\[10pt]
    MMMMMMMMMMMMMM \\[10pt]
    C \hspace{12.5pt} & \hspace{12.5pt} && C \\[10pt]
    D \hspace{12.5pt} & \hspace{12.5pt} && D
\end{alignat*}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
    A \hspace{12.5pt} & \hspace{12.5pt} && A \\
\end{alignat*}
\begin{equation*}
    MMMMMMMMMMMMMM 
\end{equation*}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
    C \hspace{12.5pt} & \hspace{12.5pt} && C \\[10pt]
    D \hspace{12.5pt} & \hspace{12.5pt} && D
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

It should look like this:

```
        A    A
    MMMMMMMMMMMMMM
        C    C
        D    D
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `gather` with some box measurements (provided by `\eqmathbox` through [`eqparbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox)):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,eqparbox}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34412/5764
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\eqmathbox}{o O{c} m}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}
    {\def\eqmathbox@##1##2{\eqmakebox[#1][#2]{$##1##2$}}}
    {\def\eqmathbox@##1##2{\eqmakebox{$##1##2$}}}
  \mathpalette\eqmathbox@{#3}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
         A \hspace{12.5pt} & \hspace{12.5pt} && AA      \\[10pt]
                                  BBB                   \\[10pt]
      CCCC \hspace{12.5pt} & \hspace{12.5pt} && CCCCC   \\[10pt]
    DDDDDD \hspace{12.5pt} & \hspace{12.5pt} && DDDDDDD
\end{alignat*}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
         A \hspace{12.5pt} & \hspace{12.5pt} && AA      \\
\end{alignat*}
\begin{equation*}
                                  BBB 
\end{equation*}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
      CCCC \hspace{12.5pt} & \hspace{12.5pt} && CCCCC   \\[10pt]
    DDDDDD \hspace{12.5pt} & \hspace{12.5pt} && DDDDDDD
\end{alignat*}

\begin{gather*}
        \eqmathbox[LHS][r]{A} \hspace{25pt} \eqmathbox[RHS][l]{AA}      \\[10pt]
                                  BBB                                   \\[10pt]
     \eqmathbox[LHS][r]{CCCC} \hspace{25pt} \eqmathbox[RHS][l]{CCCCC}   \\[10pt]
  \eqmathbox[LHS][r]{DDDDDDD} \hspace{25pt} \eqmathbox[RHS][l]{DDDDDDD}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

The `L`eft `H`and `S`ides are measured and stored in a box of maximum width (all `r`ight-aligned) and the `R`ight `H`and `S`ides are put in a different box of maximum width (all `l`eft-aligned).

---

You can also use an `array`:

[image]

```
\[
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31672/5764
  \begin{array}{ r @{\hspace{25pt}} l }
         A & AA               \\
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{BBB} \\
      CCCC & CCCCC            \\
    DDDDDD & DDDDDDD
  \end{array}
\]
```

Comment: When I try to typeset your example I get the error `Undefined control sequence. \NewDocumentCommand{\eqmathbox}{o O{c} m}{% ?`

Comment: @simplejack: Add `\usepackage{xparse}` to your preamble. Up-to-date LaTeX distributions won't need this.

Comment: Thanks, now I am able to typeset the example. However, the `eqmathboxes` do not seem to work with `prooftrees` from the package `ebproof` as their contents. I had to put them inside of braces to make `alignat` work.

Comment: @simplejack: M'kay. Can you provide some code that show the current, complete, minimal example? You can use [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com) if you wish.

Comment: I got it to work using `array` instead of `alignat`.

Comment: @simplejack: Riiight. That's another option. For reference, I'll add it to my current answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can place equations within `\intertext` to pause and resume alignment.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
    A \hspace{12.5pt} & \hspace{12.5pt} && A \\
\intertext{\[ MMMMMMMMMMMMMM \]}
    C \hspace{12.5pt} & \hspace{12.5pt} && C \\[10pt]
    D \hspace{12.5pt} & \hspace{12.5pt} && D
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image: PDFLaTeX sample]