# Aligning equations in a list

Tags: equations, align, lists

1. I would like a list of equations (ideally using enumitem's enumerate environment) aligned (e.g.) by the equal sign. Is there a way to achieve that?

   The following produces a list of equations that are not aligned:

   ```
   \begin{enumerate}
     \item $a=b$
     \item $c+d=e$
   \end{enumerate}
   ```

   I want them aligned as in

   ```
   \begin{align*}
       a &= b \\
     c+d &= e
   \end{align*}
   ```

   but numbered with the same spacing of labels that would be produced by `enumerate`.
2. If possible, I would also like to know how to have them as much to the left as possible (as opposed to centering produced by `align*` environment). In the examples above this would mean that the second equation (i.e. "c+d=e") would typeset exactly as it does using `enumerate` and the first one would be aligned to it.
3. And finally, at the risk of being unmodest, I wish to be able to choose between inline and display style.

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend using the functionality provided by [`eqparbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox). Specifically, `\eqparbox[<tag>][<align>]{<stuff>}` will set `<stuff>` in a box that has maximum width across the same `<tag>`, with an additional `<align>`ment specification (`l`eft, `c`enter/default or `r`ight). With a slight modification that accommodates for math mode, `\eqmathbox` defined below does the same:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,eqparbox}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34412/5764
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\eqmathbox}{o O{c} m}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}
    {\def\eqmathbox@##1##2{\eqmakebox[#1][#2]{$##1##2$}}}
    {\def\eqmathbox@##1##2{\eqmakebox{$##1##2$}}}
  \mathpalette\eqmathbox@{#3}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item
  $\eqmathbox[LHS][r]{a} = b$
  
  \item
  $\eqmathbox[LHS]{c + d} = e$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The principle behind `eqparbox` is to store the width of the largest element in the `.aux` file, after processing the entire document. This `.aux` is then read during a subsequent compilation, setting elements within the appropriately-sized (maximal) boxes. Since it uses the `.aux` for processing, it requires at least two compilations with every change in the widest element for a `<tag>`.

Answer (score 2):

This solution (which is inspired by code from appendix D of The TeXbook) first typesets the formulas using `\halign` and then unpacks the `\hbox`es thus produced, placing each `\hbox` content after an `\item`:

```tex
\def\itemize{\unskip\setbox0=\lastbox
  \ifhbox0{\itemize}\item\unhbox0 \fi}
\begin{enumerate}
\vbox{\halign{\hfil$#$&${}#$\hfil\cr
  a&=b\cr
  c+d&=e\cr
}\itemize}
\end{enumerate}
```

[image]

The `\vbox` is necessary because `\lastbox` cannot be used on the main vertical list.

To achieve displaystyle, replace the `\halign` template in the fourth row with `\hfil$\displaystyle#$&$\displaystyle{}#$\hfil`