# Vertical positioning of \dashv and \vdash with kpfonts-otf

Tags: math-mode, unicode-math, kpfonts

The symbols `\dashv` and `\vdash` with `kpfonts-otf` appear to be too low, instead of being vertically centered. But as the classical `kpfonts` package produces the same result, it seems to be part of the font design. Is there some way to redefine them into a vertically centered version?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kpfonts-otf}
\begin{document}

\( F \dashv U \)

\( U \vdash F \)

\end{document}
```

Comment: Isn't that up to the font designer?

Comment: `kpfonts-otf` vertically centers `\dashv` and `\vdash` on the math axis, why should this be wrong?

Comment: @DanielFlipo I didn't mean they are wrong. It is just that visually these symbols appear to be aligned to the bottom of the line, comparing with the default Latin Modern (possibly due to the size of the symbols).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Computer Modern (or Latin Modern), the vertical stroke is as high as the uppercase letters and the horizontal stroke is in the middle, hence higher than the math axis.

In Kp fonts the choice is different: the horizontal stroke is on the math axis and the heigh of the vertical stroke is chosen accordingly.

### Latin Modern

[image]

### Kp fonts

[image]

### Do you want the symbols to be higher?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kpfonts-otf}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \NewCommandCopy\standarddashv\dashv
  \NewCommandCopy\standardvdash\vdash
  \RenewDocumentCommand{\dashv}{}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\raisesymbol\standarddashv}}%
  \RenewDocumentCommand{\vdash}{}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\raisesymbol\standardvdash}}%
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\raisesymbol}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1A$}%
  \sbox\tw@{$\m@th#1#2$}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr(\ht\z@-\ht\tw@)/2}{\usebox{\tw@}}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\( F \dashv U \)

\( U \vdash F \)

\({\vdash}\frac{1}{2}\)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this! Please allow me to ask a question: the command `\raisesymbol` requires two arguments, but only `\standard...` is given, so what is the second argument here? Does it have something to do with the `\mathpalette` before it?

Comment: @Jinwen Yes: `\mathpalette` takes two arguments, the first of which should be a two-argument macro. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34393/4427