# TColorBox - Respecting the text colour and font size

Tags: tcolorbox

I want to keep the same colour and font size being used prior to entering a `\tcboxmath`. The objective is to get the right side of the output image while having the `x^2+1` highlighted.

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[theorems]{tcolorbox}

\newcommand{\mymath}[2][]{%
  \tcboxmath[colback=blue!20,size=minimal]{#2}%
}
\begin{document}
\[\color{red}Z^{\mymath{x^2+1}} \qquad Z^{x^2+1}\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current color is stored in `.` (in a color context). The size in math mode is chosen by `\mathchoice` (see [The mysteries of `\mathpalette`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34393/8425)

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage[theorems]{tcolorbox}

\newcommand{\mymath}[2][]{%
  \mathchoice%
  {\tcboxmath[colback=blue!20,colupper=.,size=minimal]{\displaystyle#2}}%
  {\tcboxmath[colback=blue!20,colupper=.,size=minimal]{\textstyle#2}}%
  {\tcboxmath[colback=blue!20,colupper=.,size=minimal]{\scriptstyle#2}}%
  {\tcboxmath[colback=blue!20,colupper=.,size=minimal]{\scriptscriptstyle#2}}%
}
\begin{document}
\[\color{red}Z^{\mymath{x^2+1}} \qquad Z^{x^2+1}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer and appreciate introducing me to `\mathpalette`.