# mathpalette-version for fontstyle instead of fontsize

Tags: fonts, macros, fontsize, math-fonts

The link [the-mysteries-of-mathpalette](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34393/the-mysteries-of-mathpalette) gives a nice overview of the mathpalette command. My question is pseudo-related. Is there a version of mathpalette where instead of "preserving the font size" it "preserves the font style"?

For example_practicality, the underline command `\underline` has the property that any math written within it preserves the fontstyle (e.g. \mathit, \mathtt, \mathrm) but the underbracket command `\underbracket[rule thickness][bracket height]{arg}` does not have this feature. I wish to make my own custom version of underbracket which mimics the underline command in this regard. If the mathpalette-version exists (I suspect not after a quick internet search), then I can see a way to get the desired code. Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Can you give a sample document showing the issues (which would also show the desired use case)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current math family is in the TeX primitive `\fam` register, for which LaTeX introduces the `\mathgroup` wrapper. The kind of problem you describe arises every time a macro sets its math content in a box for alignment or measuring or whatever. This does not happen with `\overline` because it is (in math mode) a primitive, but `\underbracket` uses a `\ialign`.

For a macro with a single argument you could define a wrapper similar<sup>1)</sup> to `\mathpalette`, but for `\underbracket` this is trickier because it has two optional arguments. I just looked into the code for the default values of the optional arguments and built a wrapper around `\underbracket`. The basic idea is to save the current value of `\mathgroup` and use it later in the argument.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\MHInternalSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\saved@mathgroup}{}% better safe than sorry
\NewDocumentCommand{\varunderbracket}{ O{\l_MT_bracketheight_fdim} O{.7\fontdimen5\textfont2} m }{%
   \edef\saved@mathgroup{\the\mathgroup}% save current \mathgroup
   \underbracket[#1][#2]{\mathgroup\saved@mathgroup#3}% use saved \mathgroup
}
\makeatother
\MHInternalSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\mathsf{foo + ba\underbracket{r - ba}z} f\underbracket{oo \mathrm{bar} baz}\\
\mathsf{foo + ba\varunderbracket{r - ba}z} f\varunderbracket{oo \mathrm{bar} baz}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

<sup>1)</sup> Well, actually completely different, but you get the idea.