Equations with words alignment (in enumerate environment)


Consider the 1.1.2 subsection. I defined the first item, the Divisor function. After that, I want to write some equations and words alongside the equations (like "unique factorization theorem" and even before the equations (phrases like "We have"and "Any divisor").
I am using \begin{align*}....\end{align*} environment for a set of equations+words, as you can see here, but this isn't looking neat. I don't know why the "Any divisor" line was intended when I put a line break at the end of the first line.
How can I preferably use phrases here, such that the equations and the phrases (before the equation) and (after the equation) are aligned, respectively?
In the preceding code, above the starting of subsection 1.1.2 Examples, Can I somehow get the equations written under 3. and 4. to be aligned along their equal signs? And a similar suggestion for parts like (m,n)=1 and \forall (m,n) to be aligned with each other in some way?

\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{cor}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lem}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{example}{Ex}[chapter]
\newtheorem{axiom}{Axiom}[chapter]

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{notation}{Notation}
\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem*{conjecture}{Conjecture}
\newtheorem*{definition}{Definition}

\newcommand{\bR}{\ensuremath{\mathbb{R}}}

\title{Notes from camp}
\author{Naman Thakkar}
\date{Nov 2024}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Partial Summation formula and applications}
\textbf{Analytic Number Theory}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Uses Analysis (real, complex, p-adiac) to study questions in number theory.
    \item We will pay attention to methods rather than specific results.
    \item Focus of study - Arithmetic Functions
\end{itemize}
\section{Arithmetic Function}
$$ f \; \colon \; \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$$
\begin{itemize}
    \item We would be interested : growth of $f(n)$ as n varies.
    \item Behaviour of sums like - $\sum\limits_{n \leq x}^{} f(n)$ and their asymptotics.
\subsection{Types of Arithmetic Functions}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Multiplicative Functions 
            $$f(mn) = f(m)f(n) \quad (m,n) = 1$$
         \item Completely Multiplicative Functions
            $$f(mn) = f(m)f(n) \quad \forall (m,n)$$
        \item Additive Functions
            \begin{align*}
                f(mn) = f(m) + f(n) \quad (m,n) = 1
            \end{align*}
        \item Completely Additive Functions
            \begin{align*}
                f(mn) = f(m) + f(n) \quad \forall (m,n)    
            \end{align*}
    \end{enumerate} 
\subsection{Examples}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Divisor function :\;  $d(n) = \# \ \textrm{of divisors of n.}$ 
        \begin{align*}
            \textrm{e.g.} \quad d(2) = d(3) = d(5) = 2 , \quad d(6) = 4
        \end{align*}
      \begin{align*}
        \text{We have}, \quad n = p_{1}^{\alpha_{1}} \cdots p_{k}^{\alpha_{k}} \quad \text{unique factorization theorem}\\
        \text{Any divisor}, \quad \delta(n) = p_1^{\beta_1} \cdots p_k^{\beta_k} \quad 0 \leq \beta_i \leq \alpha_i
      \end{align*}
    \end{enumerate} 

\end{itemize}
\end{document}


Welcome! I'm afraid that nobody is going to copy the code from a small image. Would you please provide the code?

And please, make sure that the code is a complete document that we can compile easily. Start with \documentclass, keep only the packages needed, and provide only the part of your full document that is of interest for the question.

I added the code in the post; there are 5 packages in the preamble, the usually used and standard ones, I feel, so I didn't remove which were not used, too.
Its a small document with the question about the code on second page, so i nevertheless have put the full code.

Since you're asking for suggestions, here are some:

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{eqparbox}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34412/5764
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\eqmathbox}{o O{c} m}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}
    {\def\eqmathbox@##1##2{\eqmakebox[#1][#2]{$##1##2$}}}
    {\def\eqmathbox@##1##2{\eqmakebox{$##1##2$}}}
  \mathpalette\eqmathbox@{#3}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Types of Arithmetic Functions}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Multiplicative Functions 
  \[
    \eqmathbox[lhs][r]{f(m n)} = \eqmathbox[rhs][l]{f(m) f(n)} 
      \quad \eqmathbox[cond][l]{(m, n) = 1}
  \]
  
  \item Completely Multiplicative Functions
  \[
    \eqmathbox[lhs][r]{f(m n)} = \eqmathbox[rhs][l]{f(m) f(n)} 
      \quad \eqmathbox[cond][l]{\forall (m, n)}
  \]
  
  \item Additive Functions
  \[
    \eqmathbox[lhs][r]{f(m n)} = \eqmathbox[rhs][l]{f(m) + f(n)} 
      \quad \eqmathbox[cond][l]{(m, n) = 1}
  \]
  
  \item Completely Additive Functions
  \[
    \eqmathbox[lhs][r]{f(m n)} = \eqmathbox[rhs][l]{f(m) + f(n)} 
      \quad \eqmathbox[cond][l]{\forall (m, n)}
  \]
\end{enumerate} 

\section{Examples}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Divisor function: $d(n) = \text{\# of divisors of n}$. For example,
  \[
    d(2) = d(3) = d(5) = 2 \text{ and } d(6) = 4.
  \]
  We have
  \[
    n = p_1^{\alpha_1} \dots p_k^{\alpha_k}
  \]
  due to the unique factorization theorem with any divisor
  \[
    \delta(n) = p_1^{\beta_1} \dots p_k^{\beta_k} 
      \quad 0 \leq \beta_i \leq \alpha_i
  \]
\end{enumerate} 

\end{document}

Avoid using descriptive "sentences" as part of the equation. You can use short words (like and and or, say), but longer descriptive content should be set as a paragraph; that is a common style.
I've used \eqmathbox[<tag>][<align>]{<stuff>} that sets <stuff> is a box of maximum width based on the same <tag>. Additionally you can set the appropriate <align>ment within that box (left, right or centred). This allows you to align content across \items within a list which, otherwise, would be difficult with align-and-friends. Since the approach uses the .aux file for length gathering/storing, at least two compilations are required with every change in the maximum length of a <tag>.

This helps, I'll look up \eqmathbox[<tag>][<align>]{<stuff>} to learn more. And I also learned about \[ equation \] commands. I wanted to ask if I can control the spacing between "We have" and "n=p_1^{\alpha_1}...." when using \[ equation \] commands?

@NamanThakkar: See Why is \[ … \] preferable to $$?

The (vertical) space between equations and text is given by 4 lengths: \abovedisplayskip for space where the preceding text line is "long" and \abovedisplayshortskip for space where the preceding text line is "short". Length here is relative to the content. And then there's commensurate lengths for below the equation: \belowdisplayskip and \belowdisplayshortskip.

Some additional ideas.
Speaking for myself (who else?), I can see no discernable advantage in aligning the four equations in section 1.1.1 on their = symbols.


\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{left=0pt}
\setlist[itemize]{left=0pt,noitemsep}

%\usepackage{amsmath} % is loaded automatically by 'mathtools'
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\raggedright}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Partial summation formula and applications}

\textbf{Analytic number theory}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Uses (real, complex, $p$\nobreakdash-adic) analysis to study questions in number theory.
    \item We will pay attention to methods rather than specific results.
    \item Focus of study: Arithmetic functions.
\end{itemize}

\section{Arithmetic functions}
%\[ 
%f \colon\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{C}
%\]

%\begin{itemize}
%    \item For instance, we could be interested in growth of $f(n)$ as $n$ varies.
%    \item Behaviour of sums like $\sum_{n \leq x} f(n)$ and their asymptotics.
%\end{itemize}

\subsection{Types of arithmetic functions}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Multiplicative functions
    \begin{align*}
    f(mn)  &= f(m)f(n) \quad (m,n) = 1 \\
    \intertext{\item Completely multiplicative functions}
    f(mn)  &= f(m)f(n) \quad \forall (m,n) \\
    \intertext{\item Additive functions}
    f(m+n) &= f(m) + f(n) \quad (m,n) = 1 \\
    \intertext{\item Completely additive functions}
    f(m+n) &= f(m) + f(n) \quad \forall (m,n)
    \end{align*}  
\end{enumerate}

\subsection{Examples}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Divisor function:  $d(n) = \text{\# of (unique) divisors of $n$}$. E.g., 
    \[
    d(1) = 1,\quad
    d(2) = d(3) = d(5) = 2, \quad 
    d(4) = 3, \quad 
    d(6) = 4.
    \]
    We have
    \[
    n = p_{1}^{\alpha_{1}} \dotsb p_{k}^{\alpha_{k}}
    \quad \alpha_i\in\mathbb{N}, \quad i=1,\dots,k
    \] 
    because of the unique factorization theorem.
    
    A divisor $\delta(n)$ of $n$ satisfies
    \[
    \delta(n) = p_1^{\beta_1} \dotsb p_k^{\beta_k} 
    \quad 0 \leq \beta_i \leq \alpha_i
    \]

\end{enumerate} 

\end{document}

