# How to make the amsxtra \accentedsymbol work with subscripts etc.?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, subscripts, performance

The `amsxtra` package provides the `\accentedsymbol` command which typesets the argument and stores the result.  This can [speed up LaTeX compilation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30211/6903) significantly if lots of accents etc. are used frequently.  The problem is that `\accentedsymbol` typesets only one size, so you need to have different macros for all math styles.

### Question

How can I define a command similar to `\accentedsymbol` that works properly in all math display styles?

### Comments

The solution probably involves using `\mathchoice`.  Here is a minimal working example that implements a `\mathchoice` solution by hand.  Is this the best solution? (Some issues about `\mathchoice` are discussed in the references below.) How can this be automated?  Since the goal here is performace, is `\mathchoice` a good option? (The TeXbook warns that it is slow, but since I am only typesetting saved boxes, maybe this is fine.  It seems to work well with intermediate sized problems I have tested.)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsxtra}

\accentedsymbol\vkbad{\vec{\mathbf{k}}}

\accentedsymbol\vkD{\displaystyle \vec{\mathbf{k}}}
\accentedsymbol\vkT{\textstyle \vec{\mathbf{k}}}
\accentedsymbol\vkS{\scriptstyle \vec{\mathbf{k}}}
\accentedsymbol\vkSS{\scriptscriptstyle \vec{\mathbf{k}}}
\newcommand{\vk}{\mathchoice{\vkD}{\vkT}{\vkS}{\vkSS}}

\begin{document}
This is bad: $\vkbad = x_{\vkbad}$.  This is good: $\vk = x_{\vk}$.
\end{document}
```

[image: Sample output.]

### References

- [Is there a test for the different styles inside maths mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1223)
- [Problem with \mathpalette and \mathchoice](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3875/)
- [Proper use of \mathchoice](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43978)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `\mathchoice` is indeed the answer. The `\accentedsymbol` works by precompiling the character with accent(s) into a box and then resuing this box each time. So the size is fixed and you need different versions per style. This style is only determined when the formula is processed and that is why you need `\mathchoice`. But you can mimic the `amsxtra` definition to do this for you:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\makeatletter

\def\xaccentedsymbol#1#2{%
  \newcommand#1{}%
  \expandafter\newbox
    \csname D\expandafter\@gobble\string#1@box\endcsname
  \expandafter\setbox
    \csname D\expandafter\@gobble\string#1@box\endcsname
      \hbox{$\m@th \displaystyle #2$}%
  \expandafter\newbox
    \csname T\expandafter\@gobble\string#1@box\endcsname
  \expandafter\setbox
    \csname T\expandafter\@gobble\string#1@box\endcsname
      \hbox{$\m@th \textstyle #2$}%
  \expandafter\newbox
    \csname S\expandafter\@gobble\string#1@box\endcsname
  \expandafter\setbox
    \csname S\expandafter\@gobble\string#1@box\endcsname
      \hbox{$\m@th \scriptstyle #2$}%
  \expandafter\newbox
    \csname SS\expandafter\@gobble\string#1@box\endcsname
  \expandafter\setbox
    \csname SS\expandafter\@gobble\string#1@box\endcsname
      \hbox{$\m@th \scriptscriptstyle #2$}%
  \edef#1{\mathchoice
      {\copy\csname D\expandafter\@gobble\string#1@box\endcsname{}}%
      {\copy\csname T\expandafter\@gobble\string#1@box\endcsname{}}%
      {\copy\csname S\expandafter\@gobble\string#1@box\endcsname{}}%
      {\copy\csname SS\expandafter\@gobble\string#1@box\endcsname{}}}%
}
\makeatother

\xaccentedsymbol\vk{\vec{\mathbf{k}}}

\begin{document}
   This is good: $\vk = x_{\vk}$.
\end{document}
```

Quite a mouthful, but essentially only generating the different boxes and then using it inside `\mathchoice`. What I changed compared to the original definition is however that I also precompile the box names by using `\edef`, so that the `\csname`s inside `\mathchoice` are done at defintion time not at execution time.

Still as egreg observed this `\accentedsymbol` or my variant are only really gaining somehting if you have double accents, so for normal accents it doesn't help much.

Comment: One should also realize that these accented symbols will *not* change size in a `\small` or `\large` context.

Comment: @egreg good point - essentially that means those commands are needed in headings or footnotes etc. one would either need to define yet another set of variants each or better simply use the base definitions in those cases.

Answer (score 7):

I tried the following

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsxtra}

\newcommand{\vk}{\vec{\mathbf{k}}}

\begin{document}
\newcount\lp
\loop\ifnum\lp<100000
\advance\lp 1
\setbox0=\hbox{This is good: $\vk = x_{\vk}$.}
\repeat
\end{document}
```

and with `time pdflatex test1` I got

```
    5.06 real         4.93 user         0.06 sys
```

With this other input

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsxtra}

\accentedsymbol\vkD{\displaystyle \vec{\mathbf{k}}}
\accentedsymbol\vkT{\textstyle \vec{\mathbf{k}}}
\accentedsymbol\vkS{\scriptstyle \vec{\mathbf{k}}}
\accentedsymbol\vkSS{\scriptscriptstyle \vec{\mathbf{k}}}
\newcommand{\vk}{\mathchoice{\vkD}{\vkT}{\vkS}{\vkSS}}

\begin{document}
\newcount\lp
\loop\ifnum\lp<100000
\advance\lp 1
\setbox0=\hbox{This is good: $\vk = x_{\vk}$.}
\repeat
\end{document}
```

the call `time pdflatex test2` gave

```
    5.07 real         4.92 user         0.06 sys
```

So there's not much difference. The `\accentedsymbol` macro is useful when double accents are to be set. Indeed, the same files, but with `\vec{\hat{\mathbf{k}}}}` showed a *very* big difference: with `\accentedsymbol` and `\mathchoice` the time was the same as before, without it the compilation took minutes:

```
   98.15 real        93.19 user         0.55 sys
```