# What is the Right Way to install a new font locally?

Tags: fonts, installing

In [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4192/bad-positioning-of-math-accents-for-the-beamer-standard-font/7576#7576), I produced a new `tfm` file for the beamer standard math font. What is the Right Way to make the new font available to the TeX system? With texlive I tried

```
updmap-sys --enable Map=cmssmi.map
```

but this gave the following error message.

```
updmap: This is updmap, version $Id: updmap 14402 2009-07-23 17:09:15Z karl $
updmap: no permissions for writing /usr/local/texlive/2009/texmf-var/web2c/updmap.log', so no transcript

There was a problem finding a proper place to store configuration data.
The message was:
  Directory `/usr/local/texlive/2009/texmf-config/web2c' is not writable

To overcome such problems, set up the environment variable TEXMFCONFIG to
point to a directory tree that is writable to you, e.g.
  TEXMFCONFIG=$HOME/texmf; export TEXMFCONFIG
or
  setenv TEXMFCONFIG $HOME/texmf
```

I did try setting up `TEXMFCONFIG`, but to no avail.

To make clear what I aim at: I'm on a system where I'm just a poor user; the TeX distribution is installed globally, so it's read-only for me as I don't have root permissions. Therefore, I want the changes installed in a local directory.

Comment: I suppose you installed texlive as root?

Comment: @Herbert: No, the system administrator did. Sorry that I forgot to tell.

Comment: then you have to run `updmap --enable Map=cmssmi.map`, it uses your `~/texmf` directory

Comment: @Herbert: Thanks, that works. Great! Can you please add it as an answer so that I can accept it? (And: Do I get it right that with `-sys` it tries to install the font globally?)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

then you have to run `updmap --enable Map=cmssmi.map`, it uses your ~/texmf directory

But it makes only sense, when you are a *real* user on a foreign machine.It will confuse your system, when you run sometimes the `-sys`variant and sometimes the
user variant.

Comment: What do you mean by _real_? I'm feeling rather real at the moment, or am I only imagining my existence?

Comment: "real" is that you do not have root access and are not able to mix the use of `update-sys` and `update`

Comment: So that's where I wrote "poor". Thanks! (And please remember the "@Hendrik" thing `:-)`.)